# Display number of occurrences for every character in an input string

Tags: code-golf, string, counting

The code should take a string as input from keyboard:

```
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
```

The output should be like this(not sorted in any particular order):

```
  :  15
. :  1
T :  1
a :  10
c :  1
e :  8
d :  4
g :  3
f :  2
i :  10
h :  3
m :  1
o :  4
n :  10
q :  1
p :  3
s :  5
r :  2
u :  1
t :  6
y :  1
x :  1
```

All ASCII characters count unicode is not a requirement, spaces, quotes,etc and input should come from keyboard / not constants, attributes, output should be printed with new line after each character like in the above example, it should not be returned as string or dumped as hashmap/dictionary etc, so `x :  1` and `x: 1` are ok, but  `{'x':1,...` and `x:1` are not.

Q: Function or complete program taking stdin and writing stdout?
A: Code needs to be a program taking input using standard in and display the result via standard out.

## Scoreboard:

[Shortest overall](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157214/12328): 5 bytes

<s>[Shortest overall](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string#answer-19104): 7 bytes</s>

Comment: All ascii characters as input? Or just printable? Or up to unicode? Will there be newlines?

Comment: Can I create a function, or is a whole program necessary? Can I output all the ascii characters and print `0` as the number of occurrences?

Comment: Is the output format strict, or it suffices to preserve the meaning?

Comment: Your edit did not address my question.

Comment: You didn't say if the output needs to be sorted alphabetically. You didn't say if the separator needs to be `" :  "` (note the two spaces after the `:`) or if other(shorter) seperators are fine. You didn't address the unicode/encoding issue.

Comment: what kind of sort order is that?

Comment: @Spongman The missing one type

Comment: Function or complete program taking stdin and writing stdout?

Comment: The "shortest overall" does not follow the required output.  Is that okay?

Comment: @microbian I see that as a soft requirement :)

Comment: @Eduard Florinescu, yeah, but the trouble is that your output IS sorted - losely as if it were read from a binary heap. yet you do not specify if that is a requirement. you say "The output should be" which implies that the order should be maintained.

Comment: @Spongman I used a dictionary for that, that's why, I will edit the question.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu What about JavaScript? There is no standard input. You could say that the console is standard output.

Comment: @toothbrush `prompt()`? readline for nodejs

Comment: @toothbrush nodejs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006821/nodejs-how-to-read-keystrokes-from-stdin

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu OK, thank you. I was thinking about in the browser. Is it OK to pass the string in a variable, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program body. Prompts for a string from STDIN and prints newline separated table to STDOUT. Leftmost column is the input characters, and counts are right-aligned with the largest number separated from its character by a single space.

```apl
,∘≢⌸⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDQIxEARzqtgCgGpo4ITP/pOeO/M@JL4CHglyIgKqoB43YgwRG@2sRkt53ISZRkutLpfY1nV51Our3t71/vxODb/E1W5gBI6i4mIKixAt1GmGFBxP5qIJ3q1CB0YeJioMSiQK0vDX1Bx8zrz3flgyybT9AA)

`⍞` prompt for text input from STDIN

`⌸` create a keys' table consisting of
 `,` the unique element followed
 `∘` by
 `≢` the tally of the indices of its occurrence (i.e how many times it occurs)

Comment: Looks like the `:` is unfortunately required in the output (you can't delete this answer).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer How do you deduce that? Clearly OP found this answer acceptable, in accordance with [an old comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string/157214?noredirect=1#comment38199_19068).

Comment: Another reason for spec to be in the question itself...

Answer (score 15):

### PHP - 68 (or 39) bytes

```
<?foreach(count_chars(fgets(STDIN),1)as$k=>$v)echo chr($k)." : $v
";
```

Output for the example text:

```
  : 15
. : 1
T : 1
a : 10
c : 1
d : 4
e : 8
f : 2
g : 3
h : 3
i : 10
m : 1
n : 10
o : 4
p : 3
q : 1
r : 2
s : 5
t : 6
u : 1
x : 1
y : 1
```

If the exact output is not required, this would work for **39 bytes**:

```
<?print_r(count_chars(fgets(STDIN),1));
```

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [32] => 15
    [46] => 1
    [84] => 1
    [97] => 10
    [99] => 1
    [100] => 4
    [101] => 8
    [102] => 2
    [103] => 3
    [104] => 3
    [105] => 10
    [109] => 1
    [110] => 10
    [111] => 4
    [112] => 3
    [113] => 1
    [114] => 2
    [115] => 5
    [116] => 6
    [117] => 1
    [120] => 1
    [121] => 1
)
```

where each numerical index refers the ordinal value of the character it represents.

I suspect very strongly that using an in-built function that does exactly what the problem states will soon be disallowed.

Comment: `$argv[1]` instead of `fgets(STDIN)` saves 4 bytes.

Answer (score 14):

## k (<s>8</s> 7)

```
#:'=0:0
```

Example

```
k)#:'=:0:0
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
T| 1
h| 3
e| 8
 | 15
d| 4
f| 2
i| 10
n| 10
t| 6
o| 4
s| 5
a| 10
y| 1
q| 1
u| 1
g| 3
m| 1
p| 3
r| 2
x| 1
c| 1
.| 1
```

edit: Down to seven, H/T Aaron Davies

### Explanation

Take a String from keyboard :

```
k)0:0
text
"text"
```

Group the distinct elements and return a map containing key as distinct characters and values are the indices where the distinct elements occur.

```
k)=0:0
text
t| 0 3
e| ,1
x| ,2
```

Now count values of each entry in the map.

```
k)#:'=0:0
text
t| 2
e| 1
x| 1
```

Comment: Pretty incredible.

Comment: the `:` in `=:` is superfluous; `k)#:'=0:0` works fine (7 chars). (bonus for knowing about `0:0`, i had no idea!)

Comment: A detailed explanation would be really cool :)

Comment: `q` translation is easier to understand - `count each group read0 0`

Answer (score 13):

## GNU core utils - <strike>29</strike> <strike>22</strike> 20 chars (53 with formatting)

Wumpus's improvement (20 chars):

```
fold -1|sort|uniq -c
```

Firefly's improvement (22 chars):

```
grep -o .|sort|uniq -c
```

joeytwiddle's original (29 chars):

```
sed 's+.+\0\n+g'|sort|uniq -c
```

Originally I used `sed` to simply add a newline after each character.  Firefly improved on that with `grep -o .`, since `-o` displays every matched pattern on its own line.  Wumpus pointed out a further improvement using `fold -1` instead.  Nice work!

`uniq` does the real work, although it only applies to sorted lists.

Note that the output format does not exactly match the example in the question.  That requires a final run through `sed` to swap the arguments.  (Waiting on an answer to Jan Dvorak's question to see if this is required...)

Reformatting with sed is "only" another 33 characters!  (**Total 53**)

```
|sed 's/ *\(.*\) \(.\)/\2 :  \1/'
```

Awk can *almost* do the job whilst adding only 25 chars, but it hides the first space.  Silly awk!

```
|awk '{print $2" :  "$1}'
```

I wonder if improvements can be made in the reformatting stage...

Comment: For sed you can use `&` for "whole match" instead of `\0`, though `grep -o .` is slightly shorter yet. It's worth mentioning that the output of `uniq -c` differs slightly from the one given in the question.

Comment: Oh thanks you!  Updated.  I should not forget `grep -o`; it is a useful one.

Comment: `fold -1` does the same thing as `grep -o .`

Comment: Awesome :)  Learning new tricks!

Comment: `ptx -S.` does the same [trick](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19164/9534).

Comment: I like it!  However, it doesn't comply with the "output should be printed with new line after each character" requirement.

Comment: actually, I just misread the rule. :-)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3: 76 characters

### 76

```
import collections as c
for x,y in c.Counter(input()).items():print(x,':',y)
```

#### 44

(print same characters many times, see [Wasi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string/19113#19113)'s answer for a valid version)

```
a=input()
for x in a:print(x,':',a.count(x))
```

Comment: The 45 char version prints characters more than once.

Comment: @evuez I just fixed your 45 char version. But, you removed it so I have submitted it once again. Have a [look](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string/19113#19113)

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby 1.9.3: 53 characters

(Based on @shiva's and @daneiro's comments.)

```ruby
gets.split("").uniq.map{|x|puts x+" : #{$_.count x}"}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e 'a=gets;a.split("").uniq.map{|x|puts"#{x} : #{a.count x}"}' <<< 'Hello world'
H : 1
e : 1
l : 3
o : 2
  : 1
w : 1
r : 1
d : 1

 : 1
```

### Ruby: 44 characters

Not respecting the output format:

```ruby
s=Hash.new 0;gets.chars{|c|s[c]+=1};pp s
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -rpp -e 's=Hash.new 0;gets.chars{|c|s[c]+=1};pp s' <<< 'Hello, world!'
{"H"=>1,
 "e"=>1,
 "l"=>3,
 "o"=>2,
 ","=>1,
 " "=>1,
 "w"=>1,
 "r"=>1,
 "d"=>1,
 "!"=>1,
 "\n"=>1}
```

Comment: 63 chars `a=gets.strip;a.split('').uniq.each{|x|puts"#{x} : #{a.count(x)}"}`

Comment: Why to `strip()`? The question says, “all characters count”.

Comment: Well, gets will return `\n` even if you dont intend to

Comment: Nope. Only returns `\n` if it was really passed. Passing it is a side-effect of using here-string. http://pastebin.com/gCrgk9m1

Comment: Then it becomes 57 chars

Comment: 57 -> 49 characters: `puts gets.chars.uniq.map{|c|c+" :  #{$_.count c}"}` if you don't mind newline being counted

Comment: @daniero, is that `ruby` 2++? “NoMethodError: undefined method `uniq' for #<Enumerator: "\n":chars>”

Comment: Oh, probably ;)

Comment: Using `$_` and ditching `a` is still sound though. And `c+"...` instead of `"#{c}...`

Comment: Looking at 2.1.0 documentation, neither [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html) nor [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) has such method…

Comment: Yes, but [`chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chars) now returns an array.

Comment: Oh. Seems I really have to read a good amount of changelogs. Thank you, @daniero.

Comment: why require pp? Couldn't you use `p` and save a character?

Comment: @shelvacu, I tried to keep at least partially the vertical listing format. Most of the other answers are doing something similar.

Answer (score 7):

### Perl 6: 21 chars

```
.say for get.comb.Bag
```

```
(REPL)
> .say for get.comb.Bag
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
"T" => 1
"h" => 3
"e" => 8
" " => 15
"d" => 4
"f" => 2
"i" => 10
"n" => 10
"t" => 6
"o" => 4
"s" => 5
"a" => 10
"y" => 1
"q" => 1
"u" => 1
"g" => 3
"m" => 1
"p" => 3
"r" => 2
"x" => 1
"c" => 1
"." => 1
```

Answer (score 5):

### APL (15)

```
M,⍪+⌿Z∘.=M←∪Z←⍞
```

If you really need the `:`, it's **19** (but there's others who aren't including it):

```
M,':',⍪+⌿Z∘.=M←∪Z←⍞
```

Output:

```
      M,⍪+⌿Z∘.=M←∪Z←⍞
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair. 
T  1
h  3
e  8
  16
d  4
f  2
i 10
n 10
t  6
o  4
s  5
a 10
y  1
q  1
u  1
g  3
m  1
p  3
r  2
x  1
c  1
.  1
```

Comment: Semi-serious question -- what's it like maintaining legacy APL code?

Comment: @MichaelStern: No idea, I've never had to do that. But I'd guess it's no worse than maintaining other legacy code. APL is actually quite easy to read once you're used to it.

Answer (score 5):

#### R, 30 characters

```
table(strsplit(readline(),""))
```

Example usage:

```
> table(strsplit(readline(),""))
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.

    .  a  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  T  u  x  y 
15  1 10  1  4  8  2  3  3 10  1 10  4  3  1  2  5  6  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Good idea! But the question says the code must print the result. Your code just returns the result. I suppose you need `cat`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein well it wasn't specified when i answered (i answered before revision 4 of the question)... but as a matter of fact `cat` will only return the values not the value names (i. e. the characters). So it would need a more complex solution.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl 5, 54 characters

```
map{$h{$_}++}split//,<>;print"$_ : $h{$_}\n"for keys%h
```

Comment: Very nice solution, easy to read. That would need to be `sort keys%h`, though.

Comment: Hey @protist, looks good! I agree with @primo though! You can however save two chars using `$_=<>;s/./$h{$_}++/eg;` or `map{$h{$_}++}<>=~/./g;` instead of `map{$h{$_}++}split//,<>;`

Comment: @DomHastings or `$h{$_}++for<>=~/./g`, which I think might be optimal. Literal newline instead of `\n` as well.

Comment: Ah nice, even better! Yes, I forgot to mention the literal newline, that's become my new favourite -1 byte!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript

1. **<s>66</s> 53 bytes:**

   ```
   prompt(a={}).replace(/./g,function(c){a[c]=-~a[c]}),a
   ```
2. **<s>69</s> 56 bytes:**

   ```
   b=prompt(a={});for(i=b.length;i--;){a[b[i]]=-~a[b[i]]};a
   ```
3. **<s>78</s> 65 bytes:**

   ```
   prompt().split('').reduce(function(a,b){return a[b]=-~a[b],a},{})
   ```

**N.B.:** In all cases deleted number of bytes refer to extra `console.log()` call which is pointless if run in the console. Big thanks to [@imma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14870/imma) for the great catch with `-~a[b]` and `prompt(a={})`. This definitely saved some more bytes.

Comment: map instead of a loop help a little
also (a[b[i]]||0)+1 can be reduced to -~a[b[i]] & console.log can probably go, just returning the last value, giving prompt(a={}).split("").map(function(c){a[c]=-~a[c]});a

Comment: you can change `for` into `for in` - testing in empty tab produces the same results. Also, the last `;` is not needed, thus: `b=prompt(a={});for(i in b){a[b[i]]=-~a[b[i]]}a`

Comment: nice :-)  stick the b=... into the for & swop the for{}'s for a ; for another 2 bytes off : for(i in b=prompt(a={}))a[b[i]]=-~a[b[i]];a

Comment: although they may want exact text output :-/ which puts it/me back up by 36 (to 79) bytes : for(i in b=prompt(a={}))a[b[i]]=-~a[b[i]];for(n in a)console.log(n+" :  "+a[n])

Comment: @imma `for .. in` is not the best choice for arrays and strings: it will grab own properties of the objects behind them. Normal loop is the way to go here IMO.

Comment: @VisioN only if the primitives are overloaded - `for in` indeed gives you functions in SO, but not in empty tab ;)

Answer (score 5):

## **Python 2, correctly (58)**

```
s=raw_input()
for l in set(s):print l+" : "+str(s.count(l))
```

**Output:**

```
python count.py
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
  : 15
. : 1
T : 1
a : 10
c : 1
e : 8
d : 4
g : 3
f : 2
i : 10
h : 3
m : 1
o : 4
n : 10
q : 1
p : 3
s : 5
r : 2
u : 1
t : 6
y : 1
x : 1
```

## **Python 2, cheetah style (41)**

```
s=input()
print {l:s.count(l) for l in s}
```

**Output:**

```
python count.py
"The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair."
{' ': 15, '.': 1, 'T': 1, 'a': 10, 'c': 1, 'e': 8, 'd': 4, 'g': 3, 'f': 2, 'i': 10, 'h': 3, 'm': 1, 'o': 4, 'n': 10, 'q': 1, 'p': 3, 's': 5, 'r': 2, 'u': 1, 't': 6, 'y': 1, 'x': 1}
```

Comment: Forgot to remove the brackets after print in the second one, that makes it 41

Comment: You can go down to 52 chars with your first version: `for l in set(s):print l,":",s.count(l)`. For the second one, removing unnecessary spaces makes you win 2 chars: `print{l:s.count(l)for l in s}`

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
Map[{#[[1]], Length@#} &, Gather@Characters[Input[]]] // TableForm
```

It then pops up this dialog box,

[image: input]

and for the sample sentence, produces as output

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

### python 3, 49

Stealing idea from [evuez](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string/19070#19070)

```
t=input()
for i in set(t):print(i,':',t.count(i))
```

input:

```
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
```

output:

```
  :  15
. :  1
T :  1
a :  10
c :  1
e :  8
d :  4
g :  3
f :  2
i :  10
h :  3
m :  1
o :  4
n :  10
q :  1
p :  3
s :  5
r :  2
u :  1
t :  6
y :  1
x :  1
```

Comment: nice improvement! why don't you remove the sorted()?

Comment: right! anyway, if you don't use a list comprehension, it's 1 char less: `for i in sorted(set(t)):print(i,':',t.count(i))`

Comment: @evuez Thanks, I was supposed to add it as a comment in your code. If you like you can add it again in your solution(I will happily delete this one) :D

Comment: Wouldn't be fair, I hadn't thought about `set()`! ;)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (<del>69</del> 68 characters):

*Expects `s` to hold the string.*

```
_={};for(x in s)_[a=s[x]]=-~_[a];for(x in _)console.log(x+': '+_[x])
```

*This follows the new rules perfectly.*

**Note:** *This presumes a clean environment, with no custom properties on any standard object prototypes.*

**Edit:** 1 character less!

### Console output:

```
T: 1
h: 3
e: 8
 : 15
d: 4
f: 2
i: 10
n: 10
t: 6
o: 4
s: 5
a: 10
y: 1
q: 1
u: 1
g: 3
m: 1
p: 3
r: 2
x: 1
c: 1
.: 1
```

---

## Old answer (44 characters):

```
r={};[].map.call(s,function(e){r[e]=-~r[e]})
```

*This was valid before the rules changed.*

`r` contains the output.

Answer (score 3):

## F# (<strike>66  59</strike> 49, 72 with prescribed formattting)

```
let f s=s|>Seq.countBy(id)|>Seq.iter(printfn"%A")
```

Output:

```
> f The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
(' ', 15)
('.', 1)
('T', 1)
('a', 10)
('c', 1)
('d', 4)
('e', 8)
('f', 2)
('g', 3)
('h', 3)
('i', 10)
('m', 1)
('n', 10)
('o', 4)
('p', 3)
('q', 1)
('r', 2)
('s', 5)
('t', 6)
('u', 1)
('x', 1)
('y', 1)
```

With the prescribed formatting, it becomes:

```
let f s=s|>Seq.countBy(id)|>Seq.iter(fun(a,b)->printfn"\"%c\" :  %d"a b)
```

Comment: You can drop a character by switching away from the piped syntax for a few of the function calls: `let f s=Seq.countBy id (Seq.sort s)|>Seq.iter(printfn"%A")`

Comment: In fact, why even sort in the first place? `let f s=Seq.countBy id s|>Seq.iter(printfn"%A")`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 93

```hs
import Data.List
main=getLine>>=mapM(\s->putStrLn$[head s]++" : "++show(length s)).group.sort
```

Answer (score 3):

**PowerShell (49)**

```
[char[]](read-host)|group|%{$_.Name+":"+$_.Count}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (<strike>20</strike> 15 characters)

```
 ptx -S.|uniq -c
 10                                        a
  1                                        c
  4                                        d
  8                                        e
  2                                        f
  3                                        g
  3                                        h
 10                                        i
  1                                        m
 10                                        n
  4                                        o
  3                                        p
  1                                        q
  2                                        r
  5                                        s
  6                                        t
  1                                        T
  1                                        u
  1                                        x
  1                                        y
```

ASCII encoding now supported

## Bash (23 characters):

```
xxd -p -c1|sort|uniq -c

  1 0a
 15 20
  1 2e
  1 54
 10 61
  1 63
  4 64
  8 65
  2 66
  3 67
  3 68
 10 69
  1 6d
 10 6e
  4 6f
  3 70
  1 71
  2 72
  5 73
  6 74
  1 75
  1 78
  1 79
```

ASCII formatting not supported

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you really need |sort| here, AFAIK ptx will already produce a sorted list of chars which you can feed directly to "uniq -c"

Comment: @zeppelin a little googling confimrs what you've said

Comment: Your `ptx -S.` solution doesn't work on my machine or TIO. However this works, for [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYxRCoQwDAWv8i7gwt5lLxBsagNuUpsIKt699tO/GRjm8tJ7tjVh@t5uLe5dZcM09/4rjMRZVEJMYRmiTsNOiGPbLUQXxKic/oxaGjmDFhIFaXqRWoCPynOMoVeS9nkA): `fold -1|sort|uniq -c`

Answer (score 3):

## C# (178 <strike>220</strike> chars)

Based on @Spongeman's comment I changed it up a bit:

```
using C=System.Console;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main()
{C.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",C.ReadLine().GroupBy(x=>x)
.OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Select(g=>g.Key+":"+g.Count())));}}
```

---

```
Line breaks added for readability, my first feeble attempt at code golf! :)

class P {static void Main(){var d=new Dictionary<char,int>();
Console.ReadLine().ToList().ForEach(x=>{ if(d.ContainsKey(x))
{d[x]++;}else{d.Add(x,1);}});Console.WriteLine(string
.Join("\n",d.Keys.Select(x=>x+":" +d[x])));}}
```

Comment: doesn't compile. this one does: 178 chars.
using System.Linq;using C=System.Console;class F{static void Main(){C.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",C.ReadLine().GroupBy(c=>c).Select(g=>g.Key+" :  "+g.Count()).OrderBy(s=>s)));}}

Comment: 168: using C=System.Console;using System.Linq;class F{static void Main(){foreach(var g in C.ReadLine().GroupBy(c=>c).OrderBy(g=>g.Key))C.WriteLine(g.Key+" :  "+g.Count());}}

Comment: apparently sorting is unneccesary, 150: using C=System.Console;using System.Linq;class F{static void Main(){foreach(var g in C.ReadLine().GroupBy(c=>c))C.WriteLine(g.Key+" : "+g.Count());}}

Comment: Wow. Quick or coincidence ? You replied just a second after I updated my answer :D Just noticed that sorting wasn't explicitly mentioned!

Comment: **148:** `namespace System{using Linq;class F{static void Main(){foreach(var g in Console.ReadLine().GroupBy(c=>c))Console.WriteLine(g.Key+" : "+g.Count());}}`

Comment: wow @Timwi that was neat!

Answer (score 3):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), 19 characters

```
梴要⓶銻꾠⓷❸虛變梴❶⓺減負겠⓸⓸終丟
```

### Output

```
T:1
h:3
e:8
 :15
d:4
f:2
i:10
n:10
t:6
o:4
s:5
a:10
y:1
q:1
u:1
g:3
m:1
p:3
r:2
x:1
c:1
.:1
```

If you want the spaces around the `:`, change `꾠` to `긃똠`, making it 20 characters.

### Explanation

```
Get length of input string.
梴
Stack is now [ input, length ]
While {
要
    Get first character of string and push ":"
    ⓶銻꾠
    Stack is now [ length, input, firstchar, ":" ]
    Replace all occurrences of that character with empty string
    ⓷❸虛變
    Stack is now [ length, firstchar, ":", reducedinput ]
    Get the length of that, calculate difference to previous length, push "\n"
    梴❶⓺減負겠
    Stack is now [ firstchar, ":", reducedinput, newlength, diff, "\n" ]
    Move the input string and length back up, leaving output below it
    ⓸⓸
    Stack is now [ firstchar, ":", diff, "\n", reducedinput, newlength ]
                   `------------------------'                `-------'
                   Every iteration of the               The length provides
                   While loop generates                 the While loop's
                   a bit like this                      terminating condition
} End While
終
Discard the length which is now 0
丟
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> 29 bytes

Not sure why the other Mathematica answer is so complicated... ;)

```
Grid@Tally@Characters@Input[]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>273</s> <s>253</s> <s>249</s> <s>246</s> <s>239</s> 200 bytes

```java
interface I{static void main(String[]a){int m[]=new int[999],i=0;for(int c:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().getBytes())m[c]++;for(;++i<999;)if(m[i]>0)System.out.printf("%c: %d%n",i,m[i]);}}
```

-24 bytes thanks to *@Poke*.
-7 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##TY/BasNADER/RQQCuzhdcnXc9NBboTf3ZnwQazmRU2tdr5zGhHy7uy499DZiRo@ZDq/41DWXZWFRGlv0BG/3qKjs4Rq4gR5ZTKkjy6mq0d5TDvqqPgp9Q9JVnuf1jo/7og2jWU1/WK0ugd2k/OlKjyI0mnKOSr1jsU7opu8sZKw7kb7OStFY21e@zrJfTpFl/JzIheXW9BXXL3v79x8mdUNqo63ZbP0Bts1WNjverSlbPB7L8nEmaKhlYeUgENrUM2K6ZuAIX1PQtAU0pSL2BMN5xEiApzQUUJp/SoIC3QbymoBxQB7dDw)

```java
interface I{                        // Class
  static void main(String[]a){      //  Mandatory main-method
    int m[]=new int[999],           //  Integer-array to count the occurrences
        i=0;                        //  Index-integer, starting at 0
    for(int c:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().getBytes())
                                    //   Loop over the input as bytes:
      m[c]++;                       //    Increase the occurrence-counter of the char by 1
    for(;++i<999;)                  //   Loop over the array:
      if(m[i]>0)                    //    If the current character occurred at least once:
        System.out.print("%c: %d%n",//     Print with proper formatting:
         i,                         //      The character
         m[i]);}}                   //      and the occurrence-count
```

Comment: 249 bytes `import java.util.*;class I{public static void main(String[]a){Map m=new HashMap();for(char c:new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray()){m.put(c,m.get(c)!=null?(int)m.get(c)+1:1);}for(Object e:m.keySet()){System.out.println(e+": "+m.get(e));}}}`

Comment: `m.compute(c,(k,v)->v!=null?(int)v+1:1);` instead of `m.put(c,m.get(c‌​)!=null?(int)m.get(c‌​)+1:1);` to save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>44</s> 37 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].map(x=>o[x]=-~o[x],o={})&&o
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=JSON.stringify((f=
s=>[...s].map(x=>o[x]=-~o[x],o={})&&o
)(i.value="The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair."));oninput=_=>o.innerText=JSON.stringify(f(i.value))
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge 98 - 31 to 42 chars

This does not print the spaces, and only prints for characters in the string (once for each character, even duplicates). So an input of `aa` will produce an output of:

```
a:2
a:2
```

#### 31 chars

```
~::1g1+\1p;,a.- 'g1,:',:@j`0:;#
```

---

The following seems to match almost exactly. It outputs only one time for each character, in the order they appear in the string. An input of `Bbaa` gives an output of

```
B:1
b:1
a:2
```

#### 38 chars

```
~:1g' `j::1g1+\1p;,a.- 'g1,:',:@j`0:;#
```

---

The following prints the spaces exactly as in the output example. It also outputs every single ascii character's count, which, since it is not clearly specified, I'll say is valid.

#### 42 chars

```
~:1g1+\1p;,a+1.- 'g1:,,:,," : ",:@j!`~':;#
```

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, 63

```
$a=@{};[char[]](read-host)|%{$a[$_]++};$a.Keys|%{"$_ :"+$a[$_]}
```

Comment: Each key in a hash can be accessed as a property on that hash, so you can shave off two characters by replacing each instance of `$a[$_]` with `$a.$_` . See `help about_hash_tables`

Answer (score 2):

### Windows Command Script - 72 Bytes

```
set/p.=
:a
set/a\%.:~,1%=\%.:~,1%+1
set.=%.:~1%
%.%goto:b
goto:a
:b
set\
```

**Outputs:**

```
\=15 (space)
\.=1
\a=10
\c=1
\d=4
\e=8
\f=2
\g=3
\h=3
\i=10
\m=1
\n=10
\o=4
\p=3
\q=1
\r=2
\s=5
\T=7
\u=1
\x=1
\y=1
```

Comment: Nice!  It does fold case though, but it's always amazing to see actual cleverness in batch file programming.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 23 chars

```
(~.;"0+/@|:@=)/:~1!:1]1
```

Slightly different output format (line 2 is stdin):

```
   (~.;"0+/@|:@=)/:~1!:1]1
Mississippi
┌─┬─┐
│M│1│
├─┼─┤
│i│4│
├─┼─┤
│p│2│
├─┼─┤
│s│4│
└─┴─┘
```

Answer (score 2):

C#

```
string str = Console.ReadLine(); // Get Input From User Here
char chr;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    chr = (char)i; // Use The Integer Index As ASCII Char Value --> Convert To Char
    if (str.IndexOf(chr) != -1) // If The Current Char Exists In The Input String
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chr + " : " + str.Count(x => x == chr)); // Count And Display
    }
}
Console.ReadLine(); // Hold The Program Open.
```

In Our Case, If The Input Will Be "**The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.**"

The Output Will Be:

```
  : 15
. : 1
T : 1
a : 10
c : 1
d : 4
e : 8
f : 2
g : 3
h : 3
i : 10
m : 1
n : 10
o : 4
p : 3
q : 1
r : 2
s : 5
t : 6
u : 1
x : 1
y : 1
```

Comment: The question asks for input from the keyboard, so the first line should be `string str = Console.ReadLine();`. But this is [tag:code-golf] so it should actually be `var str=Console.ReadLine();`. The other comments I would like to make have to be put on hold until OP improves the question.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 22 characters

```
(~.;"0+/@(=/~.))1!:1]1
```

Example:

```
   (~.;"0+/@(=/~.))1!:1]1
The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.
+-+--+
|T|1 |
+-+--+
|h|3 |
+-+--+
|e|8 |
+-+--+
| |15|
+-+--+
|d|4 |
+-+--+
|f|2 |
+-+--+
|i|10|
+-+--+
|n|10|
+-+--+
|t|6 |
+-+--+
|o|4 |
+-+--+
|s|5 |
+-+--+
|a|10|
+-+--+
|y|1 |
+-+--+
|q|1 |
+-+--+
|u|1 |
+-+--+
|g|3 |
+-+--+
|m|1 |
+-+--+
|p|3 |
+-+--+
|r|2 |
+-+--+
|x|1 |
+-+--+
|c|1 |
+-+--+
|.|1 |
+-+--+
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#: 129

This is Avivs answer but shorter:

```
var s=Console.ReadLine();for(int i=0;i<256;i++){var ch=(char)i;Console.Write(s.Contains(ch)?ch+":"+s.Count(c=>c==ch)+"\r\n":"");}
```

This is mine:

### C#: 103

```
foreach(var g in Console.ReadLine().OrderBy(o=>o).GroupBy(c=>c))Console.WriteLine(g.Key+":"+g.Count());
```

Comment: Won't compile, need to add about 50 chars for usings/namespace/class/method definitions.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that was mandatory, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 (90 chars)

```
import collections as c;print"\n".join("%s %s"%i for i in c.Counter(raw_input()).items())
```

Output when run on its own source:

```
  8
" 4
% 3
) 4
( 4
. 3
; 1
C 1
\ 1
_ 1
a 2
c 4
e 3
f 1
i 9
j 1
m 2
l 2
o 6
n 7
p 3
s 5
r 5
u 2
t 6
w 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript <del>30</del> 27

```
:x.|{.{=}+x\,,`': '\n]''+}/
```

Explanation:

```
:x #Assign the input string to a variable x
.| #Copy the input string, and then OR it with itself to get the unique characters
```

Now, for each distinct character, we will perform the ``` {.{=}+x\,,``': '\n]''+} ``` block.  For example, for the first iteration, the character will be 'T'.

```
.{=}+ #Generate the equality checking block.  {'T'=} is left on the stack
x #Put the input string on the stack.
\ #Flip the top elements  So the stack is now the input strick followed by the equality checking block.
, #Filter the input string by the equality checking block.  
, #Count the number of equal characters.
`': '\n #Format the string and add a newline character
] #Collect the elements into an array
''+ #Convert the array into a string
```

Comment: How do I put a single grave accent ` in a code block?

Answer (score 2):

## newLISP - 76 characters

```
(bayes-train(explode(read-line))'D)(map(fn(f)(println(f 0) ": "(f 1 0)))(D))
```

Reads from keyboard, builds a Bayes-trained context namespace, then outputs entries. It's hard to golf with the handicap of readable function names... :)

Answer (score 2):

**Scala, 64 chars**

```
readLine.groupBy(y=>y).foreach(g=>println(g._1+" : "+g._2.size))
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 17 bytes

(Outputs the result exactly in the expected format.)

```
({.,': ',".@#)/.~
```

Example:

```
      (({.,': ',":@#)/.~) 'The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.'
T: 1 
h: 3 
e: 8
...
```

### Shorter alternatives:

9 bytes:

```
  ({.;#)/.~

  (({.;#)/.~) 'The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.'
┌─┬──┐
│T│1 │
├─┼──┤
│h│3 │
├─┼──┤
│e│8 │
...
```

7 bytes:

```
      ~.;#/.~

      (~.;#/.~)'The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.'
┌──────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│The dfintosayqugmprxc.│1 3 8 15 4 2 10 10 6 4 5 10 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 1 1 1│
└──────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Here the output is a list of characters (i.e. string) and a list of occurrences of the corresponding characters.

Comment: You could try to laminate maybe.

Comment: @FUZxxl Where? I have different types so I would have to format the numbers first.

Comment: Indeed. Doesn't make it any shorter. I thought about something along the lines of `~.,&<"0#/.~` but that's too long.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 145 bytes

```pascal
var c:char;a:array[0..255]of word;i:word;begin repeat read(c);Inc(a[ord(c)])until eof;for i:=0to 255do if a[i]>0then writeln(chr(i),':',a[i])end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xbsMwDER/hVtsIDWMAllkpHv3boYHVqIsAi6lUErTfL3LZMp0d3jAwxWsHre3WPy@/6KCdz6hTuhQFe/zOAzvp9OSI9yyhondM75pZQGlQtgsMHS@nz7FdzgbtrH0V2m8AeU4xazA7jy2DKYKGTgCzrx8jC2RwE250SadT9pxfzy4w/FBe5Iw7PtXIggUWbhxFrAfLBVt3YErXK65saxgIqj4Q1CSYiXAFe0fSnhpkhvQXyHfTFgLsg7/)

Comment: It should be mentioned that `a` needs to be initialized with zeros. By definition `var`iables of “unmanaged” data types are uninitialized. You make use of the zero-initialization as common in modern multi-user _operating systems_, which prevents data leaks between users/processes.

Comment: This is code golf, where the normal rules of programming go out the window, in the quest to find the golfiest solution. Compiler warnings and whatnot do not matter :)

Answer (score 2):

## [SuperMarioLang](https://github.com/charliealejo/SuperMarioLang), 449 bytes

```
     >++++)
    >^====+  (+++<
>,[!^= (< +======"          *-<
"==#=  =" +      )      ======"
   >%+>[!%+      )         >&[!
   "====# +            )   "==#=====================
!        <>+++(-[!))+(%> [!!
#================#====="==##
                          >          (((++*)+*)&+)[!
                          "========================#
                       !)*-&)*-&)*-&)*-&.(((:)).(.(<
                       #==========================="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9RbsMgDIbfOYUhSgRhyQEm4BR7Q6qEVpoirZAFKm2nzyBZ104bn0CY379tiNfZLhezuPBm/LSuUFA8w9AWHmSGA9AsCaSeND5IoAK43CDwQz8IRKRsJECW@S6y/fg2l5aq5Urj9ne@6J3GJU@Ks7nV311b6/9A@GYT5eF00JgxTlsFGmP0p2YXSrcGQRV1DynNf@9ZXh1n@xsrEFmhOgmzfuge95inPTM20pGKWlEj65B1fTlbONqT8y654CGcwPlo8u0TXIT3a0jOT5CyK5qLhfm8mGjBTMZ5MP74EPmQwH7M9jXlhnE2bhm/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
═#8¼K
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=cd2338ac4b&i=The+definition+of+insanity+is+quoting+the+same+phrase+again+and+again+and+not+expect+despair.&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 46 bytes

```python
s=input()
for c in{*s}:print(c,":",s.count(c))
```

[Attempt it Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY0xDsIwDEV3TmExtah0RpW4BSuDlSatB-wQOxIV4iQsXeBOvQ1BZWD7T_rv_-c7TjYKz_MrW9gfllaPxDFbVW-CJHBAfN_po4uJ2CrXbLtto62T_KW6Xq2fPC_n0-ih94GYjIRBQvEVC01ACtcsRjyAlZbixUMcE6oHHJAYkPu_xGLgb9E7K4MakVK7vnwA)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to code golf! I've just added a link to ATO, a site where you can run programs from the browser. Nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-S`, 16 bytes

```
{[a':aNy]}MUQ Yq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbrBS7IKlpSVpuhYbqqMT1a0S_Spja31DAxUiCyHCUNkFN2NDMlIVUlLTMvMySzLz8xTy0xQy84oTgbxKhcxihcLS_JLMvHSFEqCq4sTcVIWCjKLE4lSFxPTEzDyFxLwUJFZefolCakVBanIJ0MDigsTMIj2ILQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
{[a':aNy]}MUQ Yq
               q  ; Read a line of stdin
              Y   ; Yank it into the global variable y
           UQ     ; Remove duplicates
{        }M       ; Map this function to each character:
 [      ]         ;  Return a list containing:
  a               ;   The character
   ':             ;   A colon
     aNy          ;   The number of times the character appears in y
                  ; The result is a list of lists; the -S flag joins each sublist
                  ; on spaces and then joins the whole thing on newlines before
                  ; printing it
```

---

With looser I/O requirements, this could be **12 bytes**:

```
_AE(_Na)MUQa
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbrBS7IKlpSVpuhZr4h1dNeL9EjV9QwMTIUJQmZuJ0UohGakKKalpmXmZJZn5eQr5aQqZecWJQF6lQmaxQmFpfklmXrpCCVBVcWJuqkJBRlFicapCYnpiZp5CYl4KEisvv0QhtaIgNbkEaGBxQWJmkR7cDQA)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 80

```
  // 80
  t=prompt(n={});for(i=0;c=t[i++];)n[c]=-~n[c];for(k in n)console.log(k+': '+n[k])

  // 47 - wrong format, no prompt
  for(i in a=t.split('').sort())console.log(a[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk, 71

```
Stdin nextLine asBag valuesAndCountsDo:[:c :n|(c,' : ')print.n printNL]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3: <s>122</s> <s>120</s> 118 chars

```
_=readLine()!.characters.reduce([Character:Int]()){var r=$0;r[$1]=($0[$1] ?? 0)+1;return r}.map{print("\($0): \($1)")}
```

After running, it waits for user input.

### Input

> The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.

### Result

```
p: 3
n: 10
.: 1
f: 2
o: 4
u: 1
q: 1
d: 4
t: 6
x: 1
a: 10
i: 10
T: 1
m: 1
r: 2
c: 1
s: 5
e: 8
 : 15
g: 3
y: 1
h: 3
```

### Explanation

- `_=` is necessary otherwise you'll get a warning: `result of call to 'map' is unused`
- removing whitespace from `($0[$1] ?? 0)` will result in an error, because swift recognizes `?` as an optional chaining operator.

Thanks to @ais523 for pointing out that there are too many whitespace characters left

Comment: I don't know the language, but are all those spaces in the source necessary? In most languages, it's possible to get some easy improvements to your score by removing whitespace (and when it isn't, it can help to give an explanation of why it's necessary).

Comment: whoops, in my previous edit I removed 2 bytes from the score but somehow i did not remove them from my code. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 77 bytes

```
lmap c [split [gets stdin] ""] {dict inc D $c}
dict ma k\ v $D {puts $k:\ $v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDoMwEAT7vGKFqPOA1DwhHVCc7ANOgO1wB0qEeLtjpUq3I@1ozC05LyslOLSaFjG0I5tCzUvoUVU9Ti/OIMGhQe2u2w9XwtzhQN3gTHsR6vnRoT6unJ8Tw/MgQUxiQByKq1ToA1G89mgSRlh5Ka2MNG2kDBpJAij4vxWigd@JS8@zJpLtnr8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>115</strike> 109 bytes

-6 bytes from @ceilingcat

```c
a[256];main(c,v)char**v;{for(;--c;)for(;*v[c];)a[*v[c]++]++;for(;c<256;)a[++c]&&printf("%c :  %d\n",c,a[c]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69DsIwDIRfxarUqr8MSDAQHoOtdLDctPWAE5JQgRDPHkInpBu@09mno24mihH7/eE4qBuylNSuFS3o6npV78m4UnUdqWqjeu1pUBX2GzRNktoCOqeCX9A0NBSFdSxhKrOc4ASQj1fJWmox/VTqE2O8LBpGPbFwYCNgJmDxmNwL2MP9YQLLDCFdebxpsItDrwHntA9Qxj8SE0A/raaQCr1Fdrsv)

Takes input as command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
q
â ®+S+Uè¥Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxCoNAEEV7T/GxleQwMTZ2Qxx1ApldnQkk1xEEKw@hB9tsme49eLwnRU9pKs4Fx17VVXNux9qmVN5HRse9qLgEReghapTtCzFM7@CiAzxXRi9GHGcyBg0kCtLujzQ4@BP54XlokWS@lsXl9gM)

### Explanation:

```
q
â ®+S+Uè¥Z
            | Set U to:
q           |   Input, split into an array of chars
â           | Return all unique items in U
  ®         | Map through the items; Z = iterative item
   +S+      |   Z + " " +
      Uè¥Z  |   Number of times where Z appears in U
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rOIgritTK1XoWg==&input=IlRoZSBkZWZpbml0aW9uIG9mIGluc2FuaXR5IGlzIHF1b3RpbmcgdGhlIHNhbWUgcGhyYXNlIGFnYWluIGFuZCBhZ2FpbiBhbmQgbm90IGV4cGVjdCBkZXNwYWlyLiIKLVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
i=input()
for c in{*i}:print(c,':',i.count(c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsIwEAR7XnFdYhSloYvEL/jAybHjLbgz9kUiini7MR3djDS7@bCkcmsNd0jebXSXqIU8Qc4rPksuEBv9NCzDhNnr/jPnWnukQGuIEBhUSGNfVO52ECq9djXIRtarys9AORWugXhjCLGsfyRqFN45eOuHNTPK/AU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 35 bytes

```
D,g,@@#,€=b+": "$J
D,f,@,qdA€gBcBJn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsIwDEX3nsIq3bA4ABIQqk5dWLiAaZzUA07aBAlWzsOpuEjIyPbf09Mna2MsZUCPxmzw@/4cbtt2D203NgM6NLjYc7W@n/pRS@eOp@ZSynVmsOxEJUtQCA5EE1V6gSRYHiGLesi1SnRniPNKiYE8iQKp/VsaMvAz8pTrYYok6@4H)

Defines a function `f`, which takes the input as an argument, and returns the complete formatted string.

### Explanation

```
D,g,		; Define a helper function, g
	@@#,	;   that takes 2 arguments		Stack: ['l' 'Hello World']
	€=	; Compare each letter to argument	Stack: [[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]
	b+	; Sum					Stack: [3]
	": "$	; Prepend ': '				Stack: [': ' 3]
	J	; Join together				Stack: [': 3']
		; Return: ': 3'

D,f,		; Define a main function, f
	@,	;   that takes 1 argument		Stack: ['Hello World']
	qd	; Push two copies of unique letters	Stack: [['H' 'e' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'W' 'r' 'd'] ['H' 'e' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'W' 'r' 'd']]
	A	; Push the argument			Stack: [['H' 'e' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'W' 'r' 'd'] ['H' 'e' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'W' 'r' 'd'] 'Hello World']
	€g	; Apply g to each unique letter		Stack: [['H' 'e' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'W' 'r' 'd'] [': 1' ': 1' ': 3' ': 2' ': 1' ': 1' ': 1' ': 1']]
	Bc	; Zip together				Stack: [['H' ': 1'] ['e' ': 1'] ['l' ': 3'] ['o' ': 2'] [' ' ': 1'] ['W' ': 1'] ['r' ': 1'] ['d' ': 1']]
	BJn	; Join all togther, then with newlines
		; Return the full string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
e=>(d={},e.replace(/\S/g,e=>d[e]=d[e]+1||1),[Object.entries(d)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY2xroJAEEV7v@JptZtlRomVybC1vuJRUFggxbo7EAwBA2jyon477vIBxpnJTU7uSeZi7mawfX0doe0cT2UycaKFSx6viLHna2Msi/UpW1eRL1zORRJCxc9nLKM8PV/Yjsjt2Nc8CCcLOdmuHbqGsekq8Zulfzj4sq3q8l@UYmXO1pmVlHLx2Uvv3P/sNpt4@YUMQECkcpWT0gCg5yWiQhdEAEhqHvSAPjyj1uG8g6GYCQIq/OJhdtum@@3uUN2O@6BPbw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
e=>(d={},[...e].map(e=>d[e]=d[e]+1||1),[Object.entries(d)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY3BCsIwDIbvPoV6aqkJDk9C1rN6cAcPHkoPdc3GRDfZpiDqs892DyAm4Ycv@SBn93Bd3la3HurG81CkA6da@PT1WRhEZItXdxNh5w3bNIZK3u9ELkx2OnPeI9d9W3EnvLRyyJu6ay6Ml6YUu0O2xy4c67IqnqIQc3fKvZtLKSe/vezB7XS9XCazP2QAAiJllCGlAUCPTURWWyIAJDUWBsAQgVHrOMHBeBgJIir84@Hhvso2q/W2vB83UR@@)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! You seem to be used to our things :) Even though, don't hesitate to keep only one answer, or to tell us why you are keeping both. Happy golfing!

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 103 bytes

```
select substr(x,level,1),count(*)from t connect by level<=length(x)group by substr(x,level,1)order by 1
```

Test in SQL*PLus

```
SQL> set pages 100
SQL> set heading off
SQL> with t(x) as (select 'The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again and not expect despair.' from dual)
  2  select substr(x,level,1),count(*)from t connect by level<=length(x)group by substr(x,level,1)order by 1
  3  /

              15
    .          1
    T          1
    a         10
    c          1
    d          4
    e          8
    f          2
    g          3
    h          3
    i         10
    m          1
    n         10
    o          4
    p          3
    q          1
    r          2
    s          5
    t          6
    u          1
    x          1
    y          1

    22 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 48 bytes

```
a:qFi32,128{b:0Fj,#a{a@jQ Ci?++bx}b?P Ci.":".bx}
```

I assume you meant printable ascii

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCsIwEEDRqwx12RK0biSbCkLXCl5gQpN0CpmkSYRK8ewxG8Hdf/ADhVJQriOd@@7UX3Ylj@PSHXDH6/KAGw1tq7aPGu61RSMbUVXKc9YwaUNMmTyDN0CcsOoNlGB9@UxsIdcrodMQ5ohJA1okBuTpr9hnMLT9dhvROYziCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes

```julia
s=readline()
Set(s).|>c->println(c,": ",sum(==(c),s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwEADvvmLxlIAVei3oJ9oPLHHVLbpJsxtQ6N9Tj73NwDDvsjHej1p1yITTxkLON08yp77/juE2psxim7jQtQ9oOy27GwYXfKfe1/paCSaaWdg4CsQZWBQvO4EVPiUaywJ2VYo7QVozKgEuyAIo0x9JNKAjUbBrqAk5980P)

Answer (score 1):

## Stax (31 bytes)

```
âpWhuÉñ♫∩Ω╝YT>ⁿë╘Æ↨»╧óPÜ≤♪Ñû1♫à
```

Try it online here:
https://staxlang.xyz/#p=837057687590a40eefeabc59543efc89d49217afcfa2509af30da596310e85&a=1

It has some limitations.  No uppercase letters, and it shows all letters, even if they have zero occurences

Unpacked version:

```
0]6{c+}*,""/{|3b@^&FVw""/{[cp':p|3@PF
^a      ^b  ^c      ^d
```

Section A prepares a list to put the values in.  Section B Gets user input.
Section C counts letters, and section D outputs the result

Comment: Welcome! This does not meet the challenge's specifications. You need to support uppercase and symbols, and you should not show all characters. Your solution must work as shown in the example. It also gives the wrong answer, because it shows `w:15`, but the sample input has no `w`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 bytes

```
ü ®Î+S+Zl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=/CCuzitTK1ps&input=IlRoZSBkZWZpbml0aW9uIG9mIGluc2FuaXR5IGlzIHF1b3RpbmcgdGhlIHNhbWUgcGhyYXNlIGFnYWluIGFuZCBhZ2FpbiBhbmQgbm90IGV4cGVjdCBkZXNwYWlyLiI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
Ċ⟑`%: %`$%,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEiuKfkWAlOiAlYCQlLCIsIiIsIlwiVGhlIGRlZmluaXRpb24gb2YgaW5zYW5pdHkgaXMgcXVvdGluZyB0aGUgc2FtZSBwaHJhc2UgYWdhaW4gYW5kIGFnYWluIGFuZCBub3QgZXhwZWN0IGRlc3BhaXIuXCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 78 bytes

```
=LET(c,CHAR(ROW(1:255)),q,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,c,)),FILTER(c&": "&q,q>0))
```

Input is in cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

- `LET(~)` stores values as variables that can be referenced later. The last term is the output.
- `c,CHAR(ROW(1:255))` stores the extended ASCII table as `c`.
- `q,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,c,))` stores a list `q` of how much shorter the input would be if you removed each ASCII character in turn.
- `FILTER(c&": "&q,q>0)` combines `c` and `q` into the desired output format and then filters the list to just show those that actually appear in the input.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 42 bytes

```powershell
$input|% t*y|group|%{$_.Name+":"+$_.Count}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsIwDEWvYlXtQkUPwMrOxI6s1k0sFTskjkpFOHvIyPa@9P4LulNMnrbtPGukWnuWkK0MYKejuKg5lOHTP6YbPmnsLt3Y@KpZ7Fvr3RMstLKwsQroCiwJ2zqAE7yyGosDa1Zqbwg@YiJAhyyAsvyRqAG9A83Wgikgx@kH)

Converts the input into an array of characters
Group them and builds a string like `<char>:<count>` for each of them

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 41 bytes

```arturo
loop tally input""[x,y]->print~"|x|: |y|"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

Heavily inspired by @Shaggy 's work.

Would be **34 bytes** if it were acceptable to have an unwanted string `[Function: g]` contained in the output ( by having `&&g` at the end instead of `&&Object.entries(g)` ).

```javascript
s=>[...s].map(g=c=>g[c]=-~g[c])&&Object.entries(g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDoMwEAS/cqJApsA/MF9Ikw5RXMzZHIKzwzlR0uTrDulS7Y60ml3xieoPzqWXNFMNrqobRmutTnbHbKLzboijn1z/@UXXtpfbSr5YknIwqYld9Uk0bWS3FE0wzXUhmCmwcOEkkAKwKJ70Bla4P1JhiVDOleJOkJcDlQAjsgDK/NckFaBXPu9OoWbkwzZdV78)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ÙvyD¹s¢‚})
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w5l2eUTCuXPCouKAmn0p&input=VGhlIGRlZmluaXRpb24gb2YgaW5zYW5pdHkgaXMgcXVvdGluZyB0aGUgc2FtZSBwaHJhc2UgYWdhaW4gYW5kIGFnYWluIGFuZCBub3QgZXhwZWN0IGRlc3BhaXIu)

> The definition of insanity is quoting the same phrase again and again
> and not expect despair.

```
[['T', 1], ['h', 3], ['e', 8], [' ', 15], ['d', 4], ['f', 2], ['i', 10], ['n', 10], ['t', 6], ['o', 4], ['s', 5], ['a', 10], ['y', 1], ['q', 1], ['u', 1], ['g', 3], ['m', 1], ['p', 3], ['r', 2], ['x', 1], ['c', 1], ['.', 1]]
```

Comment: 7 bytes: SÙDŠ¢‚ø
12 bytes: SÙDŠ¢‚ø„: ý» (provided that the result needs to be displayed according to the challenge specifications)

Comment: @Kaldo 80% sure this answer was before we had `zip` even hah! Will update.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 47 bytes

```factor
readln histogram [ "%c %d\n"printf ] assoc-each
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY07DgIxDESvMlqJkj0AHADR0AAVUFj5bCyx9hIbCU4fImjo5qc3mYJrbefj/rDbgMw0GLLWmdxZJrCiyzKak7M593bbaqJ4F5Qe6FRpxgXDKmAVrzIslcUzbj/WOlEorZ1KQkyZhZ1VoBksRt29wYbHU79f3ldGc8JSKlkCTcQCkvinRB3ptaTgHWgLcR0/)

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal, 208 B

See also [Free Pascal](/a/171139/94076).
This is a *complete* `program` according to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” though.
Note, this `program` does not count newlines.
The variable `input` possesses the built-in data type `text`, which automatically converts any newline indicator (sometimes it’s CR, sometimes LF, sometimes CR+LF, other times something completely differently) into a single space character (`' '`).
In order to distinguish between a space character as part/payload of a line vs. a space character *terminating* a line you’ll have to query `EOLn`.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var c:char;s:array[char]of integer value[otherwise 0];begin while not EOF do begin read(c);s[c]:=s[c]+ord(not EOLn)end;for c:=chr(0)to maxChar do if 0<s[c]then writeLn(c:2,s[c]:9)end.
```

Ungolfed and annotated version:

```pascal
program characterCount(input, output);
    var
        c: char;
        spreadsheet: array[char] of integer value [otherwise 0];
    begin
        { `EOF` is shorthand for `EOF(input)`. }
        while not EOF do
        begin
            { `read(c)` is shorthand for `read(input, c)`. }
            read(c);
            { If we are `read`ing from a `text` file like `input`,
              newlines are converted to a single space character.
              This is avoiding the drama of LF vs. CR vs. CR+LF.
              Therefore we’ll need to check `EOLn` so we aren’t
              counting line-terminating spaces (the value of `c`). }
            spreadsheet[c] := spreadsheet[c] + ord(not EOLn)
        end;
        
        { Note, in Pascal `for`-loop limits are inclusive.
          The constant `maxChar` is introduced in Extended Pascal. }
        for c := chr(0) to maxChar do
        begin
            if 0 < spreadsheet[c] then
            begin
                writeLn(c:2, spreadsheet[c]:9)
            end
        end
    end.
```

See also [RosettaCode’s *Letter frequency* task](https://RosettaCode.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Pascal).

Comment: 147 bytes: `var c:char;s:array[char]of word;begin fillChar(s,512,0);repeat read(c);inc(s[c]);until EOF;for c:=#0to #255do if 0<s[c]then writeLn(c:2,s[c]:9)end.`

Comment: @tsh I think you meant to post this to the linked [FreePascal](/a/171139/94076) answer. My answer concerns Pascal as defined by ISO standards.

Comment: I'm not sure what ISO standard mean. I believe it also works with Turbo Pascal although I didn't test it...

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƈıðj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhbLj3Uc2Xh4Q9aS4qTkYqjYgpuxIRmpCimpaZl5mSWZ-XkK-WkKmXnFiUBepUJmsUJhaX5JZl66QglQVXFibqpCQUZRYnGqQmJ6YmaeQmJeChIrL79EIbWiIDW5BGhgcUFiZpEexBYA)

Uses   as the separator, like a lot of the other answers.

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƈı`: j
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhYrjnUc2ZhgpZC1pDgpuRgquOBmbEhGqkJKalpmXmZJZn6eQn6aQmZecSKQV6mQWaxQWJpfkpmXrlACVFWcmJuqUJBRlFicqpCYnpiZp5CYl4LEyssvUUitKEhNLgEaWFyQmFmkB7EFAA)

Uses `:`  as the separator, like the challenge asks.

##### Explanation

```python
ƈıðj  # Implicit input
ƈ     # Produce a list of [item, count] pairs for
      # each unique character in the input string
 ı    # Map over this list of pairs:
  ðj  #  Join the pair by a space
      # Implicit output, joined by newlines

ƈı`: j  # Implicit input
ƈı      # As above
  `: j  #  Join the pair by ": "
        # Implicit output, joined by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 20 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.5 bytes

```
ĊvṄ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJqPSIsIiIsIsSKduG5hCIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIGdhbWVycyJd)

Given that any character can be used, I figured I'd add an answer that doesn't have strict IO.

### Explained

```
ĊvṄ
Ċ   # Counts of characters
 vṄ # each joined on spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 54 bytes

```clj
(doseq[[k v](frequencies(read-line))](println k": "v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7DoMwEAWvsqKyi@QAOUc6RLGyH7CBrD9rUHJ6hzLdjDSasKfXUdG7i8lQxnGjc3JzRTmgQWCuguNtF4X3k8tVtO1K2/Cg4fS@9@cKiphFpUlSSjOJGl/2JTEqR2qiC7WrMn6D8lrZQLywKLHGP9LUCJ@M0K6hZZZ6/wE)