# Three-Three-Three!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Write a program that produces an output such that:

1. At least three distinct characters appear.
2. The number of occurrences of each character is a multiple of 3.

For example, `A TEA AT TEE` is a valid output since each of the 4 distinct characters, `A`, `E`, `T` and `(space)`, occurs 3 times.

Of course, a challenge about the number 3 needs to have a third requirement. So:

3. The program itself must also follow the first two requirements. (This means your program will be at least 9 bytes long.)

You must write a full program, not a function. Be sure to show your program's output in your answer.

Also, to keep things interesting, you are highly encouraged:

- *not* to use comments to meet requirement 3 if you can help it
- to produce output that isn't just a string repeated 3 times
- to make the output different from the program itself (for languages that can automatically output the contents of its own program, [you can contribute to this community wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108142/47097)).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Do newlines count (as a distinct character) ?

Comment: Are programs that consist entirely of literals allowed? (There are a lot of languages where `123123123` will work, as currently written.)

Comment: @ais523 Thanks for pointing that out. Since a few such answers have already been posted, I've updated the question to simply discourage them.

Comment: @zeppelin Yes, newlines count as a distinct character.

Comment: Is a trailing newline allowed?

Comment: @ETHproductions If you need it to satisfy requirement 2, most definitely.

Comment: What I mean to ask is, can a program output e.g. `abcabcabc` with a trailing newline?

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah, I see. No, that is not allowed. Three trailing newlines would be acceptable, however.

Comment: Are Null bytes as one of the 3 characters acceptable?

Comment: @Mistah Figgins Yes, any character goes.

Comment: You know what would make quite an interesting CG? To produce the shortest programs which could verify solutions to this CG

Comment: Is outputting to stderr allowed? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108133/three-three-three/108180?noredirect=1#comment263268_108180 and http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/2451#2451

Comment: I don't think stderr should be allowed, personally. It should be noted that the amount of downvotes on that meta answer shows how controversial it is. Some recent challenge answers have put stderr answers as CW for that reason.

Comment: The challenge title doesn't meet the criteria, lol

Answer (score 60):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), [Flakcats](https://github.com/Flakheads/Flakcats), [Brain-Flueue](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@////39d3ZzEvPTSxPRU26SixMy8tJzS1NJUAA), [Brain-Flak Classic](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/tree/9f22727cc08fc7f48be11393ecfe44db331de55a), [Miniflak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@////39d3ZzEvPTSxPRU29zMvMy0nMRsAA), and [Fλak](https://github.com/Flakheads/f-ak) 18 bytes

***Proven optimal!***

```
((([()][()][()])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hoREdHa2hCYKxsbGampr//wMA)

### Explanation

#### Brain-Flak, Brain-Flueue, Miniflak, and Fλak

```
   ([()][()][()]) Push -3
  (              ) Copy
 (                ) Copy
```

This prints:

```
-3
-3
-3
```

*(There is a trailing newline)*

#### Brain-Flak Classic

Brain-Flak Classic is the original version of Brain-Flak and has some important differences from modern Brain-Flak.  In BFC `[...]` prints its contents rather than negating it.

```
   [()] Print 1
       [()] Print 1
           [()] Print 1
  (            ) Push 3
 (              ) Push 3
(                ) Push 3
```

At the end of executing the contents of the stack (`3 3 3`) is printed.

This prints:

```
1
1
1
3
3
3
```

*(There is a trailing newline)*

#### Flakcats

Flakcats is quite different from the other 4 flaks and I am surprised that this works in Flakcats.  The three operators here are nearly the same as the ones that Brain-Flak uses.

The main difference in this particular program between Flakcats is the `(...)` operator which in Flakcats is equivalent to `([{}]...)` in Brain-Flak.  This however does not make a difference to us because it picks up zeros and thus operates much in the same way that Brain-Flak does.

Here is that program compiled into Brian-Flak:

```
([{}]([{}]([{}][()][()][()])))
```

This prints:

```
-3
-3
-3
```

*(There is a trailing newline)*

### Proof of Optimality in [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) and Miniflak

*This is not a formal proof, but rather an informal proof that would have to be expanded to be made more rigorous*

Because of the restrictions that Brain-Flak programs must be a balanced-string and the program length must be a multiple of 3 any valid submission must be a multiple of 6 in length.  This means any solution smaller than 18 must be length 12.

Because of the outputs trailing newline the final height of the stack must be a multiple of three or we will break the restrictions on output.

Any valid submission of length 12 must have 2 types of braces (having less would break the restrictions on number of distinct characters and more would mean more than 12 characters).  Since the program produces output it must have a push.

This leaves us to select our other set of braces.  The options are:

#### `<...>/<>`

This fails because we need to generate "value" in order to create any number other than zero we must give up a `()` to create a one which makes it impossible to push more than two times.

---

#### `[...]/[]`

This fails for the same reason the last failed.  The square braces are really bad at making value.  The `[]` monad *can* create value but we need to push numbers first and we then don't have enough parens left over to push three times.

---

#### `{...}/{}`

This one is promising,  we could create a loop and use one `()` to push multiple times, but alas it is not possible.

In order for the loop to end there must be a zero on the stack at some point and in order for us to have the correct output we must have something other than zero on the stack at the end of the program.  Since we have neither `[]` nor `<>` the zero at the end of the loop *must* be a implicit zero from the bottom of the stack.  This means the loop cannot add any new numbers to the stack making it useless.

---

Since none of the brace choices can create a program of length 12 none can exist.

Since Miniflak is a subset of Brain-Flak any shorter Miniflak program would also be a shorter Brain-Flak program and thus does not exist.

### Proof of Optimality in [Brain-Flueue](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@////39d3ZzEvPTSxPRU26SixMy8tJzS1NJUAA)

Brain-Flueue is a joke language based off of Brain-Flak.  The two are so similar their interpreters are identical everywhere but two lines.  The difference between the two is, as their names suggests, Brain-Flueue stores its data in queues while Brain-Flak stores its data in stacks.

To start we have the same restrictions on program size created by Brain-Flak, thus we are looking for a program of size 12.  In addition we are going to need a `(...)` in order to create any output and another pair.  the `<>` and `[]` pairs do not work in Brain-Flueue for the exact same reason they do not work in Brain-Flak.

Now we know that our program must consist of the characters `((())){{{}}}`.

Via the same methods used in the previous proof we can demonstrate that there must be a loop in the final program.

Now here is where the proofs differ, because Brain-Flueue operates across queues rather than stacks the program can exit a loop with values on the queue.

In order to exit the loop we will need a zero in the queue (or an empty queue but if the queue is empty we get the same problem as Brain-Flak) this will mean that we will have to open our program with `({})` to create the zero.  We will need a push inside of the loop to push the necessary number of items to the queue.  We will also need to push a non zero number before the loop so that we can enter the loop at all;  this will cost us at absolute minimum `(())`.  We have now used more parens than we have.

Thus there is no Brain-Flueue program to do the task that is 12 bytes, and furthermore there our program is optimal.

### Optimal solution in [Flakcats](https://github.com/Flakheads/Flakcats) and [Brain-Flak Classic](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/tree/9f22727cc08fc7f48be11393ecfe44db331de55a)

The following solution is optimal in Flakcats and Brain-Flak Classic.

```
((([][][])))
```

---

#### Explanation

```
    [][][] -3
 (((      ))) push 3 times
```

### Alternative 24 byte Brain-Flak solutions

```
(<((<((<(())>)())>)())>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69howFFmpp2mgji/38A)

```
((<((<((<>)())>)())>)())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hYQNBdpoampoI4v9/AA)

```
((((((()()()){}){}){})))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BAZogqFldC0Wamv//AwA)

Comment: +1 for the proof as well.

Comment: +1 for the polyglot as well, esp. not all outputs are the same.

Answer (score 31):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
**‘‘‘888*
```

A full program which prints **700227072**, which is 888 cubed.

**[TryItOnline!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6@l9ahhBgRZWFho/f8PAA)**

#### How?

```
**‘‘‘888* - Main link: no arguments
          - implicit L=R=0
*         - power       A = L ^ R = 1
  ‘       - increment   B = L + 1 = 1
 *        - power       C = A ^ B = 1
   ‘      - increment   D = C + 1 = 2
    ‘     - increment   E = D + 1 = 3
     888  - literal     F = 888
        * - power           F ^ E = 700227072
```

Comment: `888^3` is `700227072`? That's very clever, perhaps other languages can use this trick.

Answer (score 24):

## Polyglot of purely literal answers, 9 bytes

```
333111222
```

This is a community wiki post for collecting answers that are just a literal that the language in question prints out automatically. Because it's a community wiki, feel free to edit it to add more languages where it works.

This program works in:

- [PHP](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- HTML (arguably not a language)
- [Jelly](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA) (and [M](https://tio.run/nexus/m#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA))
- [7](https://tio.run/nexus/7#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA) (more interesting, because the program's interpreted as both data *and* code; the first `3` prints the data, the rest of the program is useless stack manpulation)
- [CJam](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Japt](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)
- [R](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=VQ4Zcpa4) (the R display also outputs [1] as metadata)
- [RProgN](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Actually](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA) (though it actually prints `2\n2\n2\n1\n1\n1\n3\n3\n3\n`)
- [///](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=333222111&input=&run=false)
- TI-Basic
- [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate)
- [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex)
- [Husk](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39jY2NDQ0MjI6P9/AA)
- [Resource](https://tio.run/##K0ot/v/f2NjY0NDQyMjo/38A) (although this outputs the string reversed)
- `cat`

Ignoring the final newline, this is valid in quite a few more languages:

- [05AB1E](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [2sable](https://tio.run/nexus/2sable#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [GolfScript](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [PowerShell](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- m4 (any version, the program is portable)
- [Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [MATL](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Stax](https://tio.run/nexus/stax#@29sbGxoaGhkZPT/PwA)
- [Ink](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/f2NjY0NDQyMjo/38A)
- [Keg](https://tio.run/##y05N///f2NjY0NDQyMjo/38A)
- [Vyxal](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com)

Most links go to Try It Online!

Comment: This prints `2\n2\n2\n1\n1\n1\n3\n3\n3\n` in Actually, which is perfectly valid. Should that be added to the post?

Comment: @ETHproductions I actually think Actually should be added to the post since it uses the same code ;)

Comment: As the person who made Actually, I agree that it belongs in this post. The newlines don't really make a difference.

Comment: This also works on the language I've written: [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate). It will compile it into an over-kill `echo '333111222';` (in PHP) but it works.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Feel free to edit it into the answer yourself. It's a community wiki, that's how they work.

Comment: @ais523 I find that very intrusive. If ETHproductions doesn't find the language minimally interesting or doesn't like me or just having a cold, he doesn't have to have his pristine answer ruined by someone shoehorning his language into the list.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: This is a [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/347902) answer; it was only 29% written by ETHproductions (and in fact, it was me who originally created the answer, as you can see from the revision history; ETHproductions has more text in the current version of the answer than anyone else, but definitely isn't responsible for the whole thing). Its entire purpose is to be edited by a large range of users as a collaborative effort. (This is distinct from normal answers, which aren't designed to be edited.)

Answer (score 22):

### C#, <s>114</s> <s>111</s> <s>118</s> 102 bytes

If we don't care about using proper words: (102 bytes)

```
class CCcddiilMMmmnrrSSsttvvWWyy{static void Main(){{System.Console.Write(("A TEA AT TEE"));;;}}}///".
```

If we care about proper words: (120 bytes)

```
class erebeWyvern{static void Main(){int embedWildbanana;{System.Console.Write(("A TEA AT TEE"));;}}}///CC Myst mvcSMS".
```

My original submission - case insensitive: (113 bytes)

```
class EreBeWyvern{static void Main(){int embedwildbanana; {System.Console.Write(("A TEA AT TEE"));;}}}/// vyt".
```

I know the comment isn't really in the spirit of the CG, but it's all I could come up with in a limited amount of time, I'll see if I can improve it through the day. Surely I must get at least some bonus points for the nod to being adventurous.

Edit: Thank you to roberto06 for catching the missing letters!

Comment: I'm a C++ guy, not C#, but can you not just wrap the Write call in {()} without affecting it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The curly braces work, the parentheses don't

Comment: You might be able to put the parentheses around the argument, rather than the call as a whole.

Comment: Right you are! It's looking better with every edit! (although not getting any shorter sadly)

Comment: Brownie points for the wild banana.

Comment: I'm confused... The question states, "The number of occurrences of each character is a multiple of 3." I only see 1 newline, 1 `S`, 4 `E`s, 1 `C`, etc. I think it's case sensitive. (`S` is clearly not `s`)

Comment: @MistahFiggins In fairness to the competition I have revised my submission, but I I have kept the original entry because I'm quite proud of what I managed to come up with in 10mins (plus some help from commenters)

Comment: Nice! I like the variable names. +1

Comment: You should remove `V` from your comment, and add `vyt`, since `V`is only present there while `v` is present twice (typo, I guess), `y` is also present twice, and `t` is present 5 times. [See here](https://eval.in/724596). Nevertheless, awesome job !

Comment: "embedWildbanana". I agree with Mistah Figgins.

Answer (score 21):

## JavaScript, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
alert(((alert|alert||333111222)))
```

Alerts `333111222`. This works because `|` converts both of its operands to 32-bit integers, and any value that doesn't look anything like an integer (e.g. the function `alert`) gets converted to `0`. `0|0` is `0`, so the `||` operator returns its right operand, or `333111222`

A few more interesting versions:

```
(a="(trelalert)\\\"")+alert(a+=a+=a)
```

Outputs `(trelalert)\"(trelalert)\"(trelalert)\"`.

A solution using `.repeat` would be the same length, thanks to the shared `aert`:

```
alert("(trpp.all)\\\"".repeat(3.33))
```

which outputs `(trpp.all)\"(trpp.all)\"(trpp.all)\"`.

Taking advantage of the extra backslashes to get rid of `l` and `p` *almost* works:

```
a\x6cert("(trax.cc)\"".re\x70eat(6.00677))
```

This one outputs `(trax.cc)"(trax.cc)"(trax.cc)"(trax.cc)"(trax.cc)"(trax.cc)"`.

Comment: Nice abuse of decimals!

Comment: @darrylyeo Heh, thanks. I could've easily stuck those in the string, but that wouldn't be as fun ;-)

Comment: Thought I'd let you know you were topped by an [ES6 answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108313/47097).

Answer (score 15):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
10,10,10,
```

Outputs `012345678901234567890123456789`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29ooANB//8DAA)

**Explanation**

```
10,       The range from 0 to 9
   10,    The range from 0 to 9
      10, The range from 0 to 9
```

Comment: doesn't 3,3,3, work for 7 bytes?

Comment: Ah! yeah, the third requirement :)

Comment: Argh, a missed opportunity to use `99,99,99,`, because why not?

Comment: @workoverflow Because that doesn't work with the third requirement. The program needs to contain three distinct characters.

Comment: @DLosc Touche, I forgot about that!

Answer (score 13):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 12 bytes

```
++[+...][][]
```

Nobody said the output had to be short. This will output 3 copies of every ascii character except the first 2.

You can prove that this is as short as it will get. You need to output therefore you need 3 '.' there need to be different outputs therefore you need 3 [+-] now we're up to 6. 9 characters have to be printed, which means either adding 6 more '.' or adding a loop, which will add another 6 characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@6@tHa2tp6cXGw2E//8DAA)

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, <s>36</s> 30 bytes

Since a trailing newline isn't allowed, this is probably as short as it can get:

```python
print"\\\""*3;print;print;3**3
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXohQTE6OkpGVsDeZBSWMtLeP//wE)

Outputs `\"` three times, followed by three newlines.

---

The below programs don't count the trailing newline, so they're not valid.

**27 bytes**:

```python
print"""printprint"""*3*3*3
```

Prints 54 of each character in `print`.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXoqSkBKZhHC1jEPz/HwA)

---

**Same length, shorter output:**

```python
print"""printprint*3*3"""*3
```

Outputs `printprint*3*3printprint*3*3printprint*3*3`

---

**24 bytes:**

```python
print~9;print~9;print~9;
```

Comment: You could do `print"""printprint*3*3"""*3` for a much shorter output ;-)

Comment: Could you not do `print 123;print 123;print 123;` for the naive solution?

Comment: OP has clarified that the single trailing newline is not allowed (see comments).

Comment: @ETHproductions Sure. It depends how naive we're being.

Comment: @FlipTack Fixed it, and I feel like I just hit an optimal solution for when the trailing newline isn't forgiven.

Comment: Even more naive: `print~9;print~9;print~9;`

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 15 bytes

```
.say;.say;.say;
```

Prints six distinct characters, three times each:

```
(Any)
(Any)
(Any)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@69XnFhpjSD@/wcA)

#### How it works

- A bare method call operates on the current topic, `$_`.
- `$_` starts out as the [type object](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Type_Objects) of type `Any`, which `say` prints as `(Any)`.

Comment: Now I've got a [Yeah Yeah Yeahs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIIxlgcuQRU) song stuck in my head.

Answer (score 9):

### [PKod](https://github.com/PKTINOS/PKod), 9 bytes

```
sonsonson
```

Outputs: 111222333

---

### Explanation:

```
Background: PKod has only one variable that you mess with, with the code
This variable starts with default value of 0

s  -  Add next char to the variable, and jump over it. 
n  -  Print numeric value of variable
```

o has ascii char code "111" in decimal. Thus s adds 111 to the variable, then prints the number. First "son" makes it 111 and prints 111. Next makes it 222 and prints 222, lastly makes it 333 and prints 333

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
p$@;p$@;p$@;
```

outputs

```ruby
nil
nil
nil
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@1@g4mANw///AwA)

To fulfill the second "encouraged" criterion, I need 15 characters:

```ruby
p 1;p 3;p 1133;
```

produces

```ruby
1
3
1133
```

[Try it online too!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@1@gYGhdoGAMxIaGxsbW//8DAA)

Answer (score 9):

## C, 66 Bytes

```
main(i){{for(i=0;i<3;i++){printf("""poop+fart=<3<3at0m=m0n""");}}}
```

#### Output

```
poop+fart=<3<3at0m=m0npoop+fart=<3<3at0m=m0npoop+fart=<3<3at0m=m0n
```

#### Old Version 72 Bytes

```
main(i){for(i=0;i<3;i++){printf("poop+fart=<3<3 at {\"0m=m0\"}" "\n");}}
```

Comment: Not only your code is much smaller than what I did, but it also contains real bits of poop and farts. Bravo.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```
+alert((({alert}+{alert}+{})))
```

Outputs `[object Object][object Object][object Object]`.

Works by creating three objects:

- the first two are of the form `{ "alert" : alert }` using ES6 notation `{alert}`
- the third is a simple empty object

Then it uses `+` to concatenate them together, and all three have an identical expression as a string, `[object Object]`.

The leading `+` is useless, only present to fill out the number of `+` characters, but is harmless to the output of the program.

Comment: Way to beat the other JS answer!

Comment: You should also add `(ES6)` to the title.

Comment: @darrylyeo Thanks! :) And I added ES6

Answer (score 8):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 9 bytes

```
x!!xx@@!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@1@hqFhR4eCg6PD/PwA)

Print out `120120120`. `x` can be replaced by `f-m` (102-109)

#### Explanation

```
  x ! ! 
 x x @ @
! @ . . .
```

The `xx@@` is only a filler to comply with the rules.  The main flow is saving `x` into the memory (with ASCII value 120) and then print it as a number 3 times.

Answer (score 7):

## Microscript II, 9 bytes

```
{{{~~~}}}
```

Explanation: Creates a code block, but doesn't invoke it. When execution ends, the contents of the main register (IE this code block) are implicitly printed.

Comment: Have you posted something similar in the Quine challenge?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 `{}` would technically be a quine, but I don't think it meets our definition of a "proper quine". The program `"q"q` (which I did submit to the quine challenge) does, however.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: That wouldn't be a *proper* quine, because each character represents itself.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>15</s> 9 bytes

```bash
id;id;id;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@ZYg1B////BwA)

Sample Output:

```bash
uid=1000 gid=1000 groups=1000 context=system_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_t:s0-s0:c19,c100,c173,c211
uid=1000 gid=1000 groups=1000 context=system_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_t:s0-s0:c19,c100,c173,c211
uid=1000 gid=1000 groups=1000 context=system_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_t:s0-s0:c19,c100,c173,c211
```

(If you try this out, it will print your uid, gid, etc., 3 times.)

---

If you want to avoid repeating the same string 3 times (and also have the same output for everybody, unlike my first answer), the best I've found for bash + Unix utilities is 15 bytes long:

```bash
dc<<<cczdzfzfdf
```

[Try this second version online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SbGNjk5xclVKVVpWWkvb//38A)

Output:

```bash
2
0
0
3
2
0
0
3
3
2
0
0
```

(No newlines in the program, 12 newlines in the output.)

Explanation of the dc program in this answer:

```bash
c Clears the stack.
Stack: (empty)

c Clears the stack.
Stack: (empty)

z Pushes the current size of the stack (0) onto the stack.
Stack: (top) 0

d Duplicates the item at the top of the stack.
Stack: (top) 0 0

z Pushes the current size of the stack (2) onto the stack.
Stack: (top) 2 0 0

f Prints the stack, top to bottom, with a newline after each item printed (this prints the first 3 lines of the output, 2 / 0 / 0 /)

z Pushes the current size of the stack (3) onto the stack.
Stack: (top) 3 2 0 0

f Prints the stack, top to bottom, with a newline after each item printed (this prints the next 4 lines of the output, 3 / 2 / 0 / 0 /)

d Duplicates the item at the top of the stack.
Stack: (top) 3 3 2 0 0

f Prints the stack, top to bottom, with a newline after each item printed (this prints the final 5 lines of the output, 3 / 3 / 2 / 0 / 0 /)
```

Comment: How does the second one work?

Comment: @therealfarfetchd I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Damn, dc is far more powerful than I thought. Nice job!

Comment: @therealfarfetchd Thanks. I like dc. Btw, there were a couple of typos in the explanation which I just fixed.

Answer (score 7):

## C, 111 bytes

(Note how the byte count is also the three same numbers. Wow. You can't do more meta than that.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define b "<acdhlmoprsu>."
#define t "en"
main(){{{printf(("<acdhlmoprsu>." b b t t t));;;}}}
```

Prints:

```
<acdhlmoprsu>.<acdhlmoprsu>.<acdhlmoprsu>.enenen
```

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 33 bytes

```php
<?=($s="<?;<?=;'".'"').($s).($s);
```

Opted for something more interesting than the 9-byte program with no PHP tag.

Outputs `<?;<?=;'"<?;<?=;'"<?;<?=;'"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jb6uhUmyrZGNvDWRaqyvpqSupa@oBxSCE9f//AA)

Answer (score 6):

## *[99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47588/12012)*, 15 bytes

```
9 9  9999
9
9
9
```

That is nine nines, three spaces, and three line feeds, the output is **-1110-1110-1110**.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/99#@2@pYKmgYAkEXGD4/z8A)**

#### How?

```
9 9  9999 - V(9)=V(9)-V(9999)=1-1111=-1110
9         - print V(9)
9         - print V(9)
9         - print V(9)
```

The two spaces are treated as one, this third space could be a trailing space on any line too.

Answer (score 6):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), <s>273</s> 240 (<s>360</s> 286) bytes

```
HAI 1.2
I HAS A U
IM IN YR M UPPIN YR Q TIL BOTH SAEM Q 1
VISIBLE "Y SUB.EK"
IM OUTTA YR M
IM IN YR T UPPIN YR Q TIL BOTH SAEM Q 2
VISIBLE "Y SUB.EK"
IM OUTTA YR T
IM IN YR X UPPIN YR Q TIL BOTH SAEM Q 12
VISIBLE "IM"
IM OUTTA YR X
KTHXBYE
```

Note the trailing new line and [try it online](https://tio.run/##hc4xDoMwEATA/l6x4gFI8IOzZMkncCDxObJrSIfE/ysDSUHSkG632NEu6zKt86sUx4KmbkngOIARSTzkhvyARxzHT7xDpYcZ1CGw9Xtv6ClBTG9RZYRoattVx3SIqvxen5BeQe0/SE8oXT76ksT/Gok6dclkS6Vs). The second line was more or less arbitrary and can possibly replaced by a shorter command, but I just learned [LOLCODE](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md) for this puzzle. Since the version number is required in the first line, I used the numbers to add loops of length 1, 2 and 0 mod 3 to ensure the right number of characters will be printed. From this I simply counted each character (with this [tool](https://www.dcode.fr/frequency-analysis)). If it appeared 0 mod 3 times, no action was required. If it appeared 1 mod 3 times, it was added to the 1- and 2-loop so it would appear three times in the output. If it appeared 2 mod 3 times, the character was added to the 12-loop. **EDIT:** By replacing the first `VISIBLE` with an assignment (still useless but required to have 12 instead of 11 new lines), I was able to cut off 33 bytes.

Output (60 byte):

```
Y SUB.EK
Y SUB.EK
Y SUB.EK
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
IM
```

Note the trailing new line.

Nice thing about this solution in comparison to the other answers is that the Output can easily manipulated to output somewhat meaningful text. Example (286 bytes with trailing new line):

```
HAI 1.2
I HAS A U
IM IN YR MW UPPIN YR Q TIL BOTH SAEM Q 1
VISIBLE "YO SUB. EEEEK!"
IM OUTTA YR MW
IM IN YR STA UPPIN YR Q TIL BOTH SAEM Q 2
VISIBLE "YO SUB. EEEEK!"
IM OUTTA YR STA
IM IN YR XURG UPPIN YR Q TIL BOTH SAEM Q 12
VISIBLE "IMO U R SWAG! "
IM OUTTA YR XURG
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jc4xDoMwDAXQPaf4cAAkuIEjRcSCNJQkBea2GxL3n4IrBtoF1dP/lvzkdVuf2@udsyVGXTWKYSmAkBQ78A3LCDchDcOR74jcQ/toEcg46bV6cGDdG5SLR0i6gpHpivIj@BQjHcgJBlldiM1/oignOY/t5ZNfJjuPBLmfqC3wawqjumhnvRiV8w4) Output (222 bytes with trailing new line):

```
YO SUB. EEEEK!
YO SUB. EEEEK!
YO SUB. EEEEK!
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG! 
IMO U R SWAG!
```

Sadly, I'm not as good with anagrams as I thought :')

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks. Anything I need to do to get LOLCODE such a nice automatic linking as I copied from other posts? (the # [language] style) The link to the source code is contained in the answer.

Comment: The easiest way is, when you've put your program in TIO, to use the link menu and select (or copy) the choice for "Code Golf Submission". That gives you a template for a new post. I copied the part you seemed to be missing from there.

Answer (score 6):

**SHELL**

to joke :)       ( **9 Bytes** )

```
ls;ls;ls;
```

or more seriously ( **24 Bytes** )

```
sed s/./sed.g./g <<< edg
```

Result :

```
sed.g.sed.g.sed.g.
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP, 24 bytes

```
<?=111?><?=222?><?=333?>
```

Comment: What does this output? How does it work?

Comment: It uses the PHP shorttag `<?` together with the immediate `echo` statement `<?=` to output 123 3 times.

Comment: The shorter version you just edited in is invalid since the `<= ?>` characters don't appear a multiple of 3 times.

Comment: Ah, right, I knew there was a reason for the original version being as it was - I completely flaked on the requirement - I will change it back.

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 9 bytes

```
12i12i12i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@29olAlB//8DAA)

Outputs `12i` 24 times:

```
12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i12i
```

---

## Vim, 12 bytes

```
12i12i12i<ESC><ESC><ESC>
```

Outputs the same as the V answer

Answer (score 4):

## [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

This program prints its source code backwards. The first loop `[[..]]` and last `<` could be removed if it weren't for the source-restriction.

```
[[..]]<[.<]<
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#@x8dracXG2sTrWcTa/P/PwA)

**Output:**

```
<]<.[<]]..[[
```

#### Proof of Optimality:

Since the output requires at least nine characters (3 unique, 3 each), the program either needs nine prints `.` plus 3x2 other instructions to meet the source-restriction (this means 15 bytes), or the code uses a loop.

If it uses a loop, the characters necessary are `[].`, three of each. Of course, a movement instruction `<` or `>` is necessary to avoid an infinite loop, meaning that a valid solution will be at least 12 bytes.

Comment: I think you can move two `<` to the end to drop the `w`.

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, <s>36</s> 21 bytes

```
@echo
@echo
@echo
```

Outputs

```
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
```

Edit: Saved 15 bytes thanks to @P.Ktinos.

Comment: Wouldn't 3 alone echo's work? echo\necho\necho - replace \n with a new line - it looks valid to me http://image.prntscr.com/image/ef96173169eb41168815203387d4975b.png , makes it 14 bytes.

Comment: Outgolfed: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108180/63033

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge 93](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 9 bytes

```
...,,,@@@
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@6@np6ejo@Pg4PD/PwA)

Prints `0 0 0`  (Trailing space, followed by 3 null bytes)

Because Befunge's stack is padded with `0`s, we can print both the ASCII character with that value, and the integer itself. Because Befunge automatically prints a space after an integer, we are left with 3 distinct characters.

`.` prints `0`  (trailing space), `,` prints a null byte, and `@` ends the program

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes (I guess you could say this was a piece of PI)

*-0 bytes thanks to Emigna/ETHProductions, made the solution more correct.*

```
žqžqžq???
```

Alternate versions:

```
ž[g-Q]ž[g-Q]ž[g-Q]???
```

`[g-Q]` - Can put any letter a-Q here, as long as they all match (see below).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390XyEEVduD4P//AA)

**Explained:**

`PI,PI,PI,SORT,JOIN,SORT,JOIN,SORT,JOIN.`

**Result:**

`...111111222333333333444555555555666777888999999999`

The reason it is only 9 bytes is because you don't need the sorts, I just put them in to help illustrate.

**Result w/o `{` in the code:**

`3.1415926535897933.1415926535897933.141592653589793`

---

**Alternative Renditions:**

The following commands can be used in place of PI:

```
ž 23  > žg       push current year
        žh       push [0-9]
        ži       push [a-zA-Z]
        žj       push [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        žk       push [z-aZ-A]
        žl       push [z-aZ-A9-0_]
        žm       push [9-0]
        žn       push [A-Za-z]
        žo       push [Z-Az-a]
        žp       push [Z-A]
        žq       push pi
        žr       push e
        žu       push ()<>[]{}
        žy       push 128
        žz       push 256
        žA       push 512
        žB       push 1024
        žC       push 2048
        žD       push 4096
        žE       push 8192
        žF       push 16384
        žG       push 32768
        žH       push 65536
        žI       push 2147483648
        žJ       push 4294967296
        žK       push [a-zA-Z0-9]
        žL       push [z-aZ-A9-0]
        žM       push aeiou
        žN       push bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
        žO       push aeiouy
        žP       push bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz
        žQ       push printable ASCII character set (32-128)
```

Comment: Get out for the pun; for the trick though get one :)

Comment: Nice one! I don't think `žv`, `žw`, or `žx` are valid though as they each have only 2 distinct digits.

Comment: Hmm, what's the point of the backwards character classes?

Comment: @ETHproductions ahhh, forgot about `at least 3`, was just PI at first when I wrote it. What do you mean backwards character classes?

Comment: Like `[z-aZ-A9-0_]`. I don't see how that'd be any different than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Note that this is only valid if you don't count the newline that's implicitly printed. That could easily be fixed by replacing `JJJ` with `???` though.

Comment: Good call, better to be correct 100% regardless.

Comment: @ETHproductions not different, just illustrating the different ways this can be done with built-ins.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm just confused about *why* the backwards char classes are built-ins...

Comment: @ETHproductions seems very costly to get them otherwise, and they've only used a-Q they still could use R-Z for additional sequences when they need them. `žL = žnRžm` is an example of cost, prolly was spurred by a challenge. I've used it once before, forget why now.

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, 9 bytes

```
000OoOoOo
```

Prints `undefinedundefinedundefined`. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=MDAwT29Pb09v&input=)

#### Explanation

This code gets transpiled into the following JavaScript:

```
000,O.o(O.o(O.o()))
```

`O.o` is a function that outputs something without a trailing newline. When given no argument, it prints `undefined`, which could be considered a bug, but comes in handy here. It also returns `undefined`, so all three calls prints `undefined`.

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do this...

Comment: O_o Interesting :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 12 bytes

A bit of a boring answer really.  Outputs three `10`s followed by newlines

```
N@N@NOoOoOo@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@@/nAIT@@SDo8P8/AA)
Maps to the cube

```
    N @
    N @
N O o O o O o @
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

`N` Pushs 10 to the stack
`Oo` x3 Outputs 10 and newline
`@` halts the program

The initial `N@N@` is not hit.

Comment: I count 34 spaces :/

Comment: @SK19  The code is `N@N@NOoOoOo@` and does not include any spaces.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought the cube needed to fulfill the requirement, too

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
`í`²²²í`í
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=YO1gsrKy7WDt&input=)

Outputs

```
''sseerreerreerr'sererer'sererer'sererer'sererer'sererer'sererer'sererer
```

which contains each char of `'sererer` 9 times.

I found this by accident while experimenting with Japt, and wanted to share this which IMO is much more interesting than [a number literal polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108133/three-three-three/108142?s=2|6.8963#108142) and [a solution that has three dummy bytes and simply prints something three times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108133/three-three-three/108263?s=1|8.6255#108263), even though those are also 9 bytes.

#### How it works

```
`í`²²²í`í

`í`        Shoco-compressed string of "'sererer"
   ²       Repeat 2 times
    ²      Repeat 2 times
     ²     Repeat 2 times
      í    Interleave with ... into a string
       `í    Shoco-compressed string of "'sererer"
```

Japt uses shoco library for string compression, which excels at compressing sequences of lowercase letters. It's actually surprising that one byte can decompress into an 8-char string.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 9 bytes

```r
c ;c ;c ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1nBGoL@/wcA)

Outputs

function (...)  .Primitive("c")
function (...)  .Primitive("c")
function (...)  .Primitive("c")

This is a boring solution, still working on a more creative one.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 24 bytes

```
rEeEEeeEEErreEErreEEreEE
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!ce@M@MM)

Program contains 6 r's, 6 e's, and 12 E's.

Explanation:

```
rEeEEeeEEErreEErreEEreEE # full program

rEeEEeeEEE               # push '103' to the stack
          rreEErreEE     # output as int (r flag: preserve)
                    reEE # output as int
```

Output:

```
103103103
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
000gggwww
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/38DAID09vby8/P9/AA)

Prints `[[[0]]]00`. Exploits (unnecessarily, it turns out) the fact that, in the absence of constraints on a variable, its value is taken to be zero, and the `w` predicate which prints the value of its input variable without a newline places no constraints on its output variable. (In fact, if this was allowed to have only two unique characters, `gggwww` would produce the same output, and `gwgwgw` or `wgwggw` would also work.)

```
      w      Print
000          zero
   g         enclosed in a list
    g        enclosed in a list
     g       enclosed in a list,
       w     and print something with no supplied value,
        w    and print something with no supplied value.
```

Various permutations of this program work, and are more visually novel than the one presented here, but it's the first version I came up with and to my mind very much to the point. Some permutations include `0gw0gw0gw` which violates the second encouragement, `w0gw00ggw` which has a nice escalating effect, `ggwgww000` which shows that the zeros being there really doesn't matter (it may as well be `ggwgww777`), and nothing containing the substring `g0` since no matter what is on the left of the `g` `0` cannot possibly be a list containing it as its only element so the program will either fail or infinitely spew garbage as it tries to backtrack around the problem depending on whether or not there was a `w` earlier.

Less trivial variations on the same theme include `3ggw3gw3w`, `XgggwXwwX`, `w≡g≡wg≡gw`, and `w?gw?ggw?` [(which is actually compliant even with input!)](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v9w@HYiA@P9/paDUxJycSh2FzBKFzGJFJQA) I expected not to find a 9-byte solution and was pleasantly surprised to find a whole family of them.

Answer (score 4):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 84 bytes

```
PLEASE.4<-#4DOREADOUT.4DOREADOUT.4DOREADOUT.4DOGIVEUPPLEASELEAS..4<<--##DDOOUUGGIIVV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2FXPxEZX2cTFP8jV0cU/NEQPJ9PdM8w1NACiCUToAXXa6OoqK7u4@PuHhrq7e3qGhf3/DwA)

Ignores the second encouragement and essentially ignores the third (since unreachable syntax errors are pretty much comments), because I'm not feeling quite insane enough today to work around them in INTERCAL. Prints

```
IV

IV

IV
```

(6 spaces, 6 newlines, 3 Is, 3 Vs), transparently just three instances of the Roman numeral 4 which could actually just as well have been any other number since spaces get printed above them taking care of the third unique character. Had to be printed three times because number output brings two newlines along with it. Attempting to just print a third newline alone makes it a bit longer...

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 99 bytes

```
DO,1<-#1DO,1SUB#1<-#176DOREADOUT,1DO.3<-#3PLEASEREADOUT.3PLEASEGIVEUPDOOODD##UUBB7766REEAAT.LGGIIVV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYmxCoAgFAA/xrUEEXRpUd5DBOFF9dwjGoJoiP7fLJyOuzuuZ7@39SwFqFNDL9THmb34xRqgCR0QL109Uteox4RuxpZl0xAz8ghEBCAEs/fWGjMhOrfIFEKMOZfyAg)

Prints

```
III
```

(3 spaces, 3 newlines, 3 Is). Uses both numeric output and C-INTERCAL-style array output. Exactly as long as a version using just array output:

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 99 bytes

```
DO,9<-#9DO,9SUB#1<-#41DO,9SUB#4<-#77DO,9SUB#7<-#14PLEASEREADOUT,9PLEASEGIVEUPDO,<<--##SULRRTTGGIIVV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FX8fSRlfZEkQHhzopGwI5JoYwngmQZ24O45kDeYYmAT6ujsGuQa6OLv6hITqWEK67Z5hraABQoY2Nrq6ycnCoT1BQSIi7u6dnWNj//wA)

Prints

```
ëëëQQQ>>>
```

(no spaces or newlines for once). This is the approach which feels most clever to me, as it turns an obstructive feature of array output into a tool: when trying to output a value from an array, what it actually outputs is the previous value minus the value mod 256 with its bits read backwards. This makes it rather difficult to [print any particular value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181789/85334), but means that if we want to print a string of repeating characters, we don't need to actually set the corresponding elements of the array, because arrays initialize their elements to zero, and the difference between two identical codepoints is also zero. So this only sets the first, fourth, and seventh elements of `,9`, and hypothetically it could even get away with not setting the first one but I'm not sure that null bytes are valid characters.

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 87 bytes

```
DO,9<-#9DO,9SUB#4<-#7DO,9SUB#7<-#9DOREADOUT,9PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASEDO,,#SSUUB447RRTTLGGIIVV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FX8fSRlfZEkQHhzopmwA55jCOOUQmyNXRxT80RMcywMfVMdjV3TPMNTQAwgaq1FEODg4NdTIxMQ8KCgnxcXf39AwL@/8fAA)

If they are, then this version here still loses to the first one by 3 bytes, and prints this unprintable mess: `00 00 00 9F 9F 9F 0F 0F 0F`.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 9 bytes

```
zfzfdzddf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@1@VVpWWUpWSkvb/PwA)

Output:

```
0
1
0
3
3
3
1
1
0
```

(The program has no newlines; the output has 9 newlines.)

---

The new answer above is better than my old answer of the same length, because the new answer meets OP's suggestion that the output ideally shouldn't be the same string repeated 3 times.  Here's the old answer, which I'll keep here so that @mbomb007's comment continues to make sense!

```
_A_A_Annn
```

[Try the old answer online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@x/vCIJ5eXn//wMA)

Output is

```
-10-10-10
```

(no newlines in either the program or the output)

Comment: ♫ Barbara _A_A_Annn

Comment: @mbomb007 LOL!!

Answer (score 3):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 24 bytes

```
''''   'putput'3*3*3*put
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#@68OBAoKCuoFpSVApG6sBYJA1v//AA) Outputs `54` each of `p` `u` and `t`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 30 bytes

```
**ZZZZZZZZZT
*gggaaabbbTT
```

Output:

```
@@@AAACCC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@6@lFQUDIVxa6enpiYmJSUlJISFcXP//G/7XLQcA)

*(score includes 3 total newlines, and 3 bytes for `-w` on the command line)*

Chip is a new language I've been designing, and this is it's first real test drive! It's a 2D bit-based language that functions somewhat like an integrated circuit you might put together with a breadboard.

This solution outputs three @'s (binary 01000000), three A's (01000001), then three C's (01000011) by turning the bits successively on.

#### Breakdown

Ungolfed (or, really, without the excess parts):

```
*ZZZZZZZZZ
g  a  b  T
```

`*` is a source element which produces a high signal; that is sent to
`g` , which represents the bit 0x40 of the output stream, and
`Z` , which propagates signal after one clock tick. After 3 ticks (for three `Z` elements),
`a` receives a high signal, and now the 0x1 bit is also on. Three ticks later,
`b` turns on the 0x2 bit, and three ticks again activates
`T` , which terminates execution.

All other added elements are active (e.g. not a comment), but they don't do anything, similar to assigning a variable to itself.

Comment: Where are the 3 newlines? If you put your code in <pre><code>...</code></pre> in markdown, we'll be able to see them.

Comment: @mbomb007 End of each line and one more at the end. Did that change anything? I don't see a difference...

Comment: Oh, wow.... there's gray boxes. Apparently the contrast or gamma or something is really screwed up on one of my monitors.

Comment: I had that problem with a monitor a few months back. It fixed itself after a few days. Idk what caused it, but changing settings wouldn't fix it. Also, that final newline is required in the markdown, because the block shows one less due to some SE formatting issue.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), 12 bytes

```
n11n222n1(((
```

Outputs `011222` three times. Try it [here](http://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/).

#### How?

In Ouroboros, each line of code represents a snake swallowing its tail. Execution proceeds from the head (start) of the line to the tail (end), and then loops back to the head. The `(` instruction swallows characters from the tail. If the instruction pointer is swallowed, execution halts.

The `n` command outputs a number. Popping the empty stack gives zero, so the first `n` prints `0`. The next prints `11`, and the third prints `222`.

Now we come to `1(`: push `1` and swallow that many characters. The final paren is swallowed. The next-to-last paren does nothing<sup>1</sup>, and execution loops back to the beginning.

The second time through, the next-to-last paren is swallowed and we loop again. The third time, the third-to-last paren is swallowed. This swallows the IP, and the program ends.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The stack is empty, so it swallows `0` characters.</sub>

Comment: "...each line of code represents a snake swallowing its tail"  (⊙.☉)7

Comment: @Luigi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros (but yeah, that is a bit trippy)

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
aaa¶¶ccc

¶
```

prints

```
a
a
a




c
c
c
```

That's 12 linefeeds.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8@VmJh4aNuhbcnJyVxch7b9/w8A)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 57 bytes

```
main(){printf("^^-_-^-__","");("{{pprrmmaainttff,,}}");;}
```

**Output**

```
^^-_-^-__
```

**Alternative Version, 56 bytes**

```
main(){printf("%1$d%1$d%1$d","({{pprrmmaainttff,,}})");}
```

Comment: `{` and `}` appear only once in your code, so I'm afraid this is not a valid answer.

Comment: You also have a non-multiple-of-three number of `"`

Comment: @Laikoni added two more of `{` and `}`.

Comment: @VisualMelon added `,""` to `printf`

Comment: You can remove all three commas.

Answer (score 3):

## [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) (JavaScript), 84 bytes

```javascript
!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(([[]]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/hfbJvwX1ExOlYbTETDmbHaGnC2prYGThqD1IgGatbU/J9gzZWcn1ecn5Oql5OfrpFalpijUaypiSoaraenVxyrl5aZU5JapJFsa5dsa6sera6pl5Oal16SQYxqDZJUa5OkWhFJ9X8A)

first we take the 3 shortest chars to express in jsfuck:

```javascript
0: +[] (3 chars)
1: +!![] (5 chars)
2: !![]+!![] (9 chars)
```

combining them to get `"222111000"` we get this (75 chars) (this requires putting the second char in an array but then after that we can just add the other characters with the `+` operator):

```javascript
!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])
```

this has these charcounts:

```javascript
[ & ]: 13
( & ): 7
!: 18
+: 17
```

we can increase our `+`, `()`, and `[]` counts just enough by adding an arithmetic `0` to the end (`+(([[]]))`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Plumber](https://github.com/Radvylf/plumber), 45 bytes

```
]][]
==[[=]=]]
[]][ [[=][
[[=][[[=
  =]][[=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7RvbbqM49D1f4c3DCDYJDeTSaLK0mod52JF2dqV9dL0aNpCUipKIQKfVTL69axtDuBhjp0lvWhQRsA/nfo6Pjblx7pztIvI38eBu9rhMwkXsr0OwCZLbf7XF2vX6wIlWWx386AB83DkRSEI/3gIbkF5jG/gLTzP7YGDqxnYT@LF2dhVdXoU/r6KzlW7cOhvNC4B9AbzAiLxN4GDwM/gPvEI2Olv1QRd0dWPjuJ9DV/vDia@NhecH@BEj8MJVfA3OgKWDX4HFIG@deHGtnRk/zL61wwTAz58AIn1OuUt5JEfgxeDWucdcUm4xZTfBhDVnsehjTnTCEKWGgbJGRlHvgyHDR45M2hRPSZzFOlw4sWYYRuh9B5@iyHnQCNFBAZmx9INA6wLMu86w7ji8hkTJmApE83J7cotbM7NoGEovPEkOfwm0@GHjrZfEUMC2QXcbR3646uolOHJEXpxEIYFjpup29apIrvfX2g/jT7E21HWstzsv2npaQSHk8IKtRyl/xW7iRYa//T2MvZUXUQ4bCUPci@qYGsGHBeDd/pLpivztGTSW6@izg30jlYUq1Ngk22tqn@QWt@cWKCChcEW7EA9fRb5L@nKrpsZnJp3ncOsk3iRxwWyk0Qn8O69otPs@eChajcZQ5lHwHsGHgpiUPO4kLFT7iMJXWCn4B37Bhg6TICD@v4Imp83itI04bWNO26TUVrYnM04cJV6ZNdiFqIvDFEFytuk1tOk1bUH0GqbXqIsMP1wEietttUQHHz5gstMTkeWQOj@ElJbQ@MI0iJrSG0yKoZypomSNSwfHAHPB9A@7MtBI@PvYE4Zz/PcbdQjmgbih1yt6FHUWH9VdFjNU9toS9qQPblICN4wARpLTuCnToLkw91ofwZtKJLPncTsJCEh0gPpA7r@CiuiaqdouqLqq98INLNxg36pnoD13aVJI6ep1uqruJEsqE5VD0idsD4kTMWmwABXNl/Gy2CamE0GN@FC7TvkqPbvrAklVByw9s1J1K8p2lvM4ntWU@3h49jq9wMM4t3uvJTxSm1RTQ2YqRkGfcx/M6KfU6zC7Bq7NE3Ft5lybQq7Ng7i2FLgueQfhr1WGHpPBymWwhDJYB8kwehYZRrkMI6EMIwUZqkH65KjEyf6gwBTmfJnIXaVCwxWNsvVG07lAJgMyRUAWA7JEQCMGNGoG2g8wCBRGDgC7Ih/J498mKnG9pR96brEA43RYTR2jekezw2UFsY8tiMegXhfNW7nkFyKcfNbriZCZ0sjMdmSWNDKrHdlIGtmoCdluP5NhQ2/JHdDbcIfBUd1hMDiiO4iRKbqDGJmiO/CQ1dwBtSUEWQkI9I14cE95m0qNh2oSp8SrGV88xKXcnEuObGlepvVt8@AnAKnHoVzonUTxw1bFm8@oeLOlIG1VvKmk@PrcVt79eWsMojg8Z/WQ@XxuBU8o0OHWbg/6emZCJ5dEKWia8sN7rWpLSxRiS0gssDU834iDrjdNJK2ZmSoNNrrqHTmhu77VdKywoTEBl/ky4McM77wRHXfFlk8rZ9zOGL/M@f6Y0WzIbTuJGFCq3Z/JDAIc5Zlshq3XlP/qE8eMmPARpiZ5NkZK1mohfqgt1Qrv12rLgbotBy9py8FpbPlGzadouhcz2wlMht5K9hyqmcw8ssn25M2XNpmtFmWiQnxfxo1b5z4TaayzHOtEtqqF9tFkmp1Epqm6TLZUaInnSa9EFHQ88yjLdGRRIHyfY1RlRrZPffqTc19llnrAwHWSkeutFBs89bUNDqepO16HITlvbsaixRzCRUP3e1xWgMWFOFTc32CXNju0peTpkdd8MubTt9CT3JWmrWn8/NTraDlr9MXsOGftXLiEOi3sV8m29NEYYVsbdb3xNWI2lPEQnMsgUC/qpi@lxHb7zhRYy6Av7DaHS/fYZVzMhKaccS0xO8gS8O0E1jtTPHyLIfCkPKJe1LwG53uayO92t8uYq5SxjFKyEqf68KTtYZ7@ysIRpWxjJ67tTO4Dl6cI0T7kIkzjRmb@i5KOYDtD/t5gX3kOTFp0Tvllb33ZsVQxtRBzcXhbUohL70TtylbTwtvS4hI2Am30x3JC2eVir2HPK0CVVyFi2hM5uUtr8i3W01wCNtbJWUtSO2IUOI9dAmLFIZ@cCGV9n9xuzg93hRRxlDQhlSpk0kWl5m@uOSpldNt0s3nsI5NXmgg0snuIDHF9YjXZeazCoFKfcNbptsx9pSa0T2KJfibCtHOZflJCEyz22IHZwp3U29Ds2KNuEbmj3vPkSUxxIiPYbqEyXTnIYS/SbfAFPxkQP5kc4p/qhZ/QYRkjx3XYY/D4vwereLBiIboD36/9wMNuTIaVpR@6muYFfXCvsw/m9k0PtIl@/ZV@8pV/bsaGs3RCNe/sOpvID2Pty99/fjXSb/X85YOWfnL57REhiDq2DaGNbIQ6EN8DcgM79IxPGCnuIRedx299iAihx/8A)

The `]]` and `==` at the beginning of the first two lines do nothing except lower the number of spaces and increase the number of those characters, and there are two trailing newlines to bring the total up to 6. This outputs the numbers `111000222`.

Characters:

- 15 `[`
- 12 `]`
- 9 `=`
- 6 `\n`
- 3

Answer (score 3):

## [Squire](https://github.com/sampersand/squire) commit `c82e0e5`, 21 bytes

```
dump(dump(dump(III)))
```

Squire hath provideth a strange builtin called `dump`, which releases some forbidden knowledge about what it was called with, then rewards the value itself.

Outputeth:

```
Number(3)
Number(3)
Number(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```
@show @show @show 111
```

**output:**

```
111 = 111
#= /home/runner/.code.tio:1 =# @show(111) = 111
#= /home/runner/.code.tio:1 =# @show(#= /home/runner/.code.tio:1 =# @show(111)) = 111
```

inspired by [EasyasPi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230335/98541)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY7BCsIwEETv@xVLipBAaQ3ehBV/JaSRrtSNxob69zGiBY@6h4FZ3gxzzhM7@yjleB/jgt9qrS3gkDC5RSkF1VdTFRrCfoyX0KcsElLf@TiEbua4r0TzjusKmn/4n0vX1tcmuCaWeRJtAE4xISMLZuFbDtoZwHq@4j5mmTWRZtN@3muQ6eBbVKha9Jsd0dZAkKE8AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), <s>21</s> <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```dis
{{{|{{{|{{{!!!|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZtU@JIEP6eX9FEhERkw4t4i3Gsc9G7tYrTLXWv7k7Y1JgMkCNkqMyg7AK/3etJAkKidZuqJDM93U@/THfPjMXoZc/zxQc2efww5cKf@2ICjVqjXjtuNOFfITXBJFTZTJtNqBhDrdZoaGw@5ZGEbsc573ZJR1uA/D5lMGTS5eGgVIpnLp9MaOhpqzPLY09WOAsCaJyV6qVSKv7l/P4z0YtGygjV6RohXjKLC/WrnKySwUl1pa81f7m5u/qr@7fTubm9vezckzp8vb76y7m7vyCNWq2pPYBeXHw6v/vs/Hl5e3d1c62EoV8qxc5wiD1NZpVPCfc/eWY2mQVUMhCjmJVPJQ6feeSJaeDLUokGPhVQHUK5uKhX9OKv@qpMyupfLpWuv3a7nT8uyEkMbyhVni1G/kDa8RgUX0pg7ohDcc/UgUBdaTYKENPKXwJGBYMZviF7ZhEawIKgbNbPSrgNTzQAvQADGgimL5c/JxWbE/PNl4J5UBbW3Ppu2QI/P6xybMQP6L8Nd/f17qlZAZRL0TB3ROTG20jl6WnZcVjoXDhlexr5oRyA87JYLJbpWygUli8ph2bq2h4M/EhIkM8cAj9kAvgABpxLNJk@8iemaRM2UeAaAKSI@0JtV6J338GdWqpFfPYgYhMUAjGlLmKxuctwy7q/iZRBRlBFf3uy99Qb9CIob4mqJGShTCGilB7HJx2f0DXRMh6@mX31HpiWNUzJlmEt0iE@xcfX8fXr8HENstpWLjmgM@l0wAOshef6Zn0YsSl82Ezp83hj06fL36@ut7S6fBZKUrNfKXwaPegHep8cNbLUb0htH2WpZ0g9zvEukVpv5JgXMbmZJa9icitLdpTCHLWA1OYGYpX@izXwQ8Ww5Z0/MBIHSatdO2qbW0vr9ADdD6cziXkVMAwrphUPh2g9JieofNXtHRk295G@RVtpGTxlYrHWtzMxrlTyBhOiG/oiC6DPwgmV7ggzyXjHkF0r1oAFYxMDM4@65SZ2TEn9UCAzNgTfA3dEI@piEYmfU4g1r8W1GNIg@I4wKDqNGH417j0OSQ3442xA6pqhbWqw1wuxDLE6sSerJsGw03PM23MIofoEVQmzNINV1XUE1DBPjlrHv3xsK9HyQy886Kc1kCS4ZiYzld@IMJfoA0PdOH6mUejwmeQDh7uY30n@7yS/n2Z9HD0LrdkUIyUu8V5rYsAjw7a3I9oh6MaDu73HmGmJ/kyOuQ5xbc8hnv1W6mHh6of00D30DjuHCtPrvx3/rSzbA6zOHcUdgrVq7uB7pJLA2TuC33KC7aNdQfdtwbOc4HFGIyWJHEHHjGRoNc0UbL95UG8ff2zugi5zoNgwMvHzd3pTuhtjUrfHpwrxyB4fkOauJUqqQgxlB7XG5n6zumWSmlea@DkY2@/Y/27YF2/Ym9GNZJo0m485o@IaynjD8BxWQrv5iheFs0arlUNIs@Y@8rE34BEQzzGB3u9WCP8myAD0Hj77vBei/O62rN5ws5VzEy9e6gAGekpqOUNpEoJdXEc/abdA3du4HGGrARrhbYNPd5gKOeXNTIhzYXyv9NJo4X1mXWNx1Tr9pNLwf3N797/l5hLDrdTN/axDHjG8HH21aShrU5Qqv0@KG4P99CBQxzm46pZUVC1T9W0jCWRKxAaaEpEibds4MDfH/xONIFBdOxxiJngzdXKBxLYKeMnBGQ9B@nzr@MeWGJCjWvs4cxGgWF6C6LodkMBqVOuNtecBC4dyZAgi8Jwyz0iwSMIp7LVIynl5fbFeQpcUzbaZoG7cmec0GuJ99wrm67Sba7EniUuK7@U/)

Answer (score 2):

## Forth, 21 bytes

```
 1 1 1 . cr . cr . cr
```

Program contains 3 of each of `1.cr`, and 9 spaces. Output contains 3 ones, 3 spaces, and 3 newlines.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@2@oAIJ6CslFCOL/fwA)

**Output:**

Each `1` has a space after it.

```
1 
1 
1
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU Sed, 12 bytes

**Golfed**

```
abc
abc
abc
```

(note the trailing newline)

**How It Works**

> a text
>
> Appending text after a line. This is a GNU extension.

Appends the "bc" string + `LF` 3 times, resulting in 3 `b`, 3 `c` and 3 `LF` characters in the output.

**Test**

```bash
%echo|sed -n 'abc
abc
abc
'
bc                                                                                                                                                      
bc                                                                                                                                                      
bc

%echo|sed -n 'abc
abc
abc
'|tr \\n N|fold -1|sort|uniq -c
3 N                                                                                                                                               
3 b                                                                                                                                               
3 c
```

[Try It Online !](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNGVMTzV5R0tRX1E)

Comment: The newline only appears twice, I think you can add an extra newline at the end to meet this requirement

Comment: ^ What he said. Your source code's length must be divisible by 3.

Comment: @KritixiLithos, mbomb007 - Thank you ! Should be fixed now !

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
PzPzPzuuu
```

Outputs the lowercase alphabet three times, each time followed by a newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x9QBYKlpaX//wMA)

#### Explanation

The naive attempt

```
P12P12P12
```

actually prints `12` *four* times. That's because Pip autoprints the result of the last expression in the program. `P12` prints `12`, but it is also an expression that evaluates to `12`. So an extra `12` is printed.

We can avoid this by making the last expression in the program evaluate to nil. When nil is printed, it produces no output--not even a newline. The variable `u` is preinitialized to nil. Repeating it three times is fine, just adds a couple no-ops.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 27 bytes

```
aaabbb
S\`
S\`
S\`
\`\`\`
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8@VmJiYlJTEFRyTAMcxCSDI9f8/AA)

The output is 150 bytes, containing 12 `a`, 12 `b`, and 126 newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Del|m|t](https://github.com/MistahFiggins/Delimit), 21 bytes

[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/delimit#@2@tAIIWSNDU1PT/fwA)

```
; ; ; 8 8 8 8 8 8 555
```

prints `32 -1 32 -1 32 -1`  (with a trailing space)

No command line argument =   as delimiter

`;` pushes -1 followed by the delimiter, and `8` prints the top of the stack. `555` ends the program

**Here's another interesting solution with 24 bytes total:**

[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/delimit#@2@tYKCgD4QWYGhnZ2dtbWCgr6Dw/z8A)

```
; 0 / / 8 8 8 >>>;;00/
```

(2 trailing spaces to make it a multiple of 3)

This one just uses the -1, but is longer due to the lack of repetition, so the "end" command had to be pretty long

prints `-1 -1 -1`  (also a trailing space)

The `;` pushes the delimiter (as above), the 0 drops the top, so the stack only has a -1 on it. `/ /`  duplicates it twice, and 3 `8`s print. `>>>;;00/`   ends the program

Answer (score 2):

## [Del|m|t](https://github.com/MistahFiggins/Delimit), 15 bytes

[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/delimit#@2@hYKkAw6ampv//AwA)

```
8 9 8 9 8 9 555
```

Prints `0 0 0`  (with a trailing space) (there are null bytes after every space, including the trailing one

Because the stack is padded with `0`s, we can just print the ASCII value and character, because printing the value also prints a space. `555` ends the program.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch ~ 9 bytes

```
bc
bc
bc
```

Two random chars, followed by a new line, makes 3 chars that are shown 3 times.
Hex dump: `62 63 0A 62 63 0A 62 63 0A`

### Output:

```
C:\Users\4story\Desktop>bc
'bc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\4story\Desktop>bc
'bc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\4story\Desktop>bc
'bc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My environment username happens to be "4story". However, it doesnt matter what directory you are in, or what your username is - output will always fulfill the rules.

Comment: Output typically has to be to stdout, not stderr. You should ask the OP if that's okay.

Comment: @mbomb007 Maybe not: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2451/36398

Comment: @mbomb007 it's a default for allowed, but ill ask him.

Comment: @P.Ktinos It has a lot of downvotes as well. For each 3 upvotes, there are at least 2 downvotes. The other answers are far less controversial.

Answer (score 2):

## Labyrinth, 12 bytes

**Program:**

```
!!!(!(!(!@@@
```

**Output:**

```
000-1-1-1
```

The last two `@` aren't technically a comment, but they're just as useless. However, it's kind of inevitable since `@`'s a necessary character to exit a Labyrinth.

**Explanation:**

Labyrinth's stack contains an infinite number of 0's at the bottom.

`!`: pops the top of the stack and prints its decimal representation

`(`: decrements the top of the stack by 1

`@`: terminates the program

Because this program is a single line, most of Labyrinth's rules for deciding what direction to go are irrelevant; it just moves down the line from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 21 bytes

A pure Bash solution that has no external dependencies.

```
 e== ;e=cchhoo;echo $e$e$e;
```

## Testing script

For convenience, I also wrote a test script that counts the number of occurrences of a character in a string. You can use it to validate your own solutions.

```js
o={};
prompt``.split``.forEach(
ch=>o[ch]=o[ch]?o[ch]+1:1
);console.log(o)
```

Comment: Question states "... full program. Not an answer". Off of this I think this is invalid.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Fixed.

Comment: Looking good I think :) Just noticed that I wrote an answer instead of a function...

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 12 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediates window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediates window.

```
?75:?75:?75:
```

### Output

```
75 
75 
75
```

Answer (score 2):

## SQL Server, PostgreSQL, SQLite, 27 bytes

```sql
SELECT  111222333 SSELLCCTT
```

**Oracle SQL, MySQL, 46 bytes**

```sql
SELECT  111222333 SSELCCTTFFRROOMMDDUUAAL  FROM DUAL
```

**Output**

```sql
111222333
```

Comment: The top answer needs an extra *E*: `SELECT  111222333 SSELLCCT` makes it 27 bytes (which makes sense, 26 isn't a multiple of 3).

Comment: Other 27-character solutions exist, like `PRINT 123PRINT 123PRINT 123` (for MS SQL), but I think I found one for 24: `PRINT 12PRINT 12PRINT 12`, since we can count the newline that PRINT produces.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 27 Characters

```
print"\\\"printprint**"*333
```

The output and code comply with the rules.  All characters occur 3 times in the code, as you can probably see.  Since I'm multiplying by multiply of 3 the output will always be divisible by 3.

Answer (score 2):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 21 bytes

```
aaa^*2^bbb^*2^ccc^*2^
```

Outputs:

```
aaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaabbbcccaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaabbbcccaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaabbbccc
```

Which is a 117 byte long string containing 81 `a`s, 27 `b`s and 9 `c`s.

---

This also works for 9 bytes but it isn't as fun:

```
aaabbbccc
```

Comment: I see you have an interest in Carrot :D Maybe you can help me decide a potential feature change in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38136800#38136800) (don't mind the wrong ping in the message btw :/).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 15 bytes

```
'&::'o::'&::o&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/19dzcpKPR@IgXS@Wv7//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
say"\\\"ssaayyxx33"x3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIpJiZGqbg4MbGysqLC2Fipwvj//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine](https://turingmachinesimulator.com/), 180 bytes

```
name: z
init: init
accept: accept

init,_
a1,0,>
a1,_
a2,0,>
a2,_
b0,0,>
b0,_
b1,1,>
b1,_
b2,1,>
b2,_
c0,1,>
c0,_
c1,2,>
c1,_
c2,2,>
c2,_
accept,2,>

name,3
name,3,-
za0,3
za0,-,-
```

Note the trailing new line. You can paste the source code into [here](https://turingmachinesimulator.com/). The machine takes 3*3=9 steps by simply going right and outputting `000111222` (the infinite blank symbols `_` to the left and right are not counted). The last two states are unused states to have the source code fulfill the requirements. The used alphabet is `_0123-`, which is also dividable by 3 :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
..3.3**3*
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=..3.3**3*&a=1)

The output may not be what one would expect. Hope this is more interesting. Still output the same string repeated thrice, though.

### Explanation

```
..3          Two character literal. ASCII: [46, 51]
   .3*       Two character literal, "3*"
      *      Interlace, [46, "3*", 51]
       3*    Repeat 3 times
             Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>153</s> <s>150</s> <s>144</s> <s>138</s> <s>135</s> <s>120</s> <s>117</s> 111 bytes

```java
class Sbccddggmossuvvyy{public static void main(String... a){{};;System.out.print(",,,".replace(",", ",ab"));}}
```

-27 bytes thanks to *@ØrjanJohansen*.

Prints `,ab,ab,ab`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DcnbCcQgEEDRVsSvCK4NWIYVjA@CWV/EURCxduPX5XAf6PDLxaXH/vc2AWolShtj7X3HXGvrfYxZmg7ekIqAJz17SyL4dCl8fbqFEATYnEtKNSq6KHJDUc7Ci3LOqXhdCWDcEeWEctCUMbnW3h8)

[Code used to verify the occurrences of the characters are multiplies of 3](https://tio.run/##dVDBSsNAFPyV54Kwa@Ji6S2hliKKhdYKqSf1sNm8ppsmm7DZREMoeNev7I/ElXpQwdNj3gwzw2SiFedlhTpLdsOgiqo0FjL35I1VOT8LlbZoNkIizPvaCqsktKVKoBBK08gapdPHZ8H6paigmGh8gVtRbx2iLNyUhsqtMCCDLyKSQms0NOpqiwVXmnGNr3ahNFLGbXnlpDNjREcZK3jVWCr9gqfo7uHt4/D2zk4musnzKXWl2G/GGwWjY@AqzlBawKDgO@wip2HsO7FsLK9cY5trih4JgHhHF2Qe/WGK7HR8eTElT/ZutYYZLB8W6/n94hpWNzAmASGMhfv9MMhc1DVEsZRJkqZFWddN23ZdXzVx7nb6Zy7OObjB@n0Y/u1Fie/7hBuscre4Q8QH4ov4GPgJ), which is a modified version of [my answer for a different challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string/83741#83741).

**Explanation of the basic golfed program (72 bytes):**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwbe6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzOriyuCQ1Vy@/tESvAChYoqGkk5gEQUqa1rW1//8DAA)

```java
interface M{                          // Class
  static void main(String[]a){        //  Mandatory main-method
    System.out.print(",ab,ab,ab");}}  //   Print ",ab,ab,ab"
```

**Things I (and *@ØrjanJohansen*) did to create multiples of 3:**

- Changed `interface` to `class` (and added `public`  before `static`).
- Changed class-name to `Sbccddggmossuvvyy`
- Changed `String[]a` to `String... a`
- Added unused no-op `{}`-block
- Added two no-op `;`
- Changed `",ab,ab,ab"` to `",,,".replace(",", ",ab")`

Comment: You have `nnn` in there... Otherwise, I thought duplicating `System.out.print("")` seemed verbose, so I played around with some `String` methods, and managed to save 3 more bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtRCsQgDAWvIv1qPzYX6DF6gqzGki4asakg4tltYVlYeDDDwDuw4EsSxcN9xuColD1aMhs6R@T9vnMIIinlU6@rlFrbqahsTRF2JiDHedPMcQcAWlrrWz2VAsilkJ6u84Rv@90EVqLFJ03Lvz7/MP@wrOva@xg3 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online").

Comment: [Another option](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsQgEAS/EjyZw84H8gxfMKuToGtGiaMgIW93hb1s01BNHTpgw1fKxMF9xvAsdO1oaTHoHNG@HyHEeDKnlHOptfV@F0HxdmnJu@VEzzrMD4jIBxi5/AQArff9mF6ETkhVIE8vWmuFb/urApvYomil1r85s23b84zxBQ "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online") with the same length.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks! And not sure how I missed that `nnn`... Also, managed to golf three more by changing `String...e` to `String...f`, so we can remove the two `e` (and one `f`) in the interface name.

Comment: Oh, `replace` can replace all those methods. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3NCcQgEEDhVoInBdcGUkYqmPUPs8koOgoi1m4CC@/2Hd4JDT4xWTzNb62AZLMDbbcDwBjrvL@uGzGmnAtRra31PgoBBb21GMx2Q0B@UA7olVJOjDH3/eiF7K1iJZVeIc7gq/8xlW263gNnUjLJmBD7nGs9 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: Yeah, realized that ten seconds after my deleted comment.

Comment: Come to think of it, why not use `replace` for its intended purpose? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnbCcQgEEDRVsSvCK4NWIYVjA@CWV/EURCxduPX5XAf6PDLxaXH/vc2AWolShtj7X3HXGvrfYxZmg7ekIqAJz17SyL4dCl8fbqFEATYnEtKNSq6KHJDUc7Ci3LOqXhdCWDcEeWEctCUMbnW3h8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
GGG\L\L\L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/393dPcYHBP//BwA)

Outputs:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
L
L
L
```

(Note the trailing newline)

Explanation:

```
GGG\L\L\L - full program.
GGG       - output the entire alphabet 3 times, and a trailing newline
   \L\L\L - output L 3 times, and a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 51 bytes

```pascal
begin write('ABCABCABC')end.bbggin  wwrrtt(())dd..'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/Pyk1PTNPobwosyRVQ93RyRmC1DVT81L0kpLSQZIK5eVFRSUlGhqamikpenrq//8DAA)

Boring one, please see below.

---

#### [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>78</s> <s>75</s> 72 bytes

```pascal
var f:int32;begin for f:=22to 33do write(' (())..:;;==abbdggvvww')end.a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7DgAREADQq0yHYhV0xGHGNxJBrHD82ewr38Q3YHvyDEQHF2RT@9bK@lRqhzz@cUrtAVrHAXfVnTgDzoWQ0ljrHHofSznnXiZSjxIZ0Qc)

Output:

```pascal
 (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww (())..:;;==abbdggvvww
```

(One string 12 times)

Based on 75-byte solution. I managed to remove 3 `'`s by placing 1 from the string after `end.`. After parsing `end.`, FPC parses 1 more token, then ignores the rest. `'` alone after `end.` causes an error due to not closing the sting literal with another `'`, so I used one `a` from the string as a dummy token.

---

#### 75-byte solution:

Breakthrough solution

```pascal
var f:int32;begin for f:=22to 33do write(' ''(())''..:;;==aabbdggvvww')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLDsAQEADQq8xuWNSCHXGYUZ9IGkSF40/Tt3yD3pueK4@bedOEbGtbRruQSm2Q@z9e69XBmNjhzLqSQEAUQkpEpaxz3hOFEEvZ@xyUqUXF/AE)

Output:

```pascal
 '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww '(())'..:;;==aabbdggvvww
```

(One string 12 times)

---

#### 78-byte solutions:

```pascal
var f:word;begin for f:=2to 22do write(' ''(())''..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco7CsAgDADQq2SLDnVwrHiY@CtCMZKKHt@26@N1eiLdR@lx70kC5VwsyYV81QaFf/B2MFibGJbUkRUColJaIxpzOuc9UQjX95lFxpwLdW7J7P0C)

Output:

```pascal
 '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw '(())'..:;;==aabbgginoorrtvvw
```

(one string 21 times)

or

```pascal
var f:byte;begin for f:=2to 22do write(' ''(())''..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBDsAQEADAr@xtOdTBkXjMqiWSBmmFeL2210mm0XPSdcR27j3ohmj86mw9p1wg1h@c7hW0DhXmnTsLBEQhpERUyljrHJEPzOkbY8y5FkouQe39Ag)

Output:

```pascal
 '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy '(())'..:;;==aabdeegginvvwwyy
```

(one string 21 times)

or

```pascal
var f:char;begin for f:='a'to'c'do write('  (())..:;;==bbcdgghhinrrtvvww')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjLCcAgDADQVXKLHuoAFYeJ8QtFJRUd39J3fINepudKg89ZJJBuLiTWx1wbpP6HQ8LZkTF02FJnVAiglNbG3NY65z2HnEupTWSutTfq2II55wM)

Output:

```pascal
  (())..:;;==bbcdgghhinrrtvvww  (())..:;;==bbcdgghhinrrtvvww  (())..:;;==bbcdgghhinrrtvvww
```

That `v` in `var` really starts to annoy me...

Comment: Once you start adding things after `end.`, you can just put all the extra chars there, scrap the `var` and `for`, and `write` a single constant string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 18 bytes

```sh
<<<$_
<<<$_
<<<$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGJZ4Lmfz/HwA)

Also valid: `$-` with default options, and sometimes `$$`.

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) <s>36 33 30</s> 27 bytes

This solution produces an *acyclic* output:

```sh
echo {e,h,o}{,{}}  eho\\cc\
```

---

```sh
echo {e,h,o}{,{}}  eho\\cc\
     {e,h,o}{,{}}            # expands to e h o e{} h{} o{}
                   eho       # eho
                      \\c    # '\c' stops printing
```

The output contains 3 `e`, 3 `h`, 3 `o`, 3 `{`, 3 `{`, and 6 `<space>`.

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVrDTdNKt9pNT0@zFkKq6KroamhYWenp1f7/DwA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX0E3T6E6VSdZJ6O2Wrc6P69WRxdIKACl/v8HAA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX6E6VSdDJ7@2Wqe6tlZBITUjPyYmOTnm/38A)

---

> Comments on 33 byte solution:

***-3** bytes by using ) as the end of the range (still divisible by 3)*

```sh
<<<${(F):-{F..)}{F..)}$-$-((::..}
   ${   :-                      }  # empty string fallback
          {F..)}                   # The range {F..)} has 30 elements...
          {F..)}{F..)}             # so {F..)}{{F..)} has 900 elements
                      $-$-((::..   # Leftover junk, added to each of the 900 elements
   ${(F)                        }  # Join by newlines
<<<                                # Print to stdout
```

If trailing newlines are allowed, then `<<<aabbccabc` is a **12 byte** solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 12

`+++111222333` outputs `111222333`.

### Tricks Used:

The leading `+` gets auto-corrected to an `=`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 9 bytes

```c
O!O!O!000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCey4Kq2bMsUyUKKOgJZSG4/gC8IWQbVyrJPkmFZwv71XHfPi0Z@yV3ullRZ1szTPd3P9HT3OFH3Loq@vUqyKF1O4mFRTpL56/tR0xxJk9vaUFQ@LeIVUJ5kd7WhMpkJzCSeJlnM0pSl8@yOPpp69NPZ5w@sV71efrpgfvX6j8MLtl@9Hp@9Yz9VrxefWa8CH59eGtizz6cG9PPZh8PLv9sFZzZ@tNmfvb9xPXt4CcuKyeg@zJnDKwETBbZqFaMR26/mzo5@xckMJsmjrwy/D4crGFyGMOgmYNKUI7CGeXt@fkog/DggJ/vom2HIxXsBAHnD1ocwXcacX2Vj3mySH7ArV@PgonV0fmx/O9/Bf57nfePw3hoIiAOYOJyxAMGDZhM0LsK8iG3OnpuNJCtZMmg2YJS0u8yZLrMIRkg4gvdytnCLRXblj4Nnz/VeQEcjAXWEh6eHA2/eoPpkwR7vkzIuFmEUNxvwPY1tGAdxW5jhstZ1eZ1dT69z9vxyNbZ5/1WLkymNZMpsbW3ArFcWZ0KFGt2B0esMhjsdMQJ2NuK0iM2BF2FOdB9Hv7HpPGfZcnYb54W0h9lJMUnuklJphdXRnZ6rPRJPh/U81mGOtLzT4azLLM@CJdDShLM8Lpd5xlQ8CDEKicGqDQ9hnoS3aaysACPS@WOc2xGspwxhX78yZVxEbxER8cXikp5kg@tJ0HNhjwI9vGIdnjAZiQDJJsuFjVvKJKddBm/rBovzXghtwoxry6psalli00AYPNBGMVAC@QG@g2WLsChZeR@DsjAvASw3wFGM4oZGHD1RxhrHZqux8NnjtNGNigwyH0O3TOYZmI0R643BtEgxUiwXCyScq6hSIyb9ZvwB7QbZqEOF8iKDOIZchZErLResfLL0gRYDxziAeauP@QrNVEFGqU64aqPdaGqYpvPI3vfcHkcHcVg7QQ5myzQN8yfT0Wp/Lozt@Whpy2hBKb/MVqRpiR4uIZPCJk8Pj96@u/ll5/Tnc8NhU@1tslGvv653p6b4/cnlFo1lnJPKMJuwfy1D9YpqH8wl9taXEAS8tzQXJxu4IOH9unAd80KpMl9muEMDmW@dcl7YKlfSAYDQLpOI0eztcnrl74@lHWKj25QetAHFAo5VObUBCv7vpumkpfIO1RsXlawqgEOhFYhKJtav4Yast1f3E53HWDxgrTJfxi2IQT2OIQnj0xAyCE60MLJaFQnoJ/ouSw7R8eXtfJ7CzG2dga2@Vm59zyHnxz0yzbxdMzNFG7O/1EYI2nKeprZpqss8FyrE/2BytmYyVuEPhx/PXKzFItDg9eSqB8UcwglcgVf1ViR/xF9Kho@BEaOGt8gAvLn44dPnXtBTJR0zHFZ1fNCnLx57ADg@OT1y2BSS46ChQ1uuh2k4ChduGmfUARhcqY5IcAbnbhsZq4JYm7C0YcGxE@oloBYPiYsBFJUEJ3XeiGaLlR0gkpJxlUKQpmSMyxSPSRnd2w4ws9ZAAUdM/kVYp6xDq89wFQEIkFBswSAL8zY5JdXLJrAWsnxAVbhCUKdZ5li6qNm8GvPnKsyggaLcLha@gIXrunPIeDZve79P8a9CfgQkaBUc3cVlCn2i3aa9bOMOYYmcJBkfJFPbpv3EhiC6z9EWF@KUc7HNgTfYaCs8OLUBYr0jsZ7oHDEbSEIGyl4kSebOysq3lT8Cr2feVTMoaVKsMTeAwWiA@AsW80Wc2cbCbitvUasAVgUzUSkhHgPf2/@JxmVzYYuOZAqmT9ApaOEgZF3s7wAOvQO94RqwtAovGwZZJ6BWCE8sILmkG/TQWkQ1anAC5ps9S0Vj5ckv4En8O7RxeNrX/Nyp7TpdB3Ywk60BT9fCA1ZJ67wY8J@tvuwTNwSyznyyArXOqC22sQZxVYRGo31eNZZr6VCJXlJzaO8WKFg/DOvCQCe0Pua6kEl5q4KqCSwvcZhJtdtKmKxZ5g7I3CJZOK9YwIMhLj5ImtjPGnWs3aY7VLeL0LFoc6@p3W4os3ZfOwXYY8MbZ@qo5Yb5y7JQu69jQvR6wqCONojyJORLTMkYWsb2iG66Ud9tcSFFNPT9TMWSL/Yc@186DGIDCIXDeMoD5aXPN4dqFJbqIbvOXqeiiavvqItDN@rSs5Q5QvrVXYtOI9qxVa/bK4Scanc2sLBanjfw4KzxIPZ1EwuzDa45hAlMJSQANcimDBlY13DJQ9Cg2yV9kigqmasbLRgta6f/zXeJebOZmN3vCu1uFvonsVlzSFwdaMw3vRxI2gXrAev2NMuEBep7cM66PThjPRPs/yB6COmxhg0ChNK6fTXiKcqJaH/kSa59Tu2KExD/zdUDQZPkCtwRKMFiiYHveGW4j/PYKlg2hx46ScskY4/hE/DGJnO4k5bxXZyDzGKexVmZhHiLgJM8Z48xuw8fYgBKRQgv2SzMlhA@T69xFL27RcaBCmKiWKYl/mhAi@uEpyBdE6OWXKHMlNOQFfWobzvS226Ihg1rKI/u52GKtfEJvM4maTxhN5XZN1rLM34TjZmxSOXMCJV1u@qdE7whoY5h@ovOg0MK1pXCh0mvlheDelY8YObhH5rHAEX78qe2NhOAA1ZrFGnQZUY2RB2ekFQl1xd1ALE7AVQbowsawaHE0JpP5n02i2fRAsMsY6Obg//XldFf4MpIubKzwZdA@iJdOdjOvlh1g8k4fcBqAF8jfFVAdzbZWb1o91TmMRVo89pV@kNfNtWGA1NSphIt//W/kZc5yFCj5QdW30TX2txVbFBl3fr0D19kVG9b3WQQ16jdZnQqJAxqHAc1aSNNogQiOh0tJkz@FdwTv3qZjWbNO2b2LlLspN61I9SQP/D7ewYt78WVITA6rI5ZgNbvSJm8eLj6LOzVGtpLQfSK0sFqyfM3lbw9rvsAX0vv0@B/aIjQMHziVkS6@dftkNkb@eAhrtrpYZNEDYKIfzFJD0J05EmA1SfxNIQkCZ6pDjPJYDKZ0I9IYVRCmbJ2Iwt7ThzhbMstFpXpGgjdoPwhYRYmGTarLMzvIpeUOg58f@D4cxXdL/F/bmyPrKlf416@/Rs)

Output: 3x 't', 3x 'r', 3x 'u', 3x 'e', 3x newline

```c
true
true
true
```

Basically this abuses the fact that the result of `OUTPUT` is `NULL`, and `!` returns true.

Expanded (which also counts for the 333 rule:

```c
OUTPUT(!OUTPUT(!OUTPUT(!000)))
```

Basically:

```c
!000 -> true
OUTPUT true -> null
!null -> true
OUTPUT true -> null
!null -> true
OUTPUT true -> null
```

Note that `000` is just an overlong constant for `0`, and `!0` is also `true`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
+₇S₇S₇S++
```

This is not fully in the spirit of the challenge (because it repeats the output), but it the code itself doesn't repeat which is nice.

###### Mini-explanation:

```
₇S computes "128", so ₇S₇S₇S pushes three strings to the stack
+ is concat, so ++ at the end concats all three together, while the beginning one is ignored
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2B%E2%82%87S%E2%82%87S%E2%82%87S%2B%2B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 12 bytes

```
yes yes yes
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZrKlOLFWAYIgSVgakAAA)

Note the trailing space. Outputs `yes yes` with a newline, repeated infinitely, so all the characters arguably appear a multiple of 3 times.

---

More boring and definitely allowed:

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 15 bytes

```
<<<AAA<<<BB<<<B
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhbrbWxsHB0dgaSTE4iAiEIlYYoA)

Outputs with a trailing newline:

```
AAA
BB
B
```

And if we could have a trailing newline without needing it thrice, we could just have `<<<aaabbbccc`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Flipbit](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Flipbit), 15 bytes

```
^...>^...>^...>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/P05PT88OQfz/DwA)

Outputs `0x01`x3, `0x03`x3, and `0x07`x3.

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, <s>12</s> 9 bytes

*3 Bytes saved thanks to @Luis*

```
JVvJVvJVv
```

Outputs:

```
0 +1i
0 +1i
0 +1i
```

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@8VVgZB//8DAA)

**Explanation**

`J` is the shortcut for the complex number `0 + 1i`. We convert this to a string with `V` and repeat this motif 3 times and concatenate the entire stack vertically three times using `v`.

Comment: @LuisMendo Unfortunately since MATL trims trialing newlines it only has 2 :(

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah you're right! There's also the newline in the TIO version. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 9 bytes

```
¬ac¬ac¬ac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@39oTWIyDP//DwA)

This outputs:

```
ababcabcc
```

This is pretty straightforward. Each `¬` is the "range operator", that takes two character arguments and inserts each character in that range. So `¬ac` inserts `abc`. Repeating this three times causes some weird issues with the layout of the output (which is why they're not in order) but thankfully this doesn't matter for this particular answer.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 9 bytes

```
?12?21?21
```

Output:

```
12
21
21
```

Not the most exciting thing, but it fulfills all 3 recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 123 bytes

```
Sub Auto_Open()
god_fx = ("OK" + " X")
For rapid = 1 To 3
MsgBox god_fx, 3 + 1 = rapid, Mid("mk OK X", 3 + 1)
Next
End Sub
```

It's a sub, but when you paste it in an empty Excel workbook, it'll run when you open the workbook.

Displays a MsgBox with in it 3x the text "OK" and 3x an "X" (the close button looks like an 'X', right?!)  It even does this 3 times in a row for good measure :)

There are only 5 line endings in here, but that's because the VBA IDE always appends an empty line, making it 6 again.  And since VBA doesn't care about case, I didn't either :P

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 24

```
puts 12
puts 12
puts 12
```

In the code, there is an Enter at the bottom, which the site ate.

**Output:** the output consists of `12Enter12Enter12Enter`

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRjJLNDA1NDFqMW8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 87 bytes

```
AET=' TEE'
exec("""print('A TE');exec('print("A AT");exec("print(AET)")')""")
AET=="";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@@/oGmKrrhDi6qrOlVqRmqyhpKRUUJSZV6Kh7ggUVde0BouqQ8SUHBUcQ5SgYlB1QAM0lTTVNYEaNblAptkqKVlz/f8PAA)

I wasn't going for the shortest solution - I just really, really wanted to abuse `exec`.

It can probably be made shorter, though I don't remember the last time I've had this much fun golfing python. Great challenge!

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 21 bytes

```
'ans==ans '%%%ans=  '
ans = ans==ans
```

Creates a string: `'ans==ans '`, that's automatically printed (since `;` is omitted), with `ans =`  in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 21 bytes

```
say 10
say 10
say 10
```

Outputs three 10s and three newlines.

I can think of funnier output, but since this is code golf, this is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 27 bytes

```
20111[!_!_!_+]2200++[][];;;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fyMDQ0DBaMR4EtWONjAwMtLWjY6Njra2t//8HAA)

It's a cheap method, but only one I can find that works in braingolf.

### Explanation

```
20111[!_!_!_+]2200++[][];;;
20111                        Pushes 2, 0, 1, 1 and 1 to the stack
     [.......]               While loop, runs 3 times..
      !_!_!_                 ..Prints the last item on the stack 3 times without popping
            +                ..Pops and sums the last 2 items, pushing the result
              2200           Pushes 2, 2, 0 and 0 to the stack
                  ++         Sums 0 and 0, then 0 and 2
                    []       While loop, runs 4 times, does nothing
                      []     While loop, runs 3 times, does nothing
                        ;;;  Suppress implicit output (then do it 2 more times)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 18+1=19 bytes

Requires the use of the command-line switch `-l`

```
"aaabbbccc"\p\p\"p
```

Prints, unsurprisingly, `aaabbbccc`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 24 bytes

```
Print!73Print!73Print!73
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69E0dwYnf7/HwA)

The output is (with a trailing newline):

```
73
73
73
```

For bonus "encouragement" points:

#### Attache, 30 bytes

```
"PPrriinntt""""||**33"*3|Print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/XykgoKgoMzMvr6RECQhqarS0jI2VtIxrAooy80r@/wcA)

This is just:

```
"PPrriinntt""""||**33"*3|Print
"                    "            a string ("" is an escaped double quote)
                      *3          repeated 3 times
                        |Print    then print that string
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 27 bytes

```php
<?=$s=";\<?=\",\<?;",$s,$s;
```

prints `;\<?=",\<?;` three times

```php
<?=$s="\<<?=\",\>>",$s,$s?>
```

prints `\<<?=",\>>` three times

```php
<?=$s=";<?,<?=;","$s","$s";
```

prints `;<?,<?=;` three times

---

Run with `-n` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/564142fc6344c61c22d73392b6626ce571e415fe).
TiO includes checks and two variants of a 30 byte solution.

Answer (score 1):

## JsFuck, 1044 Bytes

```
[!!(([[]]))][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]])()(+(+!![]+[!![]+!![]]+(+[])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(+[])))
```

Bad one

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
,⎕A,⎕A,⎕A
```

This prints the alphabet, 3 times.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pj5qm6DuX1pSUFpipc6lAxRwRBBcXFAFygr5aQrOGYlFicklqUXFQJXVj3p36TzqXPSod2vto54daBoB)

Also works for the digits `0-9`:

```apl
,⎕D,⎕D,⎕D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pj5qm6DuX1pSUFpipc6lAxRwQRBcXFAFygr5aQrOGYlFicklqUXFQJXVj3p36TzqXPSod2vto54daBoB)

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 12 bytes

```
1:3,1:3,1:3,
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/f0MpYB4b//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 30 bytes

```
-(i)>:{(-3):{(3)}}


{3>i:->i}
```

Outputs

```
>:3
>:3
>:3
```

and a trailing newline. The output was actually mostly unintentional.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNT086qWkPXWBNIGmvW1nJxcVUb22Va6dpl1v7/DwA)

#### Explanation

```
-(i)     Labelled gather - we can read how many times we've visited this part by looking at the variable i. We can also divert to here.
>:       Print the characters > and :
{(-3):   If negative 3 is nonzero...
{(3)}}    ...print the value of the number 3
         Having at least one linebreak makes ink print a newline.
         (we have three)
{3>i:    If we've passed (i) fewer than three times...
->i}      ...jump to (i)
```

## Boring alternative, 9 bytes

```
11
21

22
```

Outputs

```
11
21
22
```

and a trailing newline. As long as there are four lines, exactly three of which contain one or more characters, you can move and replace the characters (almost) however you want.

#### Explanation

We just print non-space characters as we encounter them, and print a newline whenever we encounter some number of linebreaks (and/or the end of the program)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/f0JDLyJCLy8jo/38A)

## No printing literal characters at all, 39 bytes

```
-(i){3:{-3}}{0:{(0)}}{0}<><>{(i<3):->i}
```

Outputs `-30-30-30` with no trailing newline. This is basically the opposite of how you're supposed to use ink.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNTs9rYqlrXuLa22sCqWsNAE8SotbGzsavWyLQx1rTStcus/f8fAA)

#### Explanation

```
-(i)      Labelled gather - we can read how many times we've visited this part by looking at the variable i. We can also divert to here.
{3:       If 3 is nonzero (it is)
{-3}}     Print -3
{0:       If 0 is nonzero (is isn't)
{(0)}}     ...print 0 (we won't)
{0}       Print 0 (we *will*)
<><>      This is glue. It suppresses newlines.
{(i<3):   If we've passed (i) fewer than 3 times...
->i}       ...divert to (i)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 9 bytes

```
aaa333@@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z8xMdHY2NjBweH/fwA)

#### Explanation

Pushes 10 three times, pushes 3 three times, then prints and terminates. The extra two `@` serve no purpose beyond complying with challenge requirements. [`"3*@"`](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/JWMvh/38A) would comply with output rules (and is the shortest program that can), but does not comply with source rules.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 15 bytes

```perl
}{s{}{$~$~$~}ss
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@2uri6tlqlDgRri4v///@XX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 12 bytes

```
3a3o3a3o3a3o
```

Outputs `333666999`.

This contains six `3`'s, three `a`'s, and three `o`'s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 9 bytes (filename).

```
~~~.n.n.n
```

Output:

```
126126126
```

### How it works

- Three tildes are not commands; each of they are literals.
- Each literal means to push its own codepoint as an integer.
- `.n` pops one item and output it as a decimal integer (if any).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv/fTzHkRDJDEpJBrEiMSsFrOUcpPuqyAroCBAVD4CRB0YBfvXfPJAiE3q5bV83Mbz9nP@bhs//06y9UsPetzl7Hbuey6Nx6Q7sKyuk5uuXbAVLtiTEZWv4z0vVczrCn45EXoLPyQ@nszCwbOHgb2@jRDjojt5dO81lnNBxabpccal37RXMnjoNyh2maTsfC9dL1N1MQccyH1PFCAScRMWQfuTiPBupcWJj9UavePlxdV8ycru8swPr3q@rt2c@H8vfLy5PytUmNBhLE8Gvp6tvDzcnlVfV7rSi/zQVkojfUSqf5qkZoPPL702gmf41E7v6HhD2cOFZgI/@J84/GAQxfR17XHzv9IJ22nL7lI/URSWJIZUE8FuaSKbGvlE7Xfpydlc8rZpHbwMxe1/Cf@r3A4GPE@GLA7jyNkPgXYZYps5wCQ7mR0z1MQ@hfLAcJKdSzHN8WZrNVGlfNpacz3@4iydem2ptm@PDrXZO4wnfUYkKcC3gWoh1M8AiSUHKR@hJM6CzwkFr2UbOhq/stJDWabqYlzR49e4yykXLtPv9F1MJiyRDbRs3Qmi6f18HcfTbbdDXNaJeMeTRt3DM9lOZEbawZwSpY0DcxSqmojRLg3v4mRilIu0nGwiZG9V1R6ycZdzaxfeB7SGJguZPAvuxtYpSCsJ9c384mRim4@JJk/LKJUR0i1ku6rW9iVIeI2Ukf9zcxSvOi5iVN5zYxSkH6Ncm4t4nRHPgzTTIWNjGaAx/fkoz7mxjNgT/vySTov8HAHSu56N1NjFKIbZC0nN/EqA7uDJPx3tvEqA7udJOmC5tYHtIvJzFwUU1gO8CXSmLgtZjEwJlths2lGe5Y8XbRJXFT8n7VwlPWlFOjC/13yqSbONskTdx02e9spklErbnTzDWpBly@ls1At07X@7voGGIq1Bqv07d3q9vSUmHNaDugcG68QbNrSDO0xn1MZSUuaqirrelQXSTF5hv3x0oL7IIHuBENwYXcMWIuPMU8EY6yGSBxzyLrsJ4xd1PUFIa2wQVIcQizVOjDqKSNjfYFoBGbcgwKPhm7n4xdrbJgXGNbUOI4FD1DDCNzx4iphi2Oc6PSAglKPLRiqgaUpttA6nsr02XaAm8FgSXx@LSixWqcZAHbmOc0WpwVSc3B2@LFp8os9y24SOy5cTy@QWQqJYjLNE4uj@wyblF8TmNN/H/kSuRJnPXfCUpocXSsJETr97BjtW3HNIUmFUjIV4Ib45Hbf@j4Lz3bC4ZyStxWW4y7STExtMeIh9VjM6RKc85IddykMc1adcmftLHAEiIoTPoIxkJROBYUbpbMY4Pr/H9iroha27OtZz6BvJWw4IxGY@SOAjS0gs5T330UgFVaLFfGRGtjSrhvKp@o8SzFZ3o0EWHy72KyzSeMDZqRN6LUG3lxrMAjwyChZHx2qTSXCNn69Z9a6fzElD4@PrIu@5G2yt9r1ye1a3Nr7PXdoAfnOOcRY1yYvXaQ2oGD@pfvdUzp68lptRZCUmTftrvE9@AChflw3pu4naA/clEdV0h41XhW/sGkZVYMGLZkeUk/wST07GDiuSglA8@S8veSAvghXVL@WVKYuiXheo3ATKp0hXyLL0l4aQIXd0NVjZj5cskzwWUS8uWj8hI9xZfK3aduuCA6fdc@1I9EvaiuOPYtMiBSgxfGPa86GepDEMgahCJo0/wPZn7imiu2S/h84dH5TIAkQvzZJbQfoBXTY1j661PfsXEKQkpGq5GESQjgbDbBt0BbElxcVW6UiuIQlkUuGN6YwGM4pmO7j8ETviEGK6Uq3GSrB6ZjkAnGFRPW4gcevlGqsqxQQj4Evi7hqCLnC8X8LpkvjfTBeh2frhl@wOdKWblTfpLw3BSyD0VUg4awUNfu9Idws4TF2o@2B9/xJBCMsgnixh34wHxh1Qzu5vcOyul0@WC3QHiLGYCVP4T7fGNntyXC7nBn5vNqORaOuhBYcCESo3kISNk0d3IkjFjg0h/03Yk9ZxFnrOWDfAF4Dnf3CIMi40uzkWby08Q/CSqr@YLBsmfU8V3m58paO4vo1/H1WhD8BeF2NVkvkJOBckPCqqlziwOT1zGEf8DKVhmoasu8YYlis2qLg5CHFp8PWiuh95amIaKY9yfJsBpYMfi6bJpNb6b4QuG2UtCOLMIpmF3wErkxLw4Ybyx7sxR6@6PQ4e@F3j/dYFLcDXXNlWCxmCfoXXONNATSMxQLgjdRHTP6CrGNLQhoVOJ/swqvY@sIxGWLRaJ4G0fEWO4YGZOquQy2DnSSYTmD70pQ/03qG8QdcxsvFg8yDoGKATNCdhuOhCxUo1BEd7YHN6T@S98HNQIrFJYU62hw6BwNtp2isz0o8rHGx5CjebTDgmem3oJygGccXt@ahVmHCNLSuR5EYo3rc@vefFb94VVlRsdRdAeAKxYcT@x1q3ruM511JjDqSkhCai@3OLfgylLHacKedyvu2LyYo/MwhMLlBf0sy4YsDw4w24RZ0ULIo/AP4ikMiPH7ZbDldm3Hhhcw5BlaId6eoEFkuXoA4jKNWoKfNFWuUabQJ9GmL0fz1lwy2EnFnv5wSeog/ueBCeuQ0ZA9dgH0NsBlDLt5pNbyawyzGR7Dw7sEr/l@V7GD/tBWxp3xRHnx340uPNnJag7yf37aosDqO3Bxza8EmF2ewwK7wPBrkjSzXp9BF7JMNUfze/nCzpd8AUmhJZuiPj@pVeJTw4LjXtj6v/Mfa42jwz4CJAAOfIGTJFGH2xf8E5AfpQcL2yNBEXUizaaW9wgxqE5RnLnpr/8C)

Answer (score 1):

## [BrainCrash](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainCrash), <s>21</s> 12 bytes

```
[[[...>>>]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVNNc5swEL37VywTNYFBgHGcNDWG@NCZtpde2pkePA6DsWw0xoIgUSd1yF93V3xMJjloVvv26e3qCUpW5TfnC8OrZeXlRZrk3poLr0QYnD@jC6hlsmMwgxZZVwkXaZXIzC1zkEVdpcxdpzAHLspauepJ4RGVJWIvYVtU8PzvaVRLBlJVPFWB3h6TSnCxk8HhGRaH0Pw8of7Yx3XXLd@n0ym9RtT/0ma@P@2rY3p9beE5wsOxDmUbYMGFzmSVBqf2CkC8QKfhfH71PS7ibzG7Cs7L5dJ13SiKVqvVuYdHfGu2zFePetZJSwsZzn/9/vrjZ6RFFbYoa5lhDyrrNd5DMyhRtk39Y8ZzBjkTO5VpOCKqaUZIg3SntYp8E8qMbxUqLfDeoelP7uhtd7tbekenFDftjQQ7Yie0zNRE66QBOyQx1CJnUpL4Uqs1Gm50gx1T6eRELriIHP@@bYIjztKsgsnNTcP@oguap8fYd26lxYaFj0fDwORTetjoPURADktSrsJx18jE1LYRsAJ8VVI6jnaojMaY2wPX7GOIraz78axLbT8A5wPFuu@i48@QG4ALZcWFMnHOgYHCS2idHJATrKCBl0GqCy/DYAFcvq9cvlUe3lce3iqvQyXdDW0CIyBow@nRoEajzegZRbUxW3tNS3P60eKwf378WijZ6@fHV9KeumErQ@LGJR7fwoZtuWCbAQzyRCrgW7KP@i8FFZr@JHb9YIhtoyXv7DAaJzKtQP83ZIE6i/N/)

---

Previously:

```
...^...^...^[[[>>>]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVNNc5swEL37VywTNYFBgHGcNDWG@NCZtpde2pkePA6DsWw0xoIgUSd1yF93V3xMJjloVrv79N7qCUpW5TfnC8OrZeXlRZrk3poLr8QyOH9GF1DLZMdgBm1lXSVcpFUiM7fMQRZ1lTJ3ncIcuChr5aonhUdUloi9hG1RwfO/p1EtGUhV8VQFentMKsHFTgaHZ1gcQvPzhPpjH9ddt3yfTqf0Gqv@lzbz/WnfHdPrawvPER6OdSjbAAsudCarNDi1VwDiBToN5/Or73ERf4vZVXB2XfdhWMvlMoqi1Wp17vsjvjXbI68e9ayT1hAynP/6/fXHz0izK9Qqa5mhGJX1Gi@kEZQo26b@MeM5g5yJncp0OSKqaUYIg3SnuYp8E8qMbxUyLdCA0PQnd/S2u@YtvaNTipv2aoIdUQm9MzXQOumCHZIYapEzKUl8qdkaXW60wI6pdHIiF1xEjn/fiuCIszSrYHJz07C/aIfG6TH2nW1psWHh49EwMPmUHjZ6DxGQw5KUq3DcCZmY2jYWrACfl5SOox0qozHm9oA1@xiilHU/nnWp7QfgfIBY9110/BliA3ChrLhQJs45IJB4Ca2TQ@UEK2jgZaDqwsswWACX7zuXb52H952Ht87r0El3g0xgBARtOD0a1Gi0GT2iqDZma69paUw/Whz2z49fCyV7/fz4StpTN2xpSNy4xONb2LAtF2wzFIM8kQr4luyj/ktBhqY/iaofDLFttOSdHUbjRKYV6B@ILJBncf4P)

Comment: The TIO appears to show a different program.

Comment: fixed; thanks for commenting me so.

Answer (score 1):

## [JSFuck](http://jsfuck.com/) (eh, plain JavaScript), 2820 bytes

```javascript
(+[[]])+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]](([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[+[]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+(+[![]]+[])+[+[]]+(+[![]]+[])+[+[]]+(+[![]]+[])+[+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+([+[]]+![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VXRCsIwDPyWvjUEvyjkYagP@qCi4u/XWtuSZnMKtgPnGBQakrskPW777tZd1ufd6bo6HDdb5ywSMQNaYrKGGImB/MGYb8afaMpYvssSj1ADpUxXOd/DxzhGskfLxKqAxpvI5JpJYqVA232oVuqvR83I9k/euMEmhxBetuG/WP0uVQIGLhgftPmMSfohbbGE2VuCbEWssM6UEVYNK/Q10dBDmig5flDo03qD/pP0HzcYH5m46OQkn0QWNcxTDU@@ek1opwIL4Nwd)

Probably not the most optimal JavaScript solution (but I doubt anyone will try to optimize it).

Prints:

```javascript
NaN0NaN0NaN0
```

The program contains:

- `(`: 159
- `)`: 159
- `!`: 339
- `+`: 651
- `[`: 756
- `]`: 756

Fun fact:

The program (as an expression) evaluates to `NaN`. (When executing as a full program, it is discarded, so it isn't part of the output.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 21 bytes

```
3>\..3...(;...d/dp]%<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/39guRk/PWE9PT8MaSKTopxTEqtr8////a16@bnJickYqAA)

Formats into this triangle:

```
     3
    > \
   . . 3
  . . . (
 ; . . . d
/ d p ] % <
```

Prints `210210210`. (`2`, `1` and `0` each printed 3 times.)

The program with only conrol flow:

```
     .
    > \
   . . .
  . . . .
 . . . . .
/ . . . . <
```

The above is a nice loop we can fit the code into. To achieve the desired output we simply want to print `210` three times. So we push 3 to the stack (the number of times we want to print it) and then 3 after a directional (3 decrements to 2, then to 1, then to 0).

The first directional `\` pushes 3 to the stack, then puts the code into this loop: `(d%]`. That loop first decrements the top of stack, then prints it, then jumps back if the vale is nonzero.

The next part looks like this: `pd;` which pops the ToS (to get rid of the 0), decrements the new ToS (which was the 3 we pushed at the start), exit if the ToS is `<= 0`, then uses directionals to get back into the initial loop.

Comment: I like how the triangle code contains 30 spaces :)

Comment: Each character in the source should appear three times