# Four-Four-Four-Four!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

This is the sequel to one of my previous challenges, [Three-Three-Three!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108133/three-three-three)

---

Write a program (or function, or snippet) that takes no input and produces an output according to the following four Conditions.

> Both the program and the output must be written such that:
>
> 1. At least 16 distinct characters appear (since 16 = 4 × 4).
> 2. The number of occurrences of each character is a multiple of 4.
>
> Also:
>
> 3. The program and the output must not be the same (because [programs consisting of a single literal like `1111222233334444` are quite boring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108142/47097)).
>
> Finally, the program:
>
> 4. Cannot be written as a string repeated 4 times (e.g. `f();f();f();f();`, `1234123412341234`).

It's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)! In anticipation of a multi-way tie for 64 bytes, the first submission whose *output* also satisfies Condition 4 will be the winner.

### Notes

- You are encouraged not to use comments to satisfy Conditions 1 and 2.
- Feel free to [embed wild bananas in your variable names](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108133/three-three-three#comment263154_108145) as you see fit.

Comment: So, point 4 is absolute and 3 is optional? I suggest changing the order if that's the case.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Will do.

Comment: @StewieGriffin In what way is this a duplicate? This challenge imposes more restrictions than its predecessor.

Comment: [My previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116967/31516), and the same answer adapted to the new rules: `'ans====ans  ans'%%%%ans==== ' '`

Comment: And the 4th `'` and 4th `=`?

Comment: Fixed. Also, the most upvoted [Javascript submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108152/31516) adapted: `alert(((alert|alert|alert||4444333311112222)))`, and [CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108135/31516): `10,10,10,10,`

Comment: The four trailing spaces in the CJam snippet isn't shown, but they're there.

Comment: All right, updated Condition 1 to require at least 16 different characters. I think that should discourage direct adaptations from Three-Three-Three. :)

Comment: 16 distinct characters and a minimum code size of 64 bytes makes this not very interesting. Getting the perfect score will be trivial in most languages.

Comment: @darrylyeo hey I am from Spark (a year or so ago) username was also Christopher. Can you contact me in TNB?

Comment: If this *wasn't* considered a duplicate, how would Five-Five-Five-Five-Five and Six-Six-Six-Six-Six-Six be any more interesting? What about Two-Hundred-Fourty-Six^246? If all n for this sequence are valid, non-duplicates, PCCG will quickly fill with trivial variants.

Comment: Condition 4 *still* doesn't ban literal-only answers, so not only is this a duplicate, it's one that fails to fix the obvious exploit to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 16 bytes

```
4,4,4,4,@@@@\\\\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/30QHAh2AIAYI/v8HAA)