# Print last inputted byte

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

You have one string of input bytes, output *only* the last byte in it.

## Rules

Your submission may be a program or function outputting the last byte in the input which

- is either a string, *stdin* or command-line arguments, and
- is non-empty.

I was trying to solve this with brainfuck, however all languages are allowed to participate. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

## Examples

```
"?" -> "?"
"29845812674" -> "4"
```

Comment: Welcome, I changed your question to fit our format more properly (note this is what the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is for, usually). However in its current state the challenge is very easy (also in bf), so not sure about that.

Comment: I vote against closing; it may be trivial, but that doesn't make it offtopic

Comment: @MillyWay I think most of the close votes were before the extensive edit by ბიმო

Comment: @ბიმო We have a [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14840/56433) not to edit off-topic questions to make them on-topic which I think would have applied here.

Comment: What kind of string? Is it guaranteed to be ASCII only? Or should we handle UTF-8 (and how?) for example?

Comment: @FireCubez Yes, ASCII only

Comment: @jean Does every string you are to input to the program have only printable ascii (32 to 126), or do some of they have nonprintables and control characters?

Answer (score 13):

## x86-16 machine code, 2 bytes

As @CodyGray correctly points out, taking input as a string and output to a register removes the bulk of the standalone program version.

Input string is in `SI`, length in `CX` and output character is in `AL`:

```
F3 AC  REPZ LODSB      ; start at memory location pointer in SI, put next value in AL,
                       ; loop CX number of times. The last char will be in AL when done.
```

Or **4 bytes** as a "Pascal string" (length is prepended to beginning of string):

```
AC     LODSB           ; first byte is string length
91     XCHG AX, CX     ; move length to CX for loop 
F3 AC  REPZ LODSB      ; start at memory location pointer in SI, put next value in AL,
                       ; loop CX number of times. The last char will be in AL when done.
```

Or **5 bytes** as a "C string" (zero/null terminated), input in `DI`:

```
F2 AE     REPNZ SCASB     ; scan for value in AL (0), end when found and advance DI
8A 45 FE  MOV AL, [DI-2]  ; DI is now two bytes ahead of last, put value of DI-2 into AL
```

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>12</del> <del>11</del> 10 bytes

Or as complete program as IBM PC DOS executable.  Input is from command line, output is to console.

```
B3 80   MOV  BL, 80H            ; BX to DOS PSP at 80H 
8A 07   MOV  AL, BYTE PTR[BX]   ; get command line tail length 
D7      XLAT                    ; AL = [BX+AL] 
B4 0E   MOV  AH, 0EH            ; PC BIOS write to screen function  
CD 10   INT  10H                ; display  
C3      RET                     ; exit to DOS
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Although this certainly gets style points, from a strict golfing point of view, it's worth noting that you are allowed to write functions that return the result in a register. So, this can get a *lot* shorter. You can trivially eliminate 4 bytes, and a rewrite could shrink it down even further. By the way, is that screenshot from an emulator? Which one?

Comment: @CodyGray, oh absolutely, the code to take input from command line and output to console is nearly all of it.  Yeah, I could say "input string in `SI`, length in `CX` output char is in `AL`" and then I think the only code that would be necessary is `REPZ LODSB` (2 bytes) and we'd be done. Of course this approach wouldn't be how you do it if you were coding for efficiency, not size. Your point is very well taken though, I'll post it also as a function that does the meat of the work.

Answer (score 13):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 4 bytes

```
Last
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@98nsbjkv19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkK0kr2SjoKSkaWFiamFoZGZuQmIm5Gak5Ovo1CeX5SToqgUG/sfAA) (If the input could be a list of characters, `&/S` could work.)

### Alternatives

**5 bytes:** `` `@&-1 ``

**8 bytes:** `&/S@List`

**10 bytes:** `` `@«_,-1» ``

**10 bytes:** `Fold!Right`

**10 bytes:** `` `@<~_,-1~> ``

**10 bytes:** `` `^^&:Right ``

**10 bytes:** `{Right^^_}`

**11 bytes:** `Get«_,-1»`

**11 bytes:** `Get<~_,-1~>`

**12 bytes:** `` `@«_,#_-1» ``

**12 bytes:** `` `@<~_,#_-1~> ``

**13 bytes:** `Get«_,#_-1»`

**13 bytes:** `Get<~_,#_-1~>`

Comment: :| wtf so many alternatives

Comment: @ASCII-only Least I could do on a simple challenge like this :p

Comment: Print `Last` inputted byte. The programs contents fit with the challenge

Answer (score 8):

## Brainf***, 7 bytes

```
,[>,]<.
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/XoJLD0

It still doesn't work ;(

Comment: @jean Try it [here](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=ICxbPixdPC4g). (Honestly, I didn't even know ideone did BF).

Comment: Yes, in your link everything works fine. But online judge for this problem uses ideone where it doesn't work ;(

Comment: @jean ideone seems to use `-1` as the EOF. `+[>,+]<-.` should work

Comment: @Jo King Sorry, but the input looks like: 29845812674[enter][EOF] 
how can I print the last digit?

Comment: @jean You have to make a new question for that challenge

Comment: @jean do `<<-.` instead of `<-.`?

Comment: @Jo King Yes!!! +[>,+]<<-. That's it!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, 2 bytes

```
0)
```

MATL uses 1-based modular indexing so this solution grabs the element in the `0`-th position of the input which is the same as the last since the `0` wraps around to the end.

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=0%29&inputs=%27123%27&version=20.10.0)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab the input
0   % Push the literal 0 to the stack
)   % Use this zero to grab the character at the end of the string
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: I'd have gone for `J)`...

Answer (score 7):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), <s>270</s> <s>258</s> <s>247</s> 246 bytes

```
DO,1<-#1PLEASECOMEFROM(2)DOWRITEIN,1DO.1<-,1SUB#1DO.5<-#1$.1~#256DO.2<-.3DO(1)NEXTPLEASE.2<-!3~#15'$.3~#240PLEASE.2<-!2~#15'$.2~#240PLEASE.2<-!2~#15'$.2~#240DO(1010)NEXTDO,1SUB#1<-.3DOREADOUT,1(1)DO(1002)NEXTDO(1009)NEXTDO.3<-.3~#255(2)DOFORGET#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU9NC4JAEP0tsUIKujijawperF1DyDbWlbpGdAiiQ3T2r2@OeujUaT7em/fePF6f@/t2fTondQhlxOB0UFWndrpVtdGtj4HUZ9NY1RxDkJqPnBC6fstoEHTgcRgYimycsYx4IrUPwVFd7KxEy1UyMBBrj48V0/gHwAXA/wBpxhBPshR0CjCbGVVJ3dsQRteJFuNCo75Yep4Qm3KK6aVam72yDJzDIk9FDpht0i8)

*-8 thanks to 鳴神裁四点一号 removing `DOGIVEUP` to terminate by NEXT stack explosion, opening up another -4 changing a `PLEASE` to `DO`.*

*-11 removing some grouping from the bit-reversing expression from hell. It seems that binary operators generally act right-associative in C-INTERCAL, though having no precedence among themselves.*

*-1 trying something else for bit reversal--definitely expected more savings than that! A more principled approach might be able to do it in two steps unless there's some obvious invariant I'm missing, but I'm too tired to take a stab at that just yet.*

Writing this was... interesting. I was thinking I might want to use INTERCAL [to INTERCALate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50798/is-it-a-leap-year), but I'm a bit less sure now.

[Ungolfed and commented:](https://tio.run/##3VZdb9s2FH3Pr7hFCjgGHM0fy4YCAYYsdVsDqV04zrpXWqJsLhIpkJRVv/SvZ@eSsmMH6Yy@zghiQ7oizz3n3EMp7aVNRfH0RO3n/Yx6g@vL8wEdfr7cjW/uxzSdLcb0VVIjtCe/lqR0VXsS1ooteUNGF1tai40kV4lUUm4srkmShSyl9j1yhpSnRhVFrPXiUYYKgVXIq1KeHQC5nX0e04f57DNdDLuHN77OJwAymQLqawgnOcApR/hjkLmyztNy67FV/gy7BygdAGmswh3lHW1EUcskSWiJplRO2rwowrNn9J@fysqNMnW7FpVK4/d@bSpNRsOr35LDZhLQ3RvcP/x5Pji6fMUqvH0z@H6OJzove0yuuL0Rw3wWAldQ26MhGVy0jXJHfCbD68tkdHjlYtCl6fjvxdmJtl6w28iOlYQdZI9/b1jpWmcBicT3Ic0JTU3DZaSlzNgllVWwD3ywFOkjGZSA8tvLyXQxnt/e3HXcCTDRbpNfZhBHk7GZtLxsJuFlEA57roXf@0ykvhYFvBa2hQXrpbe4GL0RZYHGjlZG6dUzvtya8mcEZxdfOM9btir3SICLRvl12OqFNTKZi7rw7Z79bqxGoSYrRRbhLdk6LZts4BNgmNBG2MwldG@OyFmZfUPt/s1ujMGcclURJ/jo/k6wnL/BiaH5@OY9zR4WrOcJLOhWWief29i3t1MgIuJxoLlgv@K2wG2kReoP2mdj60xtVBaF5IWg86oIi5eEiyewMBMcQ9@ggXPK6B5NDpaIRuRlgQiUrEWxkUe8U62hLHtKZJCmrpgW0fYoiuTseMzo@pLejL6fD6469Db8Gv7a77xSM9zXDH@i5niC@4N@HOLXhjUZgB72E@dySAcmQ2EOmrVK15wYaGFLqdEbqZVk4yO0G9Zpa@q9BfaaAdRetiMgbYQx5GT0g9Sgf2okMcPhGsMZjPjIaCU5/uemhPy6LqUV4Fo7z4WtCqmxlm2BhzhUDnfemRIQDhFNOwv6OPlrTA9fXs2xO7NSOPp2gVVZs7KiTOiTaVjWHkcrIGdGdzzhVirzmu0XU0b4XQDilFjzFJcGmahci7B3KsTauPwwm38cLygVvMujlBWba58ZLKtreeasjoL3hz8W3HP2hX8FRyHEdltXqCX6gKXx7ACaftvrX5nK8VkC4a0Kno90c82l87u5sNLXVp8KZpjIW1NQXphmFyaFgOIYPg7edB2Rgdh4fA1jacjp1JTtIEZa2zM4RPMoBkc8ihFlXHYCy257JiFsyh1FL4d3A0BKTp16nwCELYCZD4MEImD/EITJqBcxeVvrVIQXiJgJIS6WMmc3FMZUbI3Q1gUYR97A42IVUv@I5pNp6iqjnVrCgM6050kwbBCWzYMUF1UlhY0IQ3QVvHEhVsboMNdCb9tXBQOL0@/v6OKPboDsui9jpf@ufTc4jKQRv0HwG8lV9OQweLI18fng6Wn0P/n8Cw)

```
        DO ,1<-#1             PLEASE NOTE We want the input array to only have space for one element, so it will only take one at a time
        DO COME FROM (2)
        DO WRITE IN ,1        PLEASE NOTE If this is the first byte of the input, it'll write its value... but if not, it'll write the
                              previous value minus its value mod 256.
        DO .1<-,1SUB#1
        DO .5<-#1$!1~#256'    PLEASE NOTE .5 is 3 if the input is 256, 2 otherwise
        DO .2<-.3
        DO (1) NEXT

                              PLEASE NOTE If we're here, we've found the end of the input. Now, we need to print it back out... C-INTERCAL's
                              array I/O, in order to determine what it will actually print, subtracts the value it's going to print from the
                              previous one (still mod 256, and with the previous value defaulting to 0), and then reads the bits of the byte
                              backwards. So in order to go from the value we want to display to the value we need to feed into READ OUT, we
                              reverse the bits and then subtract from 256. Rather than select the bits out individually and mingle them all
                              in one expression, I mingle the back and front halves of the byte until it adds up to a reversal.

        DO .2 <- !3~#15' $ !3~#240'
        DO .2 <- !2~#15' $ !2~#240'
        DO .2 <- !2~#15' $ !2~#240'

        DO (1010) NEXT        PLEASE NOTE .1 already has 256 in it, which is very convenient for when you need to subtract .2 from 256.

        DO ,1SUB#1 <- .3      PLEASE NOTE If we just read .3 out, we'd get a Roman numeral instead of the correct output.
        DO READ OUT ,1

        DON'T GIVE UP         PLEASE NOTE Logical end of program. However, if we don't gracefully terminate here, nothing more is output,
                              and the FORGET can't keep up with the NEXTs.

    (1) DO (1002) NEXT        PLEASE NOTE that that line in syslib does 1001 next, which pops .5 entries off the next-stack and returns
                              control flow to the last one, such that if .5 is 2 flow will come back here, but if it's 3 then it'll go back
                              to the line that nexted to this one.

                              Here we add .1 and .2 into .3, then truncate it to a byte before looping back (while managing the next-stack
                              responsibly so the program doesn't disappear into the black lagoon for any input over 79 (?) bytes)

        DO (1009) NEXT
        DO .3<-.3~#255
    (2) DO FORGET #1
```

Comment: DOGIVEUP can be removed to golf off 8 bytes because program halts by stack overflow and output is unchanged

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 14 bytes

```python
lambda x:x[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fahvzPycxNyklUaHCqiJa1zD2f0FRZl6JRqqGkr2Spo4CkDaytDAxtTA0MjM3AYoUpxbYKsXkKWn@BwA)

Comment: I feel dumb, how are you calling this without declaring it to a variable?

Comment: I looked at your TIO, but it doesn’t make much sense... What are you doing in your header?

Comment: @Bobawob For your first question, anonymous lambdas are allowed for answers (I call it using by assigning the lambda to the variable `e` in the header). For your second question, the header is `e=\ `, which basically means `e=lambda x:x[-1]`

Comment: Note that in my above comment, there is not supposed to be a trailing space in `e=\ ` but Markdown escapes the code character so I have to add a trailing space

Comment: That’s really cool! Thank you!

Comment: @NathanDimmer Thanks! When you make an anonymous lambda as a PPCG answer, you should use the format my answer used for the TIO link to make it easier to test your test cases

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 13 bytes

```php
<?=$argn[-1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSep2CroGRkaWFiamFoZGZuomStYG8HlLcFS0brGsZa//8PAA)

Run with `php -nF` input is STDIN. Example:

```php
$ echo 29845812674|php -nF lost.php
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, 14 bytes

```
a=>a.slice(-1)
```

Comment: I tried my best to find a shorter way but to my surprise I don't think this can be improved, unless there is a funky way to reverse a string in under 8 bytes, before calling `[0]`. Or maybe if there is a short way to get array length. Different approach: `a=>[...a].pop()` (15bytes)

Comment: @Matsyir `a=>/.$/.exec(a)` also 15

Answer (score 4):

## Java 11+

Input from STDIN, <s>71</s> 61 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to OlivierGrégoire

```
v->{var x=System.in;x.skip(x.available()-1);return x.read();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU49a8MwEN39K26UBgs6i3Rrtk6BLqHDWZaSSxTZnM6KivFvd1XoUChveG94Xzcs2N/G@@4i5gzvSGntKInngM7DcW0agvqYaISiQa48PTO8VednoSnZrZuXIZKDLCiNyo/x0VrUSZjS5fyJfMn/g2t3hACHvfSva0GGejh9ZfEPQ8lWk@80q2raN4o4RK90/6Ite1k4QTXscVTabrvtflPTImZuexKTUu6KrIMJKi0xam27bdtx@INATx7QfwM)

Function Argument, 25 bytes

```
s->s.charAt(s.length()-1)
```

Comment: You could add [the code for program argument](https://tio.run/##TcgxDoMwEAXRq7i0C6xQU@UCaSgRxccssCQYZBZQhDj7JkWKaJqnGbEjG9unKkeh1CGQeZyrQDiYfebWTOBoS0kc@6qGO8v3KjT5eRO/fKdYVLfahwHp/vOLYi@DdVnuXHFdqormr46P1IA@) to have all three options. :) Too bad OP specifically asks for Strings, otherwise `s->s[s.length-1]` would have been enough with a `char[]` parameter-type.

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU49a8MwEN39K26UBgs6i3Rrtk6BLqHDWZaSSxTZnM6KivFvd1XoUChveG94Xzcs2N/G@@4i5gzvSGntKInngM7DcW0agvqYaISiQa48PTO8VednoSnZrZuXIZKDLCiNyo/x0VrUSZjS5fyJfMn/g2t3hACHvfSva0GGejh9ZfEPQ8lWk@80q2raN4o4RK90/6Ite1k4QTXscVTabrvtflPTImZuexKTUu6KrIMJKi0xam27bdtx@INATx7QfwM).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire just now seeing your answer 2 years later. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>9</s> 4 bytes

```hs
last
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPyexuOR/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoJSBlA@X@n/v@S0nMT04v@6yQUFAA)

Comment: Why bother with `pure`? Isn't `last` enough?

Comment: I assumed that the output must be a string too, but you're right, OP is only talking about "bytes".

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84), 10 bytes

```
sub(Ans,length(Ans),1
```

Gets the last character in the input string.
Input is in `Ans`.
Output is in `Ans` and is automatically printed out.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 8 bytes

```
tail -c1
```

Input is from stdin, output is to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), 391 bytes

```
1 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 0
1 2 1 1 0 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
1 3 1 1 0 0 0
0 3 0 1 4 0 0
1 4 1 1 0 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
1 5 1 1 0 0 0
0 5 0 1 6 0 0
1 6 1 1 0 0 0
0 6 0 1 7 0 0
1 7 1 1 0 0 0
0 7 0 1 8 0 0
1 8 1 1 0 0 0
0 8 0 0 9 0 0
0 9 0 0 a 0 0
0 a 0 0 b 0 0
0 b 0 0 c 0 0
0 c 0 0 d 0 0
0 d 0 0 e 0 0
0 e 0 0 f 0 0
0 f 0 0 h 0 0
0 h 0 0 g 0 0
0 g 0 0 0 1 1
1 g 1 0 0 1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdA9CsJAGIThPqcYewv3N/EG3sDamLgWkYAIOf66jqPwEdjhzZNiyesxblutDgc4fM72dDx/3Tk4Y99vvcwb87QgC8YCLcqisUhLsmQs0bIsG8u0XtYb62mDbDDGtziquLiouBhVXFxVXEwqLmYVFzcVF3cVF0VV8P/D7WZF92pV62lelnWP8/pcpl19Aw)

**EXPLANATION**

```
Detect eight zero bits (which will occur at the end of the input, since TMBWW uses an infinite tape of bits.)
1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 0
1 2 1 1 0 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
1 3 1 1 0 0 0
0 3 0 1 4 0 0
1 4 1 1 0 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
1 5 1 1 0 0 0
0 5 0 1 6 0 0
1 6 1 1 0 0 0
0 6 0 1 7 0 0
1 7 1 1 0 0 0
0 7 0 1 8 0 0
1 8 1 1 0 0 0
0 8 0 0 9 0 0

-------------

When eight 0 bits are detected, move back to the final byte of the input and print it out while halting the program.
0 9 0 0 a 0 0
0 a 0 0 b 0 0
0 b 0 0 c 0 0
0 c 0 0 d 0 0
0 d 0 0 e 0 0
0 e 0 0 f 0 0
0 f 0 0 h 0 0
0 h 0 0 g 0 0
0 g 0 0 0 1 1
1 g 1 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 10 bytes

Pretty much equivalent to @remoel's VBA answer:

```
=RIGHT(A1)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), 11 bytes

```
5 370394306
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05NTfn/31TB2NzA2NLE2MDs//@S1OKSzLx0AA)

The resulting Befunge-98 program `~2j@,` was <strike>stolen</strike> borrowed from *Jo King* [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181671/62313), so credit to them for that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent), 389 Bytes

Even a task as simple as this presents an interesting optimisation challenge when riding the London Underground.

```
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Central Line to Mile End
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Piccadilly Line to Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Mile End
Take Central Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFBDoJADEX3nqIH0IV6AkWjCzEsuEAdGmkY2qQzCfH0OFGDC8Gwfv@3@f@3asJyjyorZxQcSez7EhuCq1qsyQQuLARRYY/SLF4oY3OexkCyG/qB5JxkR6nG6Vn9Lb1/w4Kdw4q9f3w5YaxNOyjJWhb0AdZL2CxhO2nZuZQESu0@Vw8corGL8wUFWlAJcDKiKc3/WDN6@uk2H2aAbJjBYyif)

Visiting Mile End station allows you to take a substring from the end of the input - but to chop just 1 character, you need to generate the integer 1 somehow. Rather than doing any arithmetic, the fastest method turns out to be to parse it from the station name "Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3".

To bypass that, an alternate strategy for this challenge would be to reverse the input, read the character code for the now first byte, and then turn that back into a char to output - but this approach takes 12 bytes longer. (Although there are fewer trips needed, so the tickets would be cheaper.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), 2 bytes

```
:}
```

Pretty simple, the suffix `:}` gets the last element of an array (implicit casting)

Comment: Another alternative: ```_\```

Comment: +1 for a happy symbol

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 12 <s>15</s> bytes

```
:1+_p1-,@>~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38pQO77AUFfHwa5O@f9/I0sLE1MLQyMzcxMA)

Thanks to @Jo King for golfing off 3 bytes.

[Alternate](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v87KUFu5TDGeS0HBQUfF5v//5MS8ktSc/NKCVAA) 15 byte version that is less messy:

```
~:1+#v!_
  @,$<
```

Taking strings as input in Befunge isn't the easiest.  If there were a single command to take in multiple characters, it would be as simple as reading the string, popping/printing the top character, and exiting.

Comment: Actually, `$$` instead of `p1` should work without the warning for the same amount of bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlX///8vzs9NVShKzEvJz1XIzCsoLVEEAA)

Not the most difficult challenge in Jelly...

Note this accepts the input as a string; if the input could be interpreted otherwise (e.g. a number, a list), then it the argument will need to be quoted (e.g. "123456" or "[123,197]"). Alternatively this can be seen as a link that takes a byte array and returns the last member of that array, in accordance with PPCG standard rules.

Thanks to @MilkyWay90 and @ბიმო for pointing this out.

Comment: -1 Fails for any number (https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlX///83MTY1NjE1MQYA)

Comment: @MilkyWay90: Doesn't need to be a full program, probably this will work as a Jelly function taking a string. But then again I don't know Jelly, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'll try seeing whether or not it will work as a link

Comment: @ბიმო Seems to work (OP can you edit the answer so I can undo my downvote?)

Comment: You can just define the T as a link and make it input a string, removing the need for "" in your input.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 2 bytes

Using command line args

```
o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9/6////usUemQpuQL4iAA)

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 11 bytes

Using stdin

```
\~o;
/?(0:i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P6Yu35pL317DwCrz/3@PTAU3oKgiAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0JL//z1Sc3LyFQxMHZ0MXQE)

`θ` or `` ` `` would also work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 6 bytes

```
pA/@po
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/7/AUd@hIP//fyNLCxNTC0MjM3MTAA)

```
  p
A / @ p
  o
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICBwCkEgLyBAIHAKICBvCg==&input=Mjk4NDU4MTI2NzQ=&speed=20)

- `A` Takes all the input
- `/` Redirect around the cube
- `pp` bring bottom of the stack to the top twice
- `o/@` output as character, redirect and halt

Answer (score 3):

## [Emotion](https://github.com/Quantum64/Emotion), 5 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0//?state=JTdCJTIybW9kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmNvZGVwYWdlJTIyJTdE)

Explanation

```
 Push a copy of the first stack value.
 Push the length of the first stack value interpreted as a string.
 Push literal 1
 Push the difference of the second and first stack values.
 Push the character of the second stack value at the index of the top stack value.
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0//?state=JTdCJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJDb2RlJTIyJTNBJTIyJUYwJTlGJTk4JUI2JUYwJTlGJTkxJTg5JUYwJTlGJTk4JTgzJUYwJTlGJTk4JUE4JUYwJTlGJTkxJUJGJTIyJTJDJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJBcmd1bWVudHMlMjIlM0ElMjIyOTg0NTgxMjY3NCUyMiUyQyUyMm1vZGUlMjIlM0ElMjJpbnRlcnByZXRlciUyMiU3RA==)

Comment: in your readme, 1. i think "to emoji" should be "from emoji" 2. if it should be "from emoji" then emotinomicon and emojicode are a thing already

Comment: Actually what you're looking at is output from a compiler, which can also be accessed via the online interface.

Comment: Isn't each emoji more than one byte? I'd think they'd be two bytes at least.

Comment: Emotion uses a custom code page. See https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0//?state=JTdCJTIybW9kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmNvZGVwYWdlJTIyJTdE

Answer (score 3):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 9 bytes

```
?a|,
;.]^
```

Pretty happy with this, as it is only 3 bytes longer than [my cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193480/87923)

## Expanded

```
   ?
  ^;.
 | |a
 ] |
a ,|
```

This essentially just loops through pushing input characters into the `a` stack until EOF is reached. Then it outputs the item at the top of the `a` stack using `.a`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/3z6xRofLWi827v//xKTklNS0dAA)

Answer (score 3):

### Rust, <strike>25</strike> <strike>16</strike> 10 bytes

```
|s|s.pop()
```

[Try it on the Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%0Afn%20main()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vec!%5B%22Hello%2C%20World%22.to_string()%2C%22%3F%22.to_string()%2C%2229845812674%22.to_string()%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.iter_mut()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.map(%7Cs%7Cs.pop())%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect%3A%3A%3CVec%3COption%3Cchar%3E%3E%3E()%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%7D)

An anonymous function that takes in a mutable String and outputs the char at the end of the string. Minus a lot of bytes, thanks to madlaina

Comment: The `.unwrap()` call isn't necessary as per [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/14275#14275). Also, if you use the closure in a function that requires a specific signature, the compiler can do a better job at type deduction and you can leave the `:String` out: [example](https://tio.run/##dY27DoJAFET7/YorDfcWkkhQUXl0xM6CL0BZHgnskt0lFMK3I9iK5WTOmVG9NnMhoM1qgQRvBmC4NjiPbW9Aj9rpZIc0A9CNTYwt6NoHSYTFFRJiQ8UVX6xkSQJTo2pREuwjeHSmliJ4VZmK2Lqbac2V2WH@LHdYoHXnTSNhkKrJLacWRiIRQRhCKluOdm7TcvmrxVtw/Ad2L7539A/u6extad5Xm@YP)

Comment: @madlaina thanks, I was testing with let bindings, and I had to be explicit there.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 11 bytes

```
"$args"[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0klsSi9WCla1zD2////ILF8hfL8opwUAA)

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 16 bytes

```
INPUT S$?POP(S$)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 13 bytes

```
echo ${1: -1}
```

string is passed as argument.

[Try it online !](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BpdrQSkHXsPb///@JSckpqWnpGQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <del>11</del> <del>18</del> 34 Bytes

```
import sys;print(sys.argv[-1][-1])
```

Usage via running the program as a python script on the command line. Input is provided as the last argument to the program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxDsIwDADAPa/wCBIgIUaeghiMGmKnrRNit1Feb2A46eowKnJz57WWZqBD77Wx2OG3C7a0P87X59/R3TH1QTTpOwfMieYl9zktGC1SsI/1uBkX0SmfwogKDB0VXptZEVhRiSV9AQ)

Comment: This does not print anything or return anything from a function - snippets are not allowed, only functions or full programs.

Comment: Ah I see, didn’t think about that when I though of the answer. Only thought about running it in the interpreter.

Comment: [38](https://tio.run/##DcbBDoMgDADQO1/RoyabybLPMR66gLSohdEawtezvdMr3SjLewy@Sq4G2tWVymLTf4uaZ1lqQD/N6/O1zWNgbJ3I654cpkjHmdoRTwwWyNnXWriNs6hPD9eDAkNDhc9tlgUuVGKJPw)

Comment: [14](https://tio.run/##Dcw7DsIwDADQPaewMrUSDBUbEicBBlf5OGnqFOwqyukD7wDv6EqVbyM8XqPgvjoEucvzurzH8U2sU5istRhbJ3ISssEcaSu5bbGgV09GP9r8qamyuHwx3QskaCiwnqqVYUehxPG/zPP4AQ)

Comment: [How about this?](https://tio.run/##FcYxDsIwDADAPa/wCBIgIUaeghiMGmKnrRNit1Feb2A46eowKnJz57WWZqBD77Wx2OG3C7a0P87X59/R3TH1QTTpOwfMieYl9zktGC1SsI/1uBkX0SmfwogKDB0VXptZEVhRiSV9AQ)

Comment: that should work too

Comment: The first `-1` can just be `1`, or alternatively, the lambda is valid

Answer (score 2):

## Turing Machine Code, <s>72</s> 42 bytes

Assumes an input with no empty cells (spaces). Thanks to ASCII-only for saving 30 bytes.

```
0 * * r 1
1 * * l 2
1 _ _ l halt
2 * _ r 0
```

Old version in 72 bytes:

```
0 * * r 0
0 _ * l 1
1 * * l 2
2 * _ l 2
2 _ _ r 3
3 _ _ r 3
3 * * * halt
```

[Try it online](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?cd86957d6d815ea8c0ab0acd1aaad5f7).

Comment: `0 * * r 1/1 * * l 2/1 _ _ l halt/2 * _ r 0`?

Comment: oi pls reply :||

Comment: wouldn't work in what way? I've tested it online

Comment: @ASCII-only It turns out you're correct, and I was simply misinterpreting the way your program actually worked. I think it's different enough that you can post it as a different answer if you want to.

Comment: Well, this is a simple challenge, don't think it needs more than one answer in any language :P

Comment: @ASCII-only Okay then.

Answer (score 2):

## Twig, 37 bytes

This just uses a simple "extract 1 char from the end and print it" aproach.

```
{%macro a(a)%}{{a[-1:1]}}{%endmacro%}
```

It was really easy to do, and test, but was fun!

---

To use it, you have to put it on a `.twig` file and import it:

```
{% import 'a.twig' as a %}
{{ a.a("string") }} {# should display "g" #}
```

You can test it on https://twigfiddle.com/aa19wd (testcases included)

Comment: Ok, that's the first time I see a Twig golf.

Comment: @Ven I've been doing it for quite a while. Here's an example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174040/ and here's another one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166800/ (I have a few more, but well)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 4 bytes

```
¯1↑⎕
```

Prompt for input string and select last byte.

Comment: 3 byte solution ⊃⌽⍞

Answer (score 2):

## VBA (Excel), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

using Immediate Window and Cell `A1` as input

Thanks @tsh

`?[RIGHT(A1)]` <s>or `?Right([A1],1)`</s>

Comment: Is `1` optional?

Comment: not on the second code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 11 bytes

```
@Right(i;1)
```

Computed field formula taking its input from editable field `i`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [C# 8.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 8 bytes

*Requires .NET Core 3.0, which is in beta. This currently crashes the CLR due to a bug, but once the bug is fixed, this will run as expected and fulfill the challenge requirements.*

`s=>s[^1]`

## [C# 8.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), Runs without crashing at time of writing, 22 bytes

`s=>s.ToCharArray()[^1]`

## [C# 8.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), Full Program, 78 bytes

`using C=System.Console;class A{static void Main(){C.Write(C.ReadLine()[^1]);}}`

Comment: The challenge mentions "output", so the last solution is probably the right one

Comment: Dang, you outdid my console answer by a lot.  How does the ^1 work?

Comment: It's the new Index type. Starting an index with a caret indicates it's from the end, i.e. `array[^n]` is the same as `array[array.Length - n]`

Comment: Interesting! I always try to stay up to date with new C# features. Do you have any link / reference on that?

Comment: Found it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0

Answer (score 2):

## LiveScript, 8 bytes

```
(.[*-1])
```

Explanation:

```
(.[*-1])
(.[*-1]) # "BIOP": operator section à la Haskell
 .[   ]  # Index into the implicit argument
   *-1   # In [], "*" refers to the length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 17 bytes

```forth
: f 1- + 1 type ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRjqKmgrGCqUVBakKlgDRQoUjFJKCyB8PSUFBV07BSWgsuQiBWuuYiUFeyWFAhBtZGlhYmphaGRmbgIS@Q8A)

#### Explanation

Adds `string-length - 1` to the string address and then prints a string of length 1 starting at that address.

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f        \ start a new word definition
  1-       \ subtract 1 from string length
  +        \ add result to string address
  1 type   \ print string of length 1 starting at the new address
;          \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

### F#, <strike>14</strike> 8 bytes

```
Seq.last
```

-6 bytes thanks to [aloisdg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15214/aloisdg).

Strings are treated as sequences in F#, so you can use the `Seq.last` function to get the last character in it.

Comment: `Seq.last` is a function. You can remove the `let s=`

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
(.|¶)*
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0Ov5tA2TS0uFSA7IzUnJ5@rJCO1KBUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 31 bytes

```c
f(int*s){gets(s),printf("%s");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpNCsIwEEDhqwwFMZHWhaCbbkVXnkBcpOPkB2ISOlNQimePWbh978PBIdZqVUiyY706Elas@zK3YFW34U6P3/oyISm9ojcz8P1wPD1G21g755y2AhMBZ3BLjGGK1MMNL/Gzh2sWEE9QokECG970hKVACkhD9n/2Aw)

Comment: O_o how does this even work

Comment: I have no idea, it just works.

Comment: Impressive list of complaints from the compiler!

Answer (score 2):

### [Caboose](https://github.com/CabooseLang/Caboose), 1514 bytes

Caboose hates me, because it *does*. *There isn't any convenient string-indexing instruction in Caboose!*

```
var a=input();print(a.endsWith(' ')and' 'or a.endsWith('!')and'!'or a.endsWith('"')and'"'or a.endsWith('#')and'#'or a.endsWith('$')and'$'or a.endsWith('%')and'%'or a.endsWith('&')and'&'or a.endsWith("'")and"'"or a.endsWith('(')and'('or a.endsWith(')')and')'or a.endsWith('*')and'*'or a.endsWith('+')and'+'or a.endsWith(',')and','or a.endsWith('-')and'-'or a.endsWith('.')and'.'or a.endsWith('/')and'/'or a.endsWith('0')and'0'or a.endsWith('1')and'1'or a.endsWith('2')and'2'or a.endsWith('3')and'3'or a.endsWith('4')and'4'or a.endsWith('5')and'5'or a.endsWith('6')and'6'or a.endsWith('7')and'7'or a.endsWith('8')and'8'or a.endsWith('9')and'9'or a.endsWith(':')and':'or a.endsWith(';')and';'or a.endsWith('<')and'<'or a.endsWith('=')and'='or a.endsWith('>')and'>'or a.endsWith('?')and'?'or a.endsWith('@')and'@'or a.endsWith('A')and'A'or a.endsWith('B')and'B'or a.endsWith('C')and'C'or a.endsWith('D')and'D'or a.endsWith('E')and'E'or a.endsWith('F')and'F'or a.endsWith('G')and'G'or a.endsWith('H')and'H'or a.endsWith('I')and'I'or a.endsWith('J')and'J'or a.endsWith('K')and'K'or a.endsWith('L')and'L'or a.endsWith('M')and'M'or a.endsWith('N')and'N'or a.endsWith('O')and'O'or a.endsWith('P')and'P'or a.endsWith('Q')and'Q'or a.endsWith('R')and'R'or a.endsWith('S')and'S'or a.endsWith('T')and'T'or a.endsWith('U')and'U'or a.endsWith('V')and'V'or a.endsWith('W')and'W'or a.endsWith('X')and'X'or a.endsWith('Y')and'Y'or a.endsWith('Z')and'Z'or a.endsWith('[')and'['or a.endsWith('\\')and'\\'or a.endsWith(']')and']'or'~');
```

If I add more constants, then Caboose will say that there are too many constants in the chunk. Fortunately it passes all test cases given. Basically it (tries to) check the last character against all characters in printable ASCII.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##XczHTgIBAIThV6G6u/QuvfeqAoICh1VI5LIYQI@@Oq75L2ZOk3wzmXf77XS6HG63b/vssStH5/Pralqlz/PRuZp27ODsL6vj9cM0PIZlO3s3Tu7un3txr7oP96n7cb96AA@oB/Gg@h1@J@4zfH/uhuxN9qb@WLilHsJD6mE8rB7BI@pRPKoew2PqcTyunsAT6kk8qZ7CU@ppPK2ewTPqWTyrnsNz6vf4vXoez6sX8IJ6ES@ql/CSehkvq1fwinoVr6rX8Jp6Ha@rN/CGehNvqrfwlnobb6t38I56F@@q9/Ceeh/vqw/wgfoQH6qP8JH6GB@rT/CJ@hSfqs/wmfoD/qD@iD@qP@FP6nN8rr7AF@pLfKn@jD@rr/CV@hpfq7/gL@qv@Kv6Bt@ob7cUbkqzo9i5bvwYVul2M4xf)

Answer (score 2):

## Scratch 3.0, 7 blocks/68 bytes

[image]

*or, as scratchblocks syntax*

```
when gf clicked
ask()and wait
say(letter(length of(answer))of(answer
```

[Try it on scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/332321884)

Did I mention this was done **100%** on mobile? Because it was *really* hard making this, but I think it was worth it.

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 38 bytes

```
2a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e2x2v1f0x1x2f2v1o0x1f
```

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v             # Set variable 1 equal to 2
1x1f1r3x1v2e2x2v1f # Function 1
                   # Read a byte of input
                   # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
                   # Otherwise, store it in variable 2,
                   # then jump back to the start of the function
1x2f2v1o           # Function 2
                   # Load variable 2 into the register and output it
1f                 # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 9 bytes

Similar to the Perl solution, but `chop` doesn't return the last character in Ruby. (It instead returns the rest of the string without the last character.)

```ruby
$_=$_[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeViU@Wtcw9v9/I0sLE1MLQyMzc5N/@QUlmfl5xf91C3IA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 2 bytes

```
|;
```

Outputs top of stack.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%7C%3B&input=Hello)

Answer (score 2):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 14 bytes

```
([]{(){}{}}{})
```

#### Run example

```
$ echo -n "?" | ./flurry -bnb -c "([]{(){}{}}{})"
?
$ echo -n "Hello world" | ./flurry -bnb -c "([]{(){}{}}{})"
d
```

`-bnb` flag means "print stack as chars, print nothing for return value, and take stdin as chars".

If the challenge were asking for "the last value from an integer array", I would use return value output and write 2 byte solution `{}` (pop the stack and return it). But since character I/O is required and the only way to output a char is via the stack, I had to manually empty the stack.

#### How it works

```
(
 []     Stack height as Church numeral; Given 2 arguments `f` `x`,
          a Church numeral `n` acts as "apply `f` `n` times to `x`"
 {      Define f, with its argument pushed to the stack:
  ()      K; Given two arguments, ignore the second
  {}      Pop; the argument
  {}      Pop; pop an extra item from the stack (ignored by K)
 }      End definition of f: Return its argument unchanged,
          popping and discarding an item from the stack
 {}     Pop an item (last char)
        At this point, the stack is empty and the value is the last char
)     Push the result of the above
```

Answer (score 2):

### Notepad, <s>9</s> 5 keystrokes

Assuming the cursor is at the end of the file.

```
[LeftArrow][Ctrl-Shift-LeftArrow][Delete]
```

I know it is not a language, but I'm posting just for fun.

Comment: The input is one line, according to the challenge specs. -6 keystrokes: `[LeftArrow][Ctrl-Backspace]`

Comment: @hi. Doesn't work on my notepad. Ctrl-Backspace just adds an unprintable character, which I suspect is `\x7f`.

Comment: @hi. I don't see anything in the specs about it only being one line of input

Answer (score 2):

## [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma), 48 bytes

```
[[[],],][.[[[,.][.[,]].,][[,].[,]].]][,[,].[,.]]
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=WyJbW1tdLF0sXVsuW1tbLC5dWy5bLF1dLixdW1ssXS5bLF1dLl1dWyxbLF0uWywuXV0iLCJcImRvdGNvbW1hXCIiLDBd)

Because dotcomma is queue-based, you can't easily access the last character. My solution is to reverse the input and then output the first character of it.

**Code:**

```
                # reverse the input
[[[],],]        mark the end with 0 0
[.[             while there are characters in input
  [[,.]         put a character on the recursion stack
    [.[,]]      go to reverse section
  .,]           save the character in the reverse section
  [[,].[,]]     go to input section
.]]

[               # get first character and delete all others
  ,[,]          delete 0 and append the next character (last of input) to the end of the queue
  .[,.]         delete everything until we reach a 0
]
                implicitly output the queue
```

## [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma) (experimental), 17 bytes

```
[,][[],][.[,.]].,
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=WyJbLF1bW10sXVsuWywuXV0uLCIsIltcImRvdGNvbW1hXCJdIiwyXQ)

I marked this "experimental" because the language dotcomma is still very young and I don't know if this is intentional behaviour. If you pass input as a list of strings it reverses each string, so you only need to extract the first letter.

```
[,]      put first character on recursion stack
[[],]    put 0 (end of queue marker) on queue
[.[,.]]  delete everything from queue
.,       write back character
```

Comment: Wasn't even sure this was possible! Would you be fine with me copying your code snippet to a github page so I can make a try it online link generator?

Comment: I think, the language has everything it needs to be Turing complete. You can build loops, you can implement if- else statements (even easier than in other esolangs), you can calculate numbers, you can read and write data and I/O. Most things will be hard to program, but it should be able to do anything. Of course you can copy my code snippet. I'd be happy to help you gain more attention for your languages.

Comment: PS: There are different versions of that snippet in my answers, depending on what type of input and output it uses. I didn't yet manage to auto- detect the input type.

Comment: I finished my [online interpreter](https://redwolfprograms.github.io/dotcomma/). Also sorry it took so long, I had a lot of other projects :p

Comment: Nice. There are some minor bugs but I updated my answer using your online interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

## vim, 6 bytes

```
VGJ$d^
```

### Annotated

```
VGJ     # join all lines
$       # move cursor to (before) last character
d^      # delete to beginning
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P8zdSyUl7v9/I0sLE1MLQyMzcxMkJpepsREYcRWnpAFRIhCnAAA)

Comment: `v}hd` is 2 bytes smaller.

Comment: @Razetime But it fails if the last line of input only has one character: there's nowhere for the `h` to go, so the last character gets included in the delete range.

Comment: ah, interesting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 4 bytes

```julia
last
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PyexuOR/QVFmXklOngaIo6Fkr6SpyYUqZGRpYWJqYWhkZm4ClPwPAA)

Comment: Damn! Of course this counts :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
#~StringTake~-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7kuuKQoMy89JDE7tU7XUO1/AJBXouCQFq2UkZqTk69Qnl@Uk6IU@/8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 81 bytes, command-line input

```cs
class M{static void Main(string[] a){System.Console.Write(a[0][a[0].Length-1]);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcQxCoAwDADAr3TUwaKCk6OrTg4OpUOoQQPaQhMEEd8e8YYLXIWUUTUcwGymhwWEgrkSrWYCigVLprg5b6B85psFTzukyOlAu2QSLMDV3v3ZEeMme9X4sn9fVW27Dw)

If you run this from an actual command line, you will need to wrap your string in quotes if it contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 115 bytes, console input

```cs
using C=System.Console;class M{static void Main(string[] a){int c=0,d;while((d=C.Read())>-1)c=d;C.Write((char)c);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCsIwEADQvV9xYwK26CAOIS6Zu@jgIA7xLtqDmkAuVUrpt8fOj4fSYsqh1kk4vsHZ6ywlfDqXoqQxGBy9CPSLFF8Y4ZuYoPcclZS8hfsDvF44FkC735H5DTwGpci67hI8Ka3P7UGjJeO6W@ayGQ4@a9RmXWuVcDrSDBMJzAQlv5tGnmF48RTrHw)

This feels kinda janky, but it does work.  Interestingly, I can't save any bytes with a for loop as the code stands.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 11 bytes

```perl6
*.comb[*-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0svOT83KVpL1zD2vzVXcWKlgh5QIi2/SEGpJLW4RElHQcnQyNjE1MzcwlJJR8nI0sLE1MLQyMzcROk/AA)

Anonymous Whatever lambda that takes a string, splits it into characters, and returns the last one.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 24 bytes

```
@set s=%1
@echo %s:~-1%
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. Note that arguments can't include special characters or spaces, but you can fake arguments with spaces in this case by preceding it with a `"`, which results in a single argument that begins with `"`, however there is no easy solution for arguments that include special characters. Batch can't easily read "all of stdin". To read up to but not including the first newline itself would however be a byte shorter:

```
@set/ps=
@echo %s:~-1%
```

Edit: A version that handles arbitrary characters in a (quoted) argument for 92 bytes:

```
@set s="%~1"
@set "s=%s:~-2,1%
@if "%s%"=="" (echo ^")else for %%s in ("%s%")do @echo %%~s
```

Explanation: The first line makes a copy of the argument in a variable and ensures that it is quoted. The second argument then takes the second last character (because the quote is now the last character). However, if that was also a quote then this results in an empty variable, so we need to special-case that and output a (quoted) quote. Otherwise, we still need to quote the character in case it is a special character as echoing `"%s%"` will echo the quotes and echoing `%s%` will actually interpret special characters, so the variable needs to be quoted to allow it to be parsed but then immediately unquoted so it can be printed. This is achieved using the `for` command. 86 bytes to read up to but not including the first newline from stdin while supporting special characters:

```
@set/ps=
@set "s=%s:~-1%
@if "%s%"=="" (echo ^")else for %%s in ("%s%")do @echo %%~s
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 11 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Last()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrpOckVhkp5CmYPu/wtauQs8nsbhEQ/O/NVd4UWZJqkaahpKRpYWJqYWhkZm5iZKmpvV/AA)

Comment: you can use a function :P

Comment: OK - Ill update my answer :)

Comment: uhm why is testcase in STDIN not footer

Comment: Wow - It's been a while. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Comment: @Ven - This is an anonymous function that takes a `string` as input and returns a `char`. The OP mentions that functions are valid submissions.

Comment: Challenge also says "is non-empty."

Comment: @Ven - It says the input is non-empty. My function should work if at least 1 character is specified (i.e. non-empty). Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: That's not how I understand it. I understand that it should print the last non-empty character. We need to ask OP.

Answer (score 1):

## Scratch 3.0, scratchblocks3 syntax

### As a function, 61 bytes

```
define l
ask[]and wait
say(letter(length of(answer))of(answer
```

### As a full program, 68 bytes

```
when gf clicked
ask[]and wait
say(letter(length of(answer))of(answer
```

[Try both online](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/294694737/editor/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 5 bytes

```
~2j@,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v84oy0Hn//@S1OKSzLx0AA)

#### Explanation:

```
~           Take input
 2j         Skip next two instructions
~           Repeat until EOF, where it reflects
   @,       Print the last character and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 byte

```
Ì
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DP//9KRpYWJqYWhkZm5iZKAA)

-1 byte thanks to Quintec!

Comment: [1 byte](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DP//9KRpYWJqYWhkZm5iZKAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 54 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][S N
N
_Discard_top][T N
S S _Print_as_character]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace can only take input as integer or character, we must add a trailing character to indicate we're done with the input-string after reading it character by character, for which I've used a newline.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBAYiAmEuBk4tTgZOTE8xXADIVgHywoAIXUJoLqoyLE8j4/9/I0sLE1MLQyMzchAsA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Example run: [`input = A2#`](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBAYiAmEuBk4tTgZOTE8xXADIVgHywoAIXUJoLqoyLE8j4/9/RSJkLAA)**

```
Command    Explanation                   Stack                Heap    STDIN STDOUT STDERR

NSSN       Create Label_LOOP             []
 SSSN      Push 0                        [0]
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)             [0,0]
 TNTS      Read STDIN as character       [0]                  {0:65}  A
 TTT       Retrieve at heap address (0)  [65]                 {0:65}
 SNS       Duplicate top (65)            [65,65]              {0:65}
 SSSTSTSN  Push 10                       [65,65,10]           {0:65}
 TSST      Subtract top two (65-10)      [65,55]              {0:65}
 NTSSN     If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT     [65]                 {0:65}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP            [65]                 {0:65}
 
 SSSN      Push 0                        [65,0]
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)             [65,0,0]
 TNTS      Read STDIN as character       [65,0]               {0:50}  2
 TTT       Retrieve at heap address (0)  [65,50]              {0:50}
 SNS       Duplicate top (50)            [65,50,50]           {0:50}
 SSSTSTSN  Push 10                       [65,50,50,10]        {0:50}
 TSST      Subtract top two (50-10)      [65,50,40]           {0:50}
 NTSSN     If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT     [65,50]              {0:50}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP            [65,50]              {0:50}

 SSSN      Push 0                        [65,50,0]
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)             [65,50,0,0]
 TNTS      Read STDIN as character       [65,50,0]            {0:35}  #
 TTT       Retrieve at heap address (0)  [65,50,35]           {0:35}
 SNS       Duplicate top (35)            [65,50,35,35]        {0:35}
 SSSTSTSN  Push 10                       [65,50,35,35,10]     {0:35}
 TSST      Subtract top two (35-10)      [65,50,35,25]        {0:35}
 NTSSN     If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT     [65,50,35]           {0:35}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP            [65,50,35]           {0:35}

 SSSN      Push 0                        [65,50,35,0]
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)             [65,50,35,0,0]
 TNTS      Read STDIN as character       [65,50,35,0]         {0:10}  \n
 TTT       Retrieve at heap address (0)  [65,50,35,10]        {0:10}
 SNS       Duplicate top (10)            [65,50,35,10,10]     {0:10}
 SSSTSTSN  Push 10                       [65,50,35,10,10,10]  {0:10}
 TSST      Subtract top two (10-10)      [65,50,35,10,0]      {0:10}
 NTSSN     If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT     [65,50,35,10]        {0:10}

NSSSN      Create Label_PRINT            [65,50,35,10]        {0:10}
 SNN       Discard top                   [65,50,35]           {0:10}
 TNSS      Print as character to STDOUT  [65,50]              {0:10}        #
                                                              {0:10}               error
```

Stops with the error: Exit not defined.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-h`, 1 byte

```
U
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=VQ==&input=IjI5ODQ1ODEyNjc0IgoKLWg=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 5 bytes

```
i1Z%@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TMErV4f9/j9ScnPwYhfD8opwURQA)

Note that input handling in Runic has implicit conversion and breaks on spaces. `\` denotes a literal space (works on newlines too) and numerical values are never strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Binary-Encoded [Golfical](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Golfical), 17 bytes

Hex-dump of binary encoded file:

```
00 60 02 1b 1a 08 01 14
16 14 24 1d 0a 01 14 18
14
```

Original image:

[image]

Magnified 45x with colors labeled:

[image]

The original image (the tiny one, not the magnified version) can be run using the interpreter normally. The binary encoded file (of which a hexdump is included above) can either be transpiled back to the image version with the Encoder program included in the github repo, or run directly using the interpreter by adding the `-x` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip) `-z`, 41 bytes

```
S
>vvvvvv~t
ABCDEFG
|Zz||Zz
zbcZzfg
a  de
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/P5jLrgwM6kq4HJ2cXVzd3LlqoqpqgJirKik5qiotnStRQSEl9f9/A0MjYxNTM3MLy8Sk5JTUtP@6VQA)

Assumes that either the byte string does not contain zero (`\0`), or that it designates the end of the string.

---

Alternate solution (45 bytes):

```
azABZbczCDZdezEFZfgzG
S-^^----^^----^^----^~t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/P7HK0SkqKbnK2SUqJbXK1S0qLb3KnStYNy5OFwhQyLqS//8NDI2MTUzNzC0sE5OSU1LT/utWAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

Takes the input, splits it in to a list, outputs the last element of the list.

```r
tail(strsplit(scan(,''),'')[[1]],1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyQxM0ejuKSouCAns0SjODkxT0NHXV0ThKOjDWNjdQw1/yt5pObk5CuE5xflpCgq/QcA)

Comment: [Simple trick to save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyQxM0cjNUejuKSouCAns0SjODkxT0NHXV0ThDV1DDX/K3mk5uTkK4TnF@WkKCr9BwA)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0qbikKDMvXaPYRrc4OTFPQ0dJSVMnLzkjsUijWFPzv5JHak5OvkJ4flFOiqLSfwA "R – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-h`, 1 byte

Can handle input as a string, integer or character/digit array.

```
s
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cw==&input=MTIzCi1o)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```c
x(char*v){printf(v+strlen(v)-1);}
```

Really simple stuff here. Nothing to ungolf either.

Saved one byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)
Fixed the answer and saved another byte thanks to [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 4 bytes

```
last
```

Functions are allowed, right?

Also with IO (18 bytes):

```
main=interact$last
```

Comment: The same answer was [already posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181637/56433), though we do allow duplicate answers as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 13 bytes

```
REEeREEEeReEe
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#T!pL) Disable "Separated by" check box below the input text box.

**Explanation:**

```
REEe  # Input as string (stack R)
REEEe # Goto last char (stack R)
ReEe  # Output char (stack R)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

This is the exact thing that Keg was built for.

```
,
```

Explanation

```
# Push implicit string input
,# Output the last pushed character
# There is no implicit output since something was outputted
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f5/9/I0sLE1MLQyMzcxMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 10 bytes

```
(#~p../)?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCsIwEIfxvU/xBwcVNO4iuLh07hNc22tz9JKG5oq4@OoxTj/4hs82oTjvSlspp8M3OXc7Px@ldGtgk8D5ghYqC8PWKkMiCD2Zt73HJKo84i3mkRPNns0EmfaBXdO0WJgTwiezTog8LNfxH@pCDBRHpI2Nq@bJ0B5DXQcm60nV4f76AQ)

Pretty straight-forward; reads characters until it gets a null read, then prints the top of the stack.

Ungolfed:

```
   ( 
  # ~ 
 p . . 
/ ) ? <
--------------------------------------------
(            Set a point to jump back to
 ~.<         Read a character, change directions ("." is a no-op)
    ?)/      If ToS <= 0, skip next instruction and change directions; otherwise, jump back to "("
       p#    Pop the top value from the stack (the null input), then pop again and print that value
```

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore 8-bit BASIC (CBM/PET, VIC-20, C64/TheC64Mini, C128, C16/+4) - byte count later

```
 0inputa$:iflen(a$)thenprintright$(a$,1)
```

#### Simplified (without the sanity check):

```
 0inputa$:?right$(a$,1)
```

There is a small limitation in that Commodore 8-bit BASIC the maximum length of a string is 255 characters, so any entry above that will cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)`-cr`, (6 bytes code + 3 bytes command line) = 9 bytes

```
({}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O61sZO8/9/3eQiEAYA)

Code:

The command line argument "-cr" means "use ASCII input and output" and "reverse the stack", so when you pop a value, the last byte of the input is popped, and when you push a value, it is pushed to the end.

```
 {}     pop a character
(    )  and push it
   <>   on the other stack
        implicitly output the current stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 18 bytes

```
>,
"+
)[
!<(-
#==.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL///fTodLSZtLM5pL0UZDl0vZ1lbv/39fkLSPo587AA)

code:

```
>    go right
,    read input
+    increment it (because EOF = -1)
[    ignore the next command, if current cell = 0
<    go to the left
!    stop moving (Mario is now standing on the elevator (#), 
     which rides up to the elevator end (")
)    go to the next memory cell
     Mario is now at the starting position (>) and runs another round 
     until the end of input

else (if he ignored the "<" instruction)
(    go one memory cell back (to the last inputted byte)
-    decrement it, so it becomes the original value again
.    print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org), <s>32 bytes</s> 24 bytes

```
(print(last(read-line)))
```

```
(print             ;; prints output
  (last            ;; get last character of input
    (read-line)))  ;; read input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X6OgKDOvRCMnsbhEoyg1MUU3JzMvVVNT8/9/I0sLE1MLQyMzcxMA)

Comment: You could shave off 3 bytes by removing all whitespace. It also seems like you don't need the `str`, but my Clojure is extremely rusty so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I don't know that I can use without whitespace at all. Thanks for that. 

I think `str` is not needed at all, but it will return char (`\?`) instead of string (`"?"`) (if that's okay)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 3 bytes

The GolfScript `=` yields a decimal. That's pretty weird ... However, (luckily enough,) GolfScript supports slicing over a string, which allows me to slice the last item of the string.

```
-1>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X9fQ7v9/I0sLE1MLQyMzcxMA)

## Explanation

```
-1  # The last item
  > # Choose everything in the string
    # after the last item, including the last item
    # this (obviously) yields the last item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
⊢/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXIv3/aY/aJjzq7XvUN9XT/1FX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCemJSsjoXkPZIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVQHAA)

The code taken literally means to "reduce by right argument function". It works like the following (basically like `foldr1 (flip const)` in Haskell):

```apl
  ⊢/ 'abcd'
→ 'a' ⊢ 'b' ⊢ 'c' ⊢ 'd'
→ 'a' ⊢ 'b' ⊢ 'd'
→ 'a' ⊢ 'd'
→ 'd'
```

This is an [idiom](https://aplcart.info/?q=%E2%8A%A2%2F#) for taking last element from a vector (or taking last element from each row of a multi-dimensional array).

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 3 bytes

Though there was already a Golfscript 3 byte solution, I figured I'd throw in the more general-purpose one.

```
)\;
```

Where ( is the front-uncon function (Golfscript treats strings as char arrays), \ swaps the string and char positions, and ; deletes the string, leaving only the last char.

Comment: Sure is not `)` what you intended to use? At least with the interpreter available on tio.run this outputs the first byte, not the last.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - thank you, accidentally copy/pasted from the wrong solution file :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 2 bytes

```
[~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f8/uu7/f4/UnJx8hfD8opwURQA)

If it needs to be pretty formatted `[~Q`

```
[~ # Last char
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), 2 Bytes

```
Vn
```

[Try it!](https://nph278.github.io/integral/?code=Vm4&input=%22%3F%22%0A%0A%2229845812674%22)

### Explanation

```
V  Reverse the input
 n Head
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
a@-1
```

`@RVa` also works, and is the same size.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0UHX8P///4YKRgrGCiYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md), 13 bytes

```
@0
00
]]..
@0
```

Marbelous is a language based on marble machines

- `@n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) is a portal which teleport the marble to another portal with the same value
- `00`-`FF` initiate a marble with this value
- `]]` passing marble take value of next input byte if there is one, else the marble is diverted to the right
- `..` is a noop
- marbles going out of the board to the bottom are implicitly outputed

[interpretor](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py)

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 8 bytes

```
,);.@
"(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fR9Naz4FLSeP/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA)

```
,)("  Loop until EOF (-1): push a char input, increment, then decrement
;.@   On EOF, discard top, print the last char, and halt
```

Comment: [Same bytecount](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQYdLSclaz@H/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA), but a little simpler. I don't think a T intersection can be made any smaller

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte

```
e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P/X/fyWP1JycfIXw/KKcFEUlAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Regex, 2 bytes

```
.$
```

Matches character then end of string.

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 7 bytes

`g(i -1)`

About as simple as possible, just gets the last character of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$1\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 0.823 bytes

```
]
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJdIiwiYWJjZGVmIl0=)

1-byters?? Seriously?? Why have that when you can have 0.823 bytes?? Literally "grab last char of (implicit) input."

Comment: Hey that ain't fair :(

Answer (score 1):

## nroff, 57 bytes

```
.de F
.ds X \\$1
.length L \\*X
.substring X \\nL
\\*X
..
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GavKL8tDQbG3VXPxf1paUlaboWNy31UlIV3Lj0UooVIhRiYlQMufRyUvPSSzIUfIBcrQguveLSpOKSosy8dLCCPB8uiLAe1AATPTcFJRNDYwsjI2NLJS4QLxVClWcklkBYCokKEEaSQrISF9B2iN4FCyA0AA)

### Usage

```
.F "41382239"
.F "e"
.F "what"
.F " a "
.F "b c"
```

### How it works

```
.de F             \" define macro F
.ds X \\$1        \" store 1st argument to string variable X
                  \" I had to do so because arguments are not in variable, but
                  \" can be obtained via requests only
.length L \\*X    \" store length of X to register L
                  \" no numerical express to do so
.substring X \\nL \" 1-indexed. replace X with L-th to last substring
\\*X              \" content of X
..                \" end of definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## AArch64 machine code, 12 bytes

```
20 8c c0 28 e3 ff ff 35 c0 03 5f d6
```

Commented assembly

```c
    .globl lastchar
    // Input: x1: null terminated UTF-32 string
    // Output: w0: last char in string
    // char32_t lastchar(int dummy, const char32_t *str);
lastchar:
.Lloop:
    // load two chars, advance by one char
    // w0 = *x1++; w3 = *x1;
    ldp     w0, w3, [x1], #4
    // loop if w3 was not zero (null terminator)
    cbnz    w3, .Lloop
    // return
    // result is in w0
    ret
```

This can be called from C using a dummy parameter to put the null terminated UTF-32 string in `x1`.

```c
char32_t lastchar(int dummy /* x0 */, const char32_t *ptr /* x1 */);
```

I don't usually do AArch64 because it isn't very compact at 4 bytes per instruction and almost always longer than Thumb, but this particular solution is really elegant even if it is larger than the equivalent Thumb code by 2 bytes (it's solely because of the return instruction being 2 bytes) (Thumb does better with ptr+length though)

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb machine code, 6 bytes

```
01 39 40 5c 70 47
```

Commented assembly:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .globl lastchar
    .thumb_func
    // C-callable function
    // Input:
    //  - r0: String of ASCII (not utf-32)
    //  - r1: Length of string
    // Output:
    //  - r0: Char
    // int lastchar(const char *ptr, uint32_t length);
lastchar:
    // It's literally ptr[length - 1]
    // Subtract 1 from the length since ARM can't do [reg, reg, offset]
    subs    r1, #1
    // load ptr[length]
    ldrb    r0, [r0, r1]
    // return in r0
    bx      lr
```

I mean it is literally `return ptr[length - 1]`, there isn't much to explain. The function is callable using the C convention, using **byte string + length** (not null-terminated UTF-32 like most of my solutions):

```c
int lastchar(const char *ptr, uint32_t length);
```

---

## ARM Thumb machine code, 10 bytes

This is the "equivalent Thumb code" I mentioned on my [aarch64 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253882/94093). It is much less elegant.

```
01 c9 0b 68 00 2b fb d1 70 47
```

Commented assembly:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .globl lastchar
    .thumb_func
    // C-callable function
    // Input:
    //  - r1: Null terminated UTF-32LE string
    // Output:
    //  - r0: Char
    // char32_t lastchar(int dummy, const char32_t *str);
lastchar:
.Lloop:
    // load 1 char, advance pointer 
    ldmia   r1!, {r0}
    // Load next char into temp
    ldr     r3, [r1]
    // compare and loop if r3 wasn't a null terminator
    cmp     r3, #0
    bne     .Lloop
    // return in r0
    bx      lr
```

This uses the same function signature, taking a null terminated UTF-32 string and a dummy parameter to put `str` in `r1`:

```c
char32_t lastchar(int dummy /* r0 */, const char32_t *str /* r1 */);
```

In an ideal world, the direct equivalent could be done:

```c
lastchar:
.Lloop:
    ldrd    r0, r3, [r1], #4
    cbnz    r3, .Lloop
    bx      lr
```

But unfortunately:

- `ldrd` will bus error if the pointer is not 8 byte aligned (even with unaligned access support), and advancing the pointer by 4 will end up unaligned.
- `ldmia` always advanced by `4 * NumRegisters`
- `cbnz` can only branch forwards

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 16 bytes

This is a pretty basic answer, but I think that it is the lowest Python 3 can go...

```
x=lambda a:a[-1]
```

[TIO](http://x=lambda%20a:a[-1]%22TIO%22)

Comment: you don't need the `x=` here

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 23 bytes

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(v,1)FROM i
```

Didn't see a SQL solution yet.

Input is via a pre-existing table \$i\$ with `varchar` field \$v\$, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 7 bytes

```perl
$_=chop
```

This must be executed using the `-pe` flags.

### Example

```perl
$ echo -n "abcd" | perl -pe '$_=chop'
d
```

### Explanation

The `-p` flag wraps code inside a block that appears as:
`while (<>) { ... ; print }` whereas the '...' would include the code provided. The entire script would expand to:

```perl
while (<>) { $_ = chop ; print }
```

What I did here was set the context variable `$_` to the return value of chop, which returns the last character of a string. Shortly after, `print` with no statements on its own will display the previously assigned context variable.

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh, 11 bytes

[try it online!!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpdrQSkHXsPb///@JSckpqWkK6RmZWdk5uXn5BQqFxUUlpWXlFZVVClb5AQA)

```zsh
<<<${1: -1}
```

clone of the `bash` answer, 2 bytes shorter

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 1 byte

```
'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/1/9////SiGpxSUKxSVFmXnpSgA)

Print the top of stack as a character!

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 6 bytes

```scala
_.last
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM1VlpijkGalEFxSlJmXrmBrp@CckVikYPs/Xi8nsbjkfwFQuCQnTyNNQyktPz8psUhJU5MLSdDQslQhr6gATTQpJzEDJFT7HwA)

Not much to say here - it's just a function that takes a string (or really any iterable) and outputs its last element.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
┤Þ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlCWH5/3/r1SSWlyixKVkD8RGlhYmphaGRmbmJkoA)

Or alternatively:

```
b§
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/p0PL//5VKUotLlLiU7IHYyNLCxNTC0MjM3EQJAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
┤   # Pop the left character of the (implicit) input-string loose to the stack
 Þ  # Only leave the top item of the stack, and discard everything else
    # (implicitly output the entire stack joined together)

b   # Push -1
 §  # Get the -1'th character of the (implicit) input-string
    # (0-based modulair similar as Python, so will index into the last character)
    # (implicitly output the entire stack joined together)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 30 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
say S at S-1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Or 51 bytes if we need to be able to handle newlines in the input:

```
listen to S
while S
listen to S

cut S
say S at S-1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3I7//wE)

```
   # (implicit) push STDIN to stack
θ  # push last character of top of stack
   # (implicit) output top of stack to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CSASM v2.2.1.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.2.1.1), 46 bytes

```
func main:
in ""
push ^1
push ^0
substr
print
ret
end
```

**Commented:**

```
func main:
    ; Get the input
    in ""
    ; Get a substring of the input from (length - 1) to (length - 0)
    push ^1
    push ^0
    substr
    ; Print it
    print
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 3 bytes

```
t`F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP8lCW7/gUb/N7K0MDG1MDQyMzcBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

```
{:
```

`{:` is implicit verb for last element of any array (including strings)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q63@a3JxpSZn5CukKagXpWUVpJYXZaUVFBapw0UNjYxNDY0NzQxNTdT/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 11 bytes

```
[ 1 tail* ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqsUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeikJ1alJeao2DNxaVkr8SlZGRpYWJqYWhkZm6i9D9awVChJDEzR0sh9n9SpoNCtIKeQqwCkPUfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), 36 bytes

```
define(f,`substr($1,decr(len($1)))')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GqXBMFGxt1V3839aWlJWm6FjdVUlLTMvNSNdJ0EopLk4pLijRUDHVSUpOLNHJS84BsTU1NdU2I2t1pGgn26ppcQMrI0sLE1MLQyMzcBCgANA6iYsECCA0A)

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 11 bytes

```
,>+[-,>+]<.
```

Explained:

```
,> [ ,> ]   get input
  + -  +    sentinels
         <. output last non-NUL byte (NUL doesn't count, doesn't it?)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 2 bytes

```
|;
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0?code=%7C%3B&input=29845812674)

Explanation:

```
|      take whole input onto stack as ASCII value
 ;     output top of stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 38 bytes

```go
func(s []byte)byte{return s[len(s)-1]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BTcWCxOTsxPRUhdzEzDyuzNyC_KISBaW03BIlrrLEIoU0BdulpSVpuhY31dJK85I1ihWiY5MqS1I1QUR1UWpJaVGeQnF0TmqeRrGmrmFsLVS1L0g12EwNTYVqLk6ggXoBRZl5JTl5GkpGlhYmphaGRmbmJko6CsUlQPF0jTQNiMmo0ppAwAU1dMECCA0A)

Answer (score 0):

## Standard ML, 8 bytes

There are two common ways of string processing: char lists and strings. In both cases, the underlying char is an 8 bit value using "extended ASCII".

For char lists:

```
hd o rev
```

I'm not sure why `List.last` isn't top-level, but that works too.

For strings, convert to List and use `explode`:

```
hd o rev o explode
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJB4biLIiwiIiwidCIsIiIsIjVcbjUxNDEiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 10 bytes

Assumes every byte is a letter one of `0` through `9`.
Is this justified?

```
s=>s%10+""
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuharim3tilUNDbSVlCACNwOtubiS8_OKSxRKUotLnBOLU4tto7kUFJSMLE0sjQyVdEBsEyWuWGsuuAK9tPwi18TkDA2gaSC9-Tmpejn56RppGsWampoQgxcsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 0 bytes

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UolS7IKlpSVpuhYLlhQnJRfDOGs9UnNy8nUUwvOLclIUIYIA)

That's right: no bytes. The `t` flag does all the work.

Or **1 byte** flagless:

```
t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWC0uWFCclF0N5C9Z6pObk5OsohOcX5aQoQgQB)

Built-in for last item.