# BF Last binary digit

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck

#### Task

Your task is to write as short as possible program preferably in Brainf**k which determines the last digit of given number after it's conversion from decimal to binary system.

#### Input

An integer in decimal system consisting of up to 200 digits. There is a newline character (ASCII 10) after the given number

#### Output

One digit (1 or 0) which is the last digit of given number after it's conversion to binary system.

#### Example

`4372667135165131576213 -> 1`

Comment: Are you looking for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113513/17602 ?

Comment: Output has to be last digit of given number after its conversion to binary

Comment: ...Which is the parity of the number (i.e. whether it is odd or even)

Comment: A bf answer from the parity question is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113512/86147). It should work for decimal-encoded strings too, since the last bit will be 1 iff the number is odd.

Comment: Since you wanted a brainfuck answer on your [last question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181632/76162) I'd suspect that these are homework questions... except that this is brainfuck lol

Comment: `+[>,+]<<<,+>[[>]+<[-<]>]++++++[->++++++++<]>.` since you like EOF as `-1`

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
Boole@OddQ@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yk/PyfVwT8lJdBBWe1/QFFmXomCg0JatImxuZGZmbmhsamhmamhsaGpuZmRoXHsfwA)