# Is it double speak?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

In an [earlier challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188988/ddoouubbllee-ssppeeaakk) I asked code golfers to produce strings which copy each character in a string. For example:

```
TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!
```

This challenge is simply to detect if some text meets the definition of a double speak string.

- There is an even number of characters.
- When split into pairs, every pair consists of two of the same character.

---

The challenge

- It's code golf, do it in few bytes.
- Use any language you choose.
- Please include a link to an online interpreter.
- The code will accept some text.
- For simplicity, the input will only consist of *printable ASCII characters*
- It will return an indication of whether or not the input is double speak. It could be:
- A boolean
- Strings ('true', 'false', 'yes', 'no' etc)
- Integers 0 or 1

---

Test Cases:

```
input -> output
aba -> false
aab -> false
abba -> false
aabb -> true
aaabb -> false
tthhiiss -> true
ttthhhiiisss -> false
```

Comment: Can the Booleans or integers be (consistently) reversed? 1 for non-double speak, 0 for double speak

Comment: @LuisMendo Unusual, but sounds okay to me.

Comment: May we error on inputs of length < 2?

Comment: Suggested test case: `abba` which should be falsey

Comment: Suggested test case: `aabbbb` which should be truthy

Comment: I guess correct spelling is not an issue, so something like "lleetteerr" would be considered truthy, right? Even though this could come from a program that says "double all characters except 't'".

Comment: @Corak that’s correct. We’re not interested in the validity of words, just whether the characters all repeat.

Comment: Can I use exit code (0/1) to output? Standard I/O rules allow that.

Comment: @val Well, I'm not going to argue with standard I/O

Comment: Suggested test case: `0` which should be falsey.

Comment: What about the empty string?

Comment: Suggested test case: `"aab"` caught me up, since I didn't check that the input was of even length, only that the pairs were equal

Answer (score 64):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda s:s[::2]==s[1::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqjjaysoo1ta2ONoQxPhfUJSZV6KRpqEUEpKRkZlZXKygACFTUvLzS0uTknJyUlMVFIqLCwpSUxMTs7MVFZU0NbkQ2jIyixUyi/PUS4DC/wE)

Answer (score 29):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 20 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Jo King.*

```
+>,[>,[-<->]<[<],]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f204nGoh0bXTtYm2ibWJ1Ym30/v8PCcnIyMwsLlZQgJApKfn5paVJSTk5qakKCsXFBQWpqYmJ2dmKigA)

[Readable output!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f204nGoh0bXTtYm2ibWJ1YnWjdUHARhsoAKT1/v8PCcnIyMwsLlZQgJApKfn5paVJSTk5qakKCsXFBQWpqYmJ2dmKigA)

Takes input two characters at a time, and moves away from the 1 on the tape if any pair doesn't match.  EOF is treated as 0 and thus handled automatically.

Output is a null byte if the string is not double speak, and 0x01 if it is.  The readable version outputs these as characters at a cost of 14 bytes.

Answer (score 18):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
Heda
```

Input is a string, enclosed with single qoutes. Output is `0` for double speak, `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yM1JfH/f/WQkIyMzMziYgUFCJmSkp9fWpqUlJOTmqqgUFxcUJCampiYna2oqA4A)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!'` as an example.

```
H    % Push 2
     % STACK: 2
     % Implicit input (triggered because the next function requires two inputs): string 
     % STACK: 'TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!', 2
e    % Reshape as a 2-column matrix of chars, in column-major order. Pads with char(0)
     % if needed. Note that char(0) cannot be present in the input
     % STACK: ['This is double speak!';
               'This is double speak!']
d    % Difference of each column
     % STACK: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
a    % Any: gives 0 if and only if all elements are 0
     % STACK: 0
     % Implicit display
```

Comment: Um... who is "Heda"? :D

Comment: "Heda" is German for "Hey! You!"

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ιË
```

Input as a list of characters.

-3 bytes by porting [@Shaggy's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189372/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M7D3f//RyuFKOmAcQYUZ0JxMRQrQDEu8RQozofiUihOguIcKE6FYpg@mDkFUAyTT4TibChWBONYAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn1l8P9zOw93/9f5HxKSkZGZWVysoAAhU1Ly80tLk5JyclJTFRSKiwsKUlMTE7OzFRW5iFbKRYKZqcUlXD45@fnl5ampRUXJyYmJxcWpqVzOzvn5RUWpqcnJJSUKClZWmppcJUCQmlpcXFKiCNSYCAcA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ι   # Uninterleave the (implicit) input-list of characters
    #  i.e. ["t","t","t","t","e","e","s","s","t","t","!","!","!"]
    #   → [["t","t","e","s","t","!","!"],["t","t","e","s","t","!"]]
 Ë  # Check if both inner lists are equal
    #  → 0 (falsey)
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
ó r¶
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8yBytg&input=IlRUaGhpaXNzICBpaXNzICBkZG9vdXViYmxsZWUgIHNzcHBlZWFha2shISI)

```
ó r¶     :Implicit input of string
ó        :Uniterleave
  r      :Reduce by
   ¶     :  Testing equality
```

### Alternative

```
ó
¥o
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8wqlbw&input=IlRUaGhpaXNzICBpaXNzICBkZG9vdXViYmxsZWUgIHNzcHBlZWFha2shISI)

Answer (score 11):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
■◄┼$Δ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=fe11c524ff&i=TThhiiss++iiss++ddoouubbllee++ssppeeaakk%21%21%0Aaaaa%0Aaaa%0AThis+is+just+regular+speak.%0Aaabbc&a=1&m=2)

**Procedure:**

- Calculate run-lengths.
- Get GCD of array.
- Is even?

Comment: Ahh, you got one that packs. Nice.

Comment: i like this algorithm!

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes

```
(.)\1

^$
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lYyxCsJAEAX7/Yo9UMg1Qtq0KWwsU4q4uTzIkcMLtxvy@WdAsNYpXjVvCiy@pK3n5vqszcXfW6LHqdZhmOcYVZk/O005b9s4pgQwq64rILIsztHPKv3RhBrdUs77DpQSgogqQH2fcylACGbMXec92QGgauaOo3x5Aw)

**Explanation:**

Remove all pair of the same characters:

```
(.)\1
```

Check if there are no characters left:

```
^$
```

Comment: You can provide a more traditional output by using `^$` as your final stage.

Comment: @Neil Ah of course, thanks! That indeed looks better. I always think it's strange outputting `false` as truthy and `true` as falsey (but if it saves a byte and it's allowed, I will still use it). ;) But since this is an equal bytes solution outputting the expected results, this is better.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ŒœE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKOTXf///x8SkpGRmVlcrKAAIVNS8vNLS5OScnJSUxUUiosLClJTExOzsxUVAQ)

Comment: Hey I like this!
It took me 80mns to do the same lol, I was like "hey let's learn Jelly now" then I learned.
I was about to post this but looked if Jelly answers were already there... and then saw this ^^ My steps: `¹©s2L€=2Ạa®s2E€Ạ`... `ḢƝs2E€Ạ`... but I couldn't manage to get what I wanted, and then I saw `Œœ` lol

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.every((x,y)=>x==s[y|1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBCoMwEEDRfU8RXSXQDvQA8RTuxMXEjDU1OMGpYqB3TxG33fzNg//GHWVYQ/o8FvZURlvENgK005q1Pu7Z2OawVrr8ffamDLwIR4LILz3qDgDqtp2mEESUuuo987Y5FyORUiIpESHOc1XVvTG3Pwd0Dk8rPw)

---

**23 bytes** using wastl's regex

```javascript
s=>/^((.)\2)*$/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcuxCoMwEIDh3aeI0uGu0Aju@hSOpXAxZ40GL/Sirx8L3br8wwf/Sifp9AkpP3bxXOa@aD@0LwCLzw7vt9Zm1gyKZZJdJbKN8oYZmnFclhBUjfnVe5HjcC5GZmNUU2Im2ra6bhCrv5mcoy@XCw)

Comment: 24 bytes, but outputs an array for true, `null` for false: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcuxDoIwEIDh3acoxOHOhJK441MwEpNre9hK5RoPfP1i4ubyD1/yP@lD6t@pbN0qges8VB1ual@0@Qj9HcDidMXLucfqZVXJbLM8YIZ2HGNMSdWYX0MQ2XfncmY2RrUUZqJlaZoW8fQ3k3P05XoA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: 27 bytes `s=>!s.some((x,y)=>x>s[y|1])`

Comment: @tsh Unfortunately, [that would only work if you replaced `>` with `!=`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/0bbY1k6xWK84PzdVQ6NCp1LT1q7Crji6ssYwVpMrCZusoi1U@n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaiRrSenp5SYmJSUrJSrKYmF7JkEprkfwA)

Answer (score 7):

## x86 machine code, <del>9</del> 8 bytes

```
D1 E9       SHR  CX, 1          ; divide length in half
       L1:
AD          LODSW               ; load next two chars into AH/AL 
3A E0       CMP  AH, AL         ; compare AH and AL 
E1 FB       LOOPE L1            ; if equal, continue loop
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function. Input string in `SI`, input string length in `CX`.  Output `ZF` if is double speak.

#### Or *14 bytes* as a complete PC DOS executable:

```
B4 01       MOV  AH, 01H        ; DOS read char from STDIN (with echo) 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; read first char into AL
92          XCHG DX, AX         ; put first char into DL
B4 08       MOV  AH, 08H        ; DOS read char from STDIN (no echo) 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; read second char into AL
3A C2       CMP  AL, DL         ; compare first and second char 
74 F3       JE   -13            ; if the same, continue loop 
C3          RET                 ; otherwise exit to DOS
```

Input is via `STDIN`, either pipe or interactive.  Will echo the "de-doubled" input until a non-doubled character is detected, at which point will exit (maybe bending I/O rules a little bit, but this is just a bonus answer).

[image]

Build and test ISDBL2.COM using `xxd -r`:

```
00000000: b401 cd21 92b4 08cd 213a c274 f3c3       ...!....!:.t..
```

#### Original *24 bytes* complete PC DOS executable:

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1          ; SI to DOS PSP (080H) 
AD          LODSW               ; load string length into AL 
D0 E8       SHR  AL, 1          ; divide length in half 
8A C8       MOV  CL, AL         ; put string length into BL 
        CLOOP: 
AD          LODSW               ; load next two chars into AH/AL 
3A E0       CMP  AH, AL         ; compare AH and AL 
E1 FB       LOOPE CLOOP         ; if equal, continue loop
        DONE: 
B8 0E59     MOV  AX, 0E59H      ; BIOS tty function in AH, 'Y' in AL 
74 02       JZ   DISP           ; if ZF, result was valid double 
B0 4E       MOV  AL, 'N'        ; if not, change output char to N 
        DISP: 
B4 0E       MOV  AH, 0EH 
CD 10       INT  10H 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
```

Input from command line, output to screen `'Y'` if double, `'N'` if not.

[image]

Build and test ISDBL.COM using `xxd -r`:

```
00000000: d1ee add0 e88a c8ad 3ae0 e1fb b859 0e74  ........:....Y.t
00000010: 02b0 4eb4 0ecd 10c3                      ..N.....
```

#### Credits:

- **-2 bytes** thx to @ErikF!

Comment: Suggest using `LOOPE` instead of `JNZ`/`LOOP` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @ErikF, brilliant! Completely forgot about that!

Answer (score 7):

## [Malbolge (*unlimited memory access variant*)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Malbolge_Unshackled), Around 4 megabytes

You asked the golfers, but for the second time forgot about the bowlers.

This is too big to include in the answer for obvious reason so here is gist [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kspalaiologos/a02e57046360ec5f1265ec25ce26768b/raw/8d1bd1b4b705f227c2c76de9921205a7531704de/189358).

You might want to use the fast interpreter to test this program, as it's hellishly slow (hellishly, get it?). I'm going to include the TIO.run link after Dennis (hopefully) takes on my issue on TIO tracker.

// Edit: Nope, no TIO link as the answer size limit is 65536 bytes, and no abusing url shorteners because they just refuse to shorten it

Comment: what is this monstrosity :)

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>58</del> 56 bytes

```php
function f($s){return!$s?:$s[0]==$s[1]&f(substr($s,2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZCxboNADIbn3FMYhApIVKEdm6JsfYJsCYMhJqCgu9PZN0V59dK7UKlL1S72/8v2Z9l2tMv73oY4eN3LZDQMRcblzZF4p5OM928ZH@u2aUJ6aZ@Ggn3H4kJT9VqWu/uSCbEwNHBUCrZbEOdJQX44jOM0MQOs8Xw2xvuum2ciAGZriRCv1yTJq80mDIgQieRVkIiPVNeIdR3kgzvgzL@AtZE/2RDZ2HUrcl0iPzqqUI9LWrVTivrRQIbuoitIT5JW8R/RltHrk05D02AcYT8W8H078joCJdwC7h9GINwXEWaRT2Pjz3l5/vgC)

As a recursive function.

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>61</del> <del>56</del> 52 bytes

```php
while(''<$l=$argn[$i++])$r|=$l!=$argn[$i++];echo!$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBbsMgDIbP5SmcCCmpmqk5L4122xP01vbgtE5BjQABUQ9bX30ZhGmdpqm7YGPwZ/4fI8y0eTHCMLZew9WiAakAoR/V0UutoNcWCJ0kC56cl@r8zO6HJUd7Vkt4m65CDlQWxYYP7VzccblaHZbcvrd8yH7WGjoKnXHbTDfGeKQ6aGHHGIQneDsSg2K7FUJK5wDSejppPY5dNwxEAM4ZQ4R4uWRZUS0WocF7Iu@LKqSIc6hrxLoOaQL3OLg/yEr7h3CIcOy6xExT/D2PWThPYR52YA1jUSHMkivI9z6vvq2Ke7VXebgUrCU8ihK@PECXWiD4GXD/MALhNv22Kap5IOdDm/hvbnp6/QQ)

Or standalone program.  Input string via `STDIN`, output is `truthy` (`1`) if it is double speak, and `falsey` (`0`) if it is not double speak.

-4 bytes thx to [@Night2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81663/night2)!

Comment: This appears to output 1 for a non-double speak string, as well as a double speak string.

Comment: @AJFaraday try now - [is double speak](https://tio.run/##NcoxCsMwDEDRq9ggQkPoCRzTrSfIVjIojVqLGEtYyfXrBkqXxx@@Jm3jTU9fUi@AEbC@SwB8AA/DHOO/ug5qBB5tr5nKefahD/RM4qGG1qYpJWYz536uq8hxLEvORM6ZqRIhbpv3H9GdpVi73r8), [is not double speak](https://tio.run/##NcpBCoMwEEDRqyQwSEV6ghi66wncFRdjnTbBkBky8fqNInTz@IsvQdr4kNMPlxugByzf7ABfEIdh9v5fXQfFQxy1lkT5PHvXO3oHtlBca9MUQoyqxlxmrmZdmfd9WVIiMkZVhAhx26z9sdTIWdv9eQA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

```hs
f(x:y:z)|x==y=f z
f[]=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDsIwDET3foUbMcDIWilbZ34AMcRtIqo4dYVTqa3492BWwo3v3t3TSfREpYTz1u3dcXlv1u42wNGE@8NeS3LTDBZGbkCzvKY5wwkCmL5nXldEIu8BRJbFe@dibFvzq96YOWf9UF19HWjGSnOIroZKEf9gopSYRXLOVSvCDDAMRF/Dm/IB)

Very straightforward. Double speak is only empty or a repeated character prepended to double speak.

Less straightforward now. Outputs via presence or absence of an error, per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/73884); no error means double speak. Pattern matching fails when the first two characters differ or when there are an odd number of characters. Thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) for these savings!

Answer (score 6):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> <s>63</s> <s>59</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

-25 bytes thanks to Giuseppe
-1 byte thanks to val

```lua
print(#(...):gsub("(.)%1","")<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDWUNPT0/TKr24NElDSUNPU9VQSUdJSdPGUPP///@JiUlJiYkA)

Removes every doubled character, then checks if the result is empty.

Comment: why not just `i:gsub("(.)%1","")` and check if `i==""`?

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0QjsSg92jDWKr24NElDSUNPU9VQSUdJSdPWFkj8//8/MTEpKTERAA) is 34 bytes, not totally sure it's valid since I've never written Lua before, but it appears to work.

Comment: welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange though!

Comment: I assumed that `"(.)%1"` by itself included collisions, but it didn't occur to me that by replacing it once for all captures would be enough. Should I implement your solution or should you write your own answer? And thanks!

Comment: @Giuseppe Managed to chisel out one extra byte from your solution

Comment: Very nice! I only asked since the R solution takes a similar `gsub` approach; glad to help you golf it down :-)

Comment: Nice idea! `arg[1]` can be replaced with `(...)` to save one byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 bytes

```perl
$_=/^((.)\2)*$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/TkNDTzPGSFNLRf///5CQjIzMzOJiBQUImZKSn19ampSUk5OaqqBQXFxQkJqamJidraj4L7@gJDM/r/i/bgEA)

Outputs 1 for double-speak, nothing for non-double-speak.

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

```
½=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///QXtv//9VLUotL1LnUS0pSU4uLS0DMjIzU1Jyc/HwdBYXy8vz8oqKcnJQURUWgjEcGkADRHlAV6EoA)

Basically the same as the 05AB1E answer, `½` splits the string into even and odd characters, then check for equality. Passes for the empty string.

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```powershell
!$($args|?{+$p*($p="$_"[$p-eq$_])};$p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBTsMwDIbvfQp3GNbCeIKpohJC2g0kequqKd3ctSwsWZwAUtdnL2FdD9vIIYr@z/lsyVp9k@GapOyxSto@xAiF2fDhqX1AfR@hTia4nOSoH2mPyyLu5qjjvguCNArAn1mE1jiaAUwXC/IepabxSCoh2aOR/APO49GUZXXdNMwAw71eK@VcWUpJBMCsNZEQ220Y@r@XTlGW4lopfHzdP8uI2NrL8iEfQBAfbtsjRvrRtLK0ngEyJIDLITbETlof3GEFqR/3BtiaZrcB1lJY618h0N41X0LSzkKlDOSrWpi8KI6G/O392bFVn6/lh29QpO2gTE7qOTT8cuo9Zn/rGOfxfKedL@cu6Pr@Fw)

where `$p` contains a previous char.

No [recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189404/80745), no [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189370/80745) :). Takes input as a char-array via a splatting string (see TIO link).

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 48 bytes

```powershell
for(;$b-eq$a-and$args){$a,$b,$args=$args}$b-eq$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFNasMwEIX3PsWEqo0DzgmCwVAK2bVQ70Ioo3gcu1EtRSO1Bddnd1X/LJpEi0F63@i9QTL6iyxXpFQvyrTtS23jjZBrOgtcY1MItEdetQITIZPhkA61m3r6LoqyOIKwklg46ykBWG63FBy1Xq5mUqLigGZyA/yXZ6c8r6q6ZgYYa1Fo7b2UShEBMBtDhHg6LRbh7qUnSonXlhjk6/w8J2LnLttHfQTR6ue@HbCgb0MHR0UCgiEF8TbKltgrF4QHUUIWxr0DdrZujsBGoXNhtwA6@/oTFTUOwmvD7lCh3e33g8Pu5fXRs9Mfz/I9BOyzdrRMJ@sN1Pw0Zc/a3z/M8wTeGB/auYu6vv8F)

No [recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189404/80745), no [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189370/80745) and no pipe :D. It also takes input as a char-array via a splatting string. It uses `$b-eq$a` instead `$a-eq$b` for a case when a last char has #0 code.

Answer (score 5):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>204</s> 156 bytes

-48 bytes thanks to Jo King (mostly by changing the output method)

```
A.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:Open mind.Puck:Open
mind.Is I worse zero?If soSpeak thy.Is you as big as I?If soLet usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsIwFESvMgcoOUA3kkUXAUGhy9JFTL9aq0nI/8HWy0dSN65mhnkMw/FZilb6YddGnbNbGqWdwLSqd@SpmqFbKXsZh84LJVQU1k@o9FhTe4rk8Zr9tC/8RcMweIfEhA@lcDBXcOgj2QVy32q9hQzLuMy3KuZHHEmQef@hShEh@gI)

Exits with error if the input is double speak, and with warning if it is not double speak (which is [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/86301) by default).

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Razetime!*

```
ETC2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zXE2ej///9KJSUZGZlKAA)

Hooray for all ASCII solutions! Outputs a positive number if the input is doublespeak, otherwise zero.

```
  C2  Cut list into chunks of 2
 T    Transpose
E     Check if list has all the same elements (return length of list if so)
```

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9xsV2ej////K5WUZGRkZhYXKwEA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime That doesn't appear to check if the length is even

Comment: [this should work](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zXE2ej///9KJSUZGZlKAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
y=
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=y%3D&inputs=HHeelllloo&header=&footer=)

Look ma, no Unicode!

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
s->s[1:2:end]==s[2:2:end]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/WNeuONrQysgqNS8l1ta2ONoIyv5fUJSZV5KTp5GmoRQSkpGRmVlcrKAAIVNS8vNLS5OScnJSUxUUiosLClJTExOzsxUVlTQ1uYjXiKLvPwA)

Comment: It's shorter to use a symbol instead of `f`, e.g `!a=...`. Or to use an anonymous function: `s->...`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
Óˆ±
ø^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DkQx2HNnId3hGn8v9/RkZqak5Ofj4A) or [Verify test cases](https://tio.run/##K/v//3Df4cmHOg5t5AIydsSp/P@fkZGampOTn89VXp6fX1SUk5OSwmVoaGRkbGxiYmrKlZ5eVJQKBHl5Cgrp6Tk5iYnFQKCgkJKSnw9Sz8XlATPA0MjYBKaVKwNmLgA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: d388 b10a d85e 24                        .....^$
```

Just two regexes. Explanation:

```
Ó   " Remove all occurrences...
 ˆ  "   Any character
  ± "   Followed by itself
    "   This regex is actually just the compressed form of (.)\1
ø   " Count the number of matches
 ^$ "   An empty line
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
-:2#_2{.\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUy9CsIwGNz7FFcdgtAG6RhwsdBJHLSjIkn6lcYWUvyayYePQaEe3MFxP8@4kaLHQUGgwB4qsZSoL6cmlqraPqq3vN3jLjsfJa7BWmLOyA4ePUTbDoNzzMBPu877EIyZJiKAeZ6JtB7HPBfrZkmgdLIsIvueNtpN4UVrQWtj7NovlND/cYqSix8)

*-2 bytes thanks to Adám*

*-1 byte thanks to miles*

TLDR explanation: Is the input the same as every other character of the input doubled?

Comment: [`-:]#~2 0$~#`](https://tio.run/##PYyxCoMwGIT3PMVZCz8FDdIx0KUFp9Khde2QxF@MCkpjVl89DS14cDd99w3xIKnDRYFQoIJKLSVuz3sdS/XOtzOq45bHk3hcJV7BWvZesO1ndKCm6XvnvAf@27bzHIIx08QMeL8szFqPY5bR/llTOEnWlcRPWms3hQ/vgNbG2J0vFGkS8Qs)

Comment: `-:2#_2{.\]` should save another byte

Comment: very nice, thanks @miles

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>64</s> 59 bytes

```powershell
filter f($n){$a,$b,$r=$n;$a-eq$b-and$(if($r){f $r}else{1})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcmxCoMwEAbgvU8R5B8S0KFz6Vu4icOlvaAQ0vYS6BDy7Kcdla7f9359WfLCMaqGNRYWEyySq6AevofckW6ggT/wA6Un7Lq/uBoMpHHMXK/NNQ3GTo@FZJrnjrynzl0OtNuJxpE551L@8U9VNw)

Recursive function, no regex. Takes input as a `char`-array (see TIO link). Peels off the first two elements into `$a` and `$b`, stores the remaining into `$r`. If we still have elements remaining, recurse along with `$a -eq $b`. Otherwise just check whether `$a -eq $b`. Output is implicit.

*-5 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Comment: de-duplicate [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcmxCoMwEAbgvU8R5B8S0KFz6Vu4icOlvaAQ0vYS6BDy7Kcdla7f9359WfLCMaqGNRYWEyySq6AevofckW6ggT/wA6Un7Lq/uBoMpHHMXK/NNQ3GTo@FZJrnjrynzl0OtNuJxpE551L@8U9VNw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Thanks! I was missing the `$` before the statement block and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ġ₂z₂=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WU9B51rFBKS8wpBrJrH@7qrH24dcL/IwsfNTVVAbHt///RSiEhGRmZmcXFCgoQMiUlP7@0NCkpJyc1VUGhuLigIDU1MTE7W1FRSUcpFQigFIj28EhNzcnJz9fRUVAID8/PLyrKyUlJAUpArYwFAA)

Succeeds or fails.

```
ġ₂       The at-most-length-2 chunks of the input,
  z₂     which have equal length, zipped together,
    =    are equal.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
2==GCD@@Length/@Split@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCsIwFEX3fkVMoZNScK8@qCCCg2A3cXhJXk1o2obmdRK/PUqLdzjnLLdHttQjO42prdK@qs71CeBKw4ttCffgHUNepNvkBn7ku0MLtcUJNdMUIX8WJbwz2TTWOhejECuNGcd5Vsp7IiFiDIEIses2G7nNJKL6bSmlcLVWeqlLFI6FGWflScRA2B3/F62NzD7pCw)

```
        Length/@Split@#&    (*for the lengths of runs of characters*)
2==GCD@@                    (*check that they are all even*)
```

Comment: You've excluded the necessary code to convert the **string** input into a list which can be fed to `Split` (i.e. the 11 bytes of `Characters@`)

Comment: @AntiEarth [What's a string?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/81203)

Answer (score 4):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 192 bytes

```
PLEASE,1<-#2DOCOMEFROM(2)DOWRITEIN,1DO.5<-#1$',1SUB#1'~#256PLEASE(1)NEXTDOREADOUT#1DOGIVEUP(1)DO(1002)NEXTDO.5<-#1$',1SUB#2'~,1SUB#2DO(3)NEXTDOREADOUT#0PLEASEGIVEUP(3)DO(1002)NEXT(2)DOFORGET#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoJAFEV/RZlABQtnxFZtrBlFSJ/oWG01BxQlJXPrr0@SbmxzeXDPO9z69RHvZ95KGV@ZmzITn/aIULhAyLwEQp0YFO5JwFkQmZjCwZl7vNNMnGZnhLUJEee4vOrYiNiDU0iYSyHjaMb94MayeG4o6NiyyEpsLUSb1mOm7D@JtchXkb0R/cZ5kPiMIyIl51VV18OgKEuWZdeNY1G0rRCKMgx9L0SeN42qfgE)

Output is done with INTERCAL's native "butchered Roman numerals", so the true output of 1 prints as `\nI\n`, and the false output of 0 prints as `_\n\n`.

I don't feel like writing out a full explanation at the moment, but the ungolfed code is [here](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2FVBx1DBRldB2YjLxV/B2d/XVcEtyN9XQcNIEyQQHuQZ4qrg6QdUBeLqmYLVGqqo6xgGhzopG6rXKRuZmnFBjdIw1FTwc40IASkNcnV0UfAPDQGqBnHdPcNcFUIDuEBKgFwNQwMDI4RidHON1OugDJCshjE2Yw1gtsKNNsYwGugLkJCbf5C7K1CL0f//jo5OIAAA), I lifted the control flow from [something I wrote earlier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181789/85334), and the gist of what it does is read two characters at a time from the input through the usually unhelpful "Turing Tape" I/O until either the first resulting number is 256 (in which case the entire input has been validated and has even length, so it is double-speak), or the second resulting number is not 0 (in which case the second character is different from the first or does not exist, and the input is not double-speak).

I think I might be able to restructure this to cut down on redundancy, but I'm not quite feeling up to that at the moment either.

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>19</s> 17 characters

```
?{!1<|=[|0.(_)]}1
```

Explanation:

```
?             # read input

{             # while
    !1<       # stack length greater than 1?
|             # end of while condition and beginning of while block
    =         # compare the 2 top values in the stack
    [         # if (the condition is the top of stack)
    |         # end of then block and beginning of else block
        0.    # output 0
        (_)   # clear stack (discard top of stack in for loop stack length times)
    ]         # end if
}             # end while

1             # stack is already empty, push a truthy value

              # implicitly output the stack content if there was no explicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fvlrR0KbGNrrGQE8jXjO21vD//5CQjIzMzOJiBQUImZKSn19ampSUk5OaqqBQXFxQkJqamJidragIAA)

Comment: The `<` should be a `>`

Comment: And, uh, [10 bytes with `-rR` flag](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUM2@WtHQrsb20cR9//@HhGRkZGYWFysoQMiUlPz80tKkpJyc1FQFheLigoLU1MTE7GxFxf@6RUEA "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: [6 bytes with `-rR flag`](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUM1ew/bRxH3//4eEZGRkZhYXKyhAyJSU/PzS0qSknJzUVAWF4uKCgtTUxMTsbEXF/7pFQQA "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: [For the sake of it, 5 bytes using `-ir, -lp` and `-rR`](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUE3D9tHEff//h4RkZGRmFhcrKEDIlJT8/NLSpKScnNRUBYXi4oKC1NTExOxsRcX/ukVB/3Uzi/7r5hQAAA "Keg – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Curry, 18 bytes

*Tested to work in both [PAKCS](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/) and [KiCS2](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/)*

```
f(a:a:x)=f x
f[]=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcixDkAwFAXQ3VdcYmAgsTbpZjGxi@HhNZEWTatJfX0lzni24NzbWNKbT0lVJEjEWirETM2L7NJJxwUhMDk2Yed2GFHV2b8S1h3XgxIKRd/fdwjragwz4L21zERa53mRPg)

[Test it on smap!](https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?browser/78)

This returns `1` if string is double speak and nothing otherwise.

### Explanation

This is a pretty straight forward translation of the Haskell program:

```
f(a:b:x)|a==b=f x
f[]=1
```

But it uses Curry's more powerful pattern matches to save a bunch of bytes.  And while missing a pattern in Haskell is rather difficult to recover from, making this definitely pretty un-idiomatic at best and perhaps a little cheaty.  In curry missing patterns just mean it's not a match which is idiomatic and recoverable.  So it's shorter and I don't feel like I'm cheating.

### Testing

TIO has a limited ability to test things like this.  I recommend you use the [smap link](https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?browser/78) to test this.
This test handler I've made on smap will not work in KiCS2 or the newer version of PAKCS so you must select `PAKCS 2.2.0` (both `/one-value` and `/all-values` work fine).  This is because of the library `Control.SetFunctions` which I use for the test.  But the function itself does work in the versions if you want to manually test it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 1.75 bytes

```
y=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9fiIsIiIsInk9IiwiIiwiISguKikgLT4gKFxcZClcbmFiYSAtPiAwXG5hYmJhIC0+IDBcbmFhYmIgLT4gMVxuYWFhYmIgLT4gMFxudHRoaGlpc3MgLT4gMVxudHR0aGhoaWlpc3NzIC0+IDAiXQ==)

Basically every other answer

### Explained

```
y=
y   # Uninterleave the input, dumping to stack
 =  # Are the two items equal?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>26</s>, 22 bytes

```
({<({}[{}])>{()<>}{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6PaRqO6Nrq6NlbTrlpD08autrq2VvP//0Qg@K@bCAA)

Outputs 1 for false and 0 for true.

Readable version:

```
({
    <({}[{}])>
    {
        ()
        <>
    }
    {}
})
```

I originally had this:

```
{
    ({}[{}])

    {
        <>([()])<>{{}}
    }{}
}
<>({}())
```

Which is 10 bytes longer.

Comment: Does 0/non0 count as a boolean? If so, you can do [`({({}[{}]){{}}{}})`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6Nao7o2uro2VrO6urYWiDT//09MSkr8r5sIAA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: lol at the "Readable version" - its so very readable :P

Comment: @riley No that's not valid. However, I found a better trick.

Comment: @quinn Looks readable to me :P

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
s=>/^((.)\2)+$/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcRBCoMwEAXQq0RxMUMxQvd6CpdFiGas0eAEf@z104Vv8Xb3c1iukHJ7qpey9gX90E1Elj9vfjWdzYJM4LLoCY1io35ppXocty0EwJhn71Xve55jFDEGSEnEueOoqpq5/AE)

### Recursive Solution, 30 bytes

Thanks to Arnauld for a fix at the cost of 0 bytes.

```
f=([x,y,...s])=>x?x==y&f(s):!y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjukKnUkdPT684VtPWrsK@wta2Ui1No1jTSrHyf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGUmJiUpKSpiYXFuFkHOIQmf8A)

Comment: [Fixed recursive version](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jukKnUkdPT684VtPWrsK@wta2Ui1No1jTSrHyf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGUmJiUpKSpiYXFuFkHOIQmf8A)?

Comment: Thanks, @Arnauld :)

Comment: @Oliver, crap; only saw your original solution before posting mine. I'm happy to roll back to 26 if you got to that 23 before me - let me know.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> 34 bytes

-19 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
function(a)gsub("(.)\\1","",a)==""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcSxDsAQEADQXzk3kWiT7vUXRgtFCUF69f069A3vWRHObcXZrjf3xq24aTqOfBfGHCgRpRVKIa7IUeuUciYC@Pe@9zmdqzUEAKIxQrC2FMZQrA8)

Comment: I think `gsub("(.)\\1","",a)==""` would do the trick as well; many others use the same regex.

Comment: @Giuseppe This whole regex thing is pretty new to me. Thanks.

Comment: R + pryr gets you a [32-byter](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@7@gqLLIyipNI724NElDSUNPMybGUElHSUknUdPWVklJ83@ahlJISEZGZmZxsYIChExJyc8vLU1KyslJTVVQKC4uKEhNTUzMzlZUVNLkwqI@Ly8vPz@/pKQEIp2YlJQIZQGZSUlASwA) trivially modified from this answer.

Comment: If input can be taken as a vector, then `function(a)!sum(rle(a)$l%%2)` for 28

Answer (score 3):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 11 bytes

```apl
''≡⍵
(.)\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/19d/VHnwke9W7k09DRjDLn@/w8JycjIzCwuVlCAkCkp@fmlpUlJOTmpqQoKxcUFBampiYnZ2YqKAA)

`''≡⍵` the result is an empty string when

`(.)\1` a character followed by itself

is replaced by nothing

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 40 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Where((c,i)=>c!=$"{s}"[i|1]).Any()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrpOUn59jl2b7v9jWrlgvPCO1KFVDI1knU9PWLlnRVkWpuriWUSk6s8YwVlPPMa9SQ/O/NRdXeFFmSapPZl6qRpqGUkhIRkZmZnGxggKETEnJzy8tTUrKyUlNVVAoLi4oSE1NTMzOVlRU0tTEqrmYEs3E2IxFbyI2MeyCOETBwv8B)

Each character is tested against it's neighbor for inequality. If any inequalities exist, the result is false.

Since input is limited to printable ASCII characters, a control character is appended to input which is compared to the last character of an odd length string.

Outputs are reversed.

-3 bytes inspired by @Oliver

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcuxCsMgFEDRPV@hmRTSQOdWoUunjoEMoYOal/qIaPDFoZB/t5RuXe5w4Do6OcJ6L9Fdac8YX51NKehFVVKaUz96yCCE61Aq7biiCY/zU/a3@BayXppmzLjDAyOIRbTD4D0iEWO/znNKpVgbAgBjRNsGYMy6ct5K@T8ba82X6wc)?

Comment: @Oliver - this throws an exception on inputs like `a`, `aaa`, `aaaaa`, etc. You might be into something though, I'll keep fiddling.

Comment: I was able to knock off a few bytes at least :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 36 bytes

```
func[s][parse s[any[copy t skip t]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxCsQgEEX7nGKSG6TdY2zSDRajjkQMOjha5PQuYWEJ@4sPr3ivsh9v9mim8IIRenaoBoWqMihSvtAVuaCBpijQjDFDaswNAiz7fhwxqgJ83/tSerf2PJkBVEWYiVKa52X6Sev6ALLuQf@9bRMhqrU1undnxgc)

### Longer alternative:

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 40 bytes

```
func[s][(extract s 2)= extract next s 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsMwEEP3fMUlUzumY6E/0WQzHs72mZgEx9zZkL93a0pLqAahJ5CYXH2SU7rzd6i@RKtEqwsdmdFmELhdH/Cl@A6t0jVxiBk8DPO8LCGIAHzcuX0vxZhtIwIQSYkIcV37fuh@o3E8ARp7ov@/aUoJkTlnbGo39QU)

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <strike>60</strike> 45 bytes

thanks to Unrelated String

```
+[].
+[A,A|T]:- +T.
-X:-string_chars(X,Y),+Y.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/Xzs6Vo9LO9pRx7EmJNZKV0E7RI9LN8JKt7ikKDMvPT45I7GoWCNCJ1JTRztS7/9/dV11DaWQkIyMzMziYgUFCJmSkp9fWpqUlJOTmqqgUFxcUJCampiYna2oqKSpx4VNS15@CTG6UkEAhQfkAAA)

Converting it from a string to a list of atoms kind of ruined the score, but well..

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/Xzs6Vo9LO9pRx7EmJNZKV0E7RI9LN8JKt7ikKDMvPT45I7GoWCNCJ1JTRztS7/9/dV11DaWQkIyMzMziYgUFCJmSkp9fWpqUlJOTmqqgUFxcUJCampiYna2oqKSpx4VNS15@CTG6UkEAhQfkAAA)

Comment: ...it looks like you can also use `atom_chars` instead of `string_chars`, even though you're taking a string as input, and not an atom. But that may be irrelevant if you can take a backtick-delimited string--that is, a list of char codes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brain-Flak), <s>36</s> <s>10</s> <s>42</s> 30 bytes

```
(<>)<>{({}[{}]<>){{}{}}{}<>}<>
```

Outputs 0 if it is double speak, and nothing if it isn't

-12 bytes thanks to [Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69059/nitrodon)

## How it works

```
(<>) Pushes 0 to the second stack
<>   Swaps back to the first stack
{    Begins a loop that will run until the stack is empty
({}[{}]<>)    Pops the top two items off of the first stack and pushes their difference to the second stack
{{}{}}{}      If the difference is zero, it gets popped and nothing happens. 
If there difference is one, the zero that was put on at the beginning gets popped, so nothing will get outputted at the end 
<>   Swaps back to the first stack
}    End loop
<>   Swap to the second stack for output
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X8PGTtPGrlqjuja6ujYWyKmurq2uBSIbOyD6/9/FJT@/tDQpKScnNVVBITi4oCA1NTExO1tR8b9uIgA)

Comment: Fixed both of the problems

Comment: `({}<>)<>({}<>)({}[{}])` can be simplified to `({}[{}]<>)`.

Comment: oh wow, no clue why I decided to pop and swap stacks twice, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 36 bytes

> [My Zsh answer to the previous challenge can be found here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189073/86147)

Exits truthy (0) if *NOT* double speak, and falsy (1) if double speak. (As allowed in a comment.)

```sh
for a b (${(s::)1})r+=${a#$b}
[ $r ]
```

---

```sh
for a b (${(s::)1})r+=${a#$b}
         ${(s::)1}             # split $1 characterwise
for a b (         )            # take pairs of characters from ${(s::)1}, assign to $a and $b
                      ${a   }  # first character
                      ${ #$b}  # remove second character as prefix
                   r+=         # append to $r as string
[ $r ]                         # exit truthy if $r is non-empty
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lcu9CsIwFIbhPVdxWjNYpINrRbyJbuKQmGNzaMhp84Ng6bVHi5ubyzd8vM8r2vK05BACKgOOPJ7AsIiYoG2hlttTlwcHUKBhL5d97LrmuDbhcJaL2km9iivIALeCd8sgLyL7TQdh2GPpe2uJYgT4rjHMOWvtHCJAjNOEqNQ4VpX4TT2n/3rPnD5knnMmSmkDIRANg7UpVUK8AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/), 31 bytes

```mathematica
AllTrue[Length/@Split@#,EvenQ]&
```

This works by converting the input (an array of characters, according to @attinat) into a list of characters, splitting this list into sublists of contiguous identical elements, and checking that each sublist has an even number of elements.

Comment: An answer should be a [full program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/81203); this is a snippet that requires `s` to be defined beforehand.

Comment: @attinat fixed; I was adopting the convention used by other answers (and see with amusement you pointed this out after I asked about your exclusion of `Characters@`)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcExCoAwDADAr5QKrr5ACKi4OCiO4hA0mkJtJQb7/Ordhcp0oboN82Hq3L0UpqVvWoCBwqlcwXx7p1CsZR7FBYUDGkbBTUkeMJaZyP9iNCalGEW833ebPw) by using [`GCD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GCD.html) instead of `AllTrue`. See also [this n-speak solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189815/87058).

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcHBCYAwDADAVYKCXycQIuLPh@IEoU1NobYSg45fvTvJhE@y6KgGGOqYPeL8cN56XDgfJj3uV4qGbVdXjdkw4CSk5Iz1RmhEmNOvFID3LUU1Je@b@gE) by using `And` instead of `AllTrue`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```scala
_.grouped(2).forall(t=>t.size>1&&t(0)==t(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BasJAEIbvPsXPIrILbag9SjfQ4sVzHqBMdNTYZXebmUip5NnjYjx9/8fM4ZM9BZpSe@G9Yic73aahDdxkph/wn3I8CD5zxm0BXCngOMQNGu27eIKv8ZVSYIrw03d16tOQ@WDfXXVMPYVg1ddaSffP9Xq1UvvmvFe7dm4Cyges4OMVDf9aQ9SaFxhqacaTZcx8DtXzuetE5l2kWFExzj0KgVzKNEQrZikbLG@l14objSvXcTFOdw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 18 bytes

```
;U;;A-!/@/n\nW.\O?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9861NraUVdR30E/LyYvXC/G3/7/fxeX/PzS0qSknJzUVAWF4OCCgtTUxMTsbEVFAA)
Outputs 1 if True and nothing if False.

I suppose that it is fitting that this is twice the length to my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189496/31347) to the previous question

```
    ; U
    ; ;
A - ! / @ / n \
n W . \ O ? . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=O1U7O0EtIS9AL25cblcuXE8/&input=RERvb3V1YmJsbGVlICBTU3BwZWVhYWtrISE=&speed=20)

- `A` Put all input onto the stack
- `-` subtract the TOS and start of the test loop
- `!` test result for 0
- `@` if not 0, halt (FALSE for double speak)
- `/;U;;` if 0, pop subtraction result and top two items from the stack, u-turn sends it in the right direction.
- `!\n/?` an ignored "if 0", reflect, negate, reflect and test for EOI (now 1)
- `O\/@` if positive (1) output and reflect a couple of times onto the halt (TRUE for double speak)
- `nW` if negative, reverse the negation and shift lane onto the start of the test loop.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
2Zy
```

Almost as trivial as the solution to the other challenge. Errors with an input size < 2, which was never confirmed to be allowed, so might be invalid.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3yiq8v//kpKMjMzM4mIA)

```
2Z   Unzip input by 2
  y  All equal?
```

Unzipping by 2 basically undoes the result of interleaving 2 strings. So if two equal strings are interleaved, then it is doublespeak.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
$QUWa
```

The existing solution used a longer iterative comparison. Thankfully, the unweave function exists.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fJTA0PPH///@JiYlJSQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 13 bytes

```
,:,
" -@
""}!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fx0qHS0lB14FLSalW8f//lJT8/NLSpKScnFQA)

That's a whole lot of no-ops, but I can't find any easy way to remove them.

Prints -1 if the input is a double speak, nothing otherwise. Allowed by [this I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17938/78410).

#### How it works

```
,:,    Push char input (,), duplicate (:), push another char input
-      Subtract the top two.
       It can be nonzero for two reasons: the string has odd length or
       the last two chars differ.
       In either case, take a turn and exit, producing no output (@)
}      Remove the top number from scope and reveal the first char pushed
       (out of the last two). If it is negative (EOF), turn left,
       print it as number (-1), and exit (@).
"""    Otherwise, turn right and go through the no-op path back to
       the start of the program.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 28 bytes

```
[ 2 group [ = ] assoc-all? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0xDsIwDIXhvad4F4CBEYQYEQsLYqo6mMi0ESFJY1cVQpw9uOrgT//0/CSnqdT77XI970EiyQn6kqbsY48Xl8gBubDqJxcfFeMM4XHi6FhwaJpx/oIeZLdgGouqw@C9iIWVpbXgV1vs1n20OKJbX24ohBO6@qaMbf0D)

- `2 group` Split a sequence every 2 elements, e.g. `{ 1 1 2 2 3 3 } -> { { 1 1 } { 2 2 } { 3 3 } }`
- `[ = ] assoc-all?` Does every pair in a sequence consist of equal values?

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
[ 2 group flip 1 cut = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsJAEIThPk8xTyBoqViLjY1YicXl2CSH8bK3t0eQkGc/N1jMx19N57xOUh/36@1yRC9T4RB7vEkijWAh1S9LiIo0I1MqFD1lnJomzQtc62wbprGpOgwh5GxhZWmdsdYnDv9/dGNg7OGL4oxX/TjGrv4A)

*Thanks to @Bubbler!*
*-2 bytes from me*

- `flip` Transpose a matrix. e.g. `{ { 1 1 } { 2 2 } { 3 3 } }` -> `{ { 1 2 3 } { 1 2 3 } }`
- `1 cut` Split the matrix in two between its first and second rows. If there isn't a second row, outputs `{ }`. e.g. `{ { 1 2 3 } { 1 2 3 } }` -> `{ { 1 2 3 } } { { 1 2 3 } }`
- `=` Are they equal?

Comment: Alternative [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc0xDsIwEETRPqeYE6RICUKUiIYGUSEKJ1onFsF2djcKCHF2sxEFxXy9brzrNHG5nI@nwwZOJHWCntOcQ@xxJ440IjOpvjKHqJgWCE0zxY7kr5qeyk6wrappecO1zrbGalmrOgwhiBhMRrPgU65ofofwY8jY@8CiDXa4lYfLqMsX).

Comment: @Bubbler that's really nice. I tried the `flip` approach at first but forgot about conditional first2.

Comment: @ Bubbler we can save 2 more bytes with `1 cut` instead of `?first2`.

Answer (score 3):

## Desmos, 225 bytes

```
f\left(i\right)=\left\{\operatorname{total}\left(\left[\left\{i\left[a\cdot2+1\right]=i\left[a\cdot2+2\right]\right\}\operatorname{for}a=\left[0...\frac{\operatorname{length}\left(i\right)}{2}-1\right]\right]\right)>0\right\}
```

Input is taken as a list of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character codes, I don't know much about Desmos, so I'd love to know if there's a better way!

[Try it online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xaq0towu5j)

Comment: Damn, that's amazing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 22 bytes

Essentially the inverse of my ["DDoouubbllee ssppeeaakk!!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241513/77309) answer.

Capture any character twice, and delete it.

If it's double speak, the result is empty string, and a non-empty string otherwise.

```bash
a:
{[]$1 $1,$$ $$}=>*
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
zạ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS6oe7lq4pDgpuRgqsOCmVkhIRkZmZnGxggKETEnJzy8tTUrKyUlNVVAoLi4oSE1NTMzOVlSEaAEA)

##### Explanation

```python
zạ  # Implicit input                -> s
z   # Uninterleave the input        -> [s[0::2], s[1::2]]
 ạ  # Check if they are both equal  -> s[0::2] == s[1::2]
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 2 bytes

```
ĭ=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FouPrLVdUpyUXAzlL7hpqpSYlKjEBSQhFJAGUxC6pCQjIzOzuBjMBLKBHCCvWAmiGwA)

```
ĭ       Deinterleave
 =      Check equality
```

Since Nekomata doesn't have the concept of booleans or truthiness, the flag `-e` is required for every [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
≅⊃'▽¬▽◿2⇡⧻.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZyDihpAg4omF4oqDJ-KWvcKs4pa94pe_MuKHoeKnuy4KCmcgImFhYSIKZyAiYWJhIgpnICJhYmJhIgpnICJhYWJiIgpnICJhYWFiYiIKZyAidHRoaGlpc3MiCmcgInR0dGhoaGlpaXNzcyI=)

```
≅⊃'▽¬▽◿2⇡⧻.
          .  # duplicate
         ⧻   # length
        ⇡    # range
      ◿2     # modulo two
 ⊃'▽¬▽       # get the elements at even and odd indices
≅            # do they match?
```

Comment: [fails](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgL8OX4omhLz3ihq_iip_ip7ssMgoKZiAiYWFhIg==) for "aaa".

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks. Fixed for +1.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 12 bytes

**Solution:**

```
&/1==/'0N 2#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X03f0NZWX93AT8FIWSkkJCMjM7O4WEEBQqak5OeXliYl5eSkpiooFBcXFKSmJiZmZysqKv3/DwA)

**Explanation:**

```
&/1==/'0N 2# / the solution
       0N 2# / reshape into Nx2 grid
    =/'      / equals (=) over (/) each (')
  1=         / equal to 1 (ie a match)
&/           / take the minimum
```

**Extra:**

- `(~).+0N 2#` works([ish](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X6NOU0/bwE/BSFkpJCQjIzOzuFhBAUKmpOTnl5YmJeXkpKYqKBQXF6SkpiYmZmcrKir9/w8A)) for 10 bytes, but not if the only difference is a character on the end of one of the strings :(

Comment: Wouldn't just `&/=/'0N 2#` work?

Comment: Not for [odd-length input](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X03fVl/dwE/BSFkpJCQjIzOzuFhBAUKmpOTnl5YmJeXkpKYqKBQXFxSkpiYmZmcrKiYq/f8PAA) :(

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
!($args-creplace"(.)\1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoMwEIDhPU9xOa4lgbbQtVBw9AEcCxL1bMRAQg7pYH32VOny8w1/ih/O4jmEQuNzLdqQy2@59plTcD2judnXHW3ZlKqMwrrm/Y0RL7sPHWga76dJBODfYYhxWbouBGYAkZSYnZtnrVHZ72lFauEBZM40ArUWt/ID)

Uses the regex method going around. If the string is emptied out, it will return true, otherwise false.

Comment: you can omit  `,''` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoMwEIDhPU9xOa4lgbbQtVBw9AEcCxL1bMRAQg7pYH32VOny8w1/ih/O4jmEQuNzLdqQy2@59plTcD2judnXHW3ZlKqMwrrm/Y0RL7sPHWga76dJBODfYYhxWbouBGYAkZSYnZtnrVHZ72lFauEBZM40ArUWt/ID "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Ha ha, I'm smrt. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 63 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
R	I LEN(1) . X
	I X X =	:S(R)
	OUTPUT =IDENT(I) 1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCoAgEAXP@hXbTS9B0CnolgchLGqDrklCkWSw9P22EAOPeTB0J59inbOw0Fo3Lign1t44VWkoYZX8VqYVzawmLcWwIFccd8ahshoqaVyXM@JxnCcRwL/7ntL7eh9jCABEzxPCtl1XUXw)

Matches the first character `LEN(1)` and saves it `.` to `X`. If `I` matches `X` concatenated with itself, it replaces that substring and repeats. If the remaining string is empty, `IDENT(I,<implicit empty string>)`, then `1` is output, else nothing is output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⬤⪪Ｓ²⁼ι⮌…ι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYgxDoMwDAD3vsJsRqILayeEOnSrCh8wwWoiLJLGCRKvT0GcdDecsRSNJynlHd2asBPBIYhL@FpDTkM67hfrBtrD5y@TKLoGPrxxVMZ@N8K99eGcbX3yKGUcrXVOFeDqPHuf8zSJMAOohsBMtCxVdSv3Tf4) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs Charcoal's default boolean format, which is `-` for true and nothing for false. Explanation:

```
  Ｓ         Input string
 ⪪ ²        Split into substrings of length up to 2
⬤           All substrings
        ι   Current substring
       … ²  Extended to length 2
      ⮌     Reversed
    ⁼       Equals
     ι      Current substring
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 73 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_input_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_input_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_EXIT]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing newline so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

Outputs `0` for falsey, or nothing for truthy.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XYpRCsAgDEO/21PEO3kBnQVFYUInO36nbl@DJCSP3Llcoj0cYsbA1DSDmEBEe2NWzL3h//HhTWnRVcy8z7kUVeDNlM5zjBhbEwFUexcJoVbn@AE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Start LOOP:
  Character c = STDIN as character
  If(c == '\n'):
    Stop program
  Character d = STDIN as character
  If(c == d):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Print 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>20</s> 15 bytes

5 bytes saved thanks to Adam.

Prompts for input of string:

```
n≡(2×2|⍳⍴n)/n←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/7nPepcqGF0eLpRzaPezY96t@Rp6ucBZYGq/gPl/6dxqYeEZGRkZhYXKyhAyJSU/PzS0qSknJzUVAWF4uKCgtTUxMTsbEVFdS6g8sTEpKTkZCgzEcQEAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 11 bytes

```
~#@~# -_#q1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@vU3aoU1bQjVcuNPz/PyQkIyMzs7hYQQFCpqTk55eWJiXl5KSmKigUFxcUpKYmJmZnKyoCAA)

Returns 1 if double speak, 0 if not.

10 byte solution which returns 0 for double speak and non-0 otherwise:

```
~#q~#1-_#q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@vUy6sUzbUjVcu/P8/JCQjIzOzuFhBAUKmpOTnl5YmJeXkpKYqKBQXFxSkpiYmZmcrKgIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda s:all[([s[2*i]==s[2*i+1]for i in range(int(len(s)/2))]),0][len(s)%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBDsIgEAC/sj2Ysmqi4s2EX/SGHCCAJV2BsO3B12O0l5lMpn7WueR7j@rZyb6dt8APS6SFZi2PySj19@lmYmmQIGVoNr@CSHkVFLJgvEhEg@er0XsfpOm1/X4U4zTNc0rMADu9L2XbnCMKAYC51hCsXZZhGBH7Fw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
╩3╦x╨
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ca33cb78d0&i=TThhiiss++iiss++ddoouubbllee++ssppeeaakk%21%21%0Aaba%0Aabba%0Aaabb%0Aaaabb%0Aaabbbb%0Atthhiiss%0Attthhhiiisss&a=1&m=2)

Outputs integers. Zero for double speak and nonzero (one now!) otherwise, as allowed [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak#comment453405_189358). Replace `1I` below with `|e` if you want the opposite behavior, but I think this version looks nicer.

#### Unpacked (6 bytes) and explanation

```
:G|g1I
:G        Array of run lengths
  |g      GCD
    1I    Is odd? Could use 2% instead
```

The GCD of run lengths will be even exactly when all run lengths are.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>37</s> 40 bytes

+3 bytes to fix `'0'` issue

```php
<?=''==preg_replace('/(.)\1/','',$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcQ7CoAwDADQq1QQouAHZy1unqCjIFWDLRYbGr2@cfANjxyJDKMG0JoSHktCCnbDAtqiKeeuhQqgym06rrIXMcY575mV@t/3GJ9nXUNAVIqZCNHa88yyN9Lt48VSTx8)

Similar to other RegEx answers.

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 55 bytes

```php
for(;($l=$argn[$i++])==$argn[$i++]&&$l.$l;);echo$l=='';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKw1VHJsVRKL0vOiVTK1tWM1bZF5amoqOXoqOdaa1qnJGflAlbbq6tb//4eEZGRkZhYXKyhAyJSU/PzS0qSknJzUVAWF4uKCgtTUxMTsbEXFf/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

Loops to the end of the string as long as every even character (0th, 2nd, 4th, etc ...) is equal to the character after it, else stops the loop. Finally, checks if it has arrived at the end of the string, which means the string is a double speak.

---

Outputs 1 for double speak and nothing for not double speak.

Comment: Your first one is close, but it negates the resulting string. `"0"` is falsey in PHP, so an input of `"000"` will be deemed doublespeak

Comment: @aross: Thanks for pointing it out, yeah that `'0' == false` is always an issue. Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

## dzaima/APL, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```apl
⊢≡⊢⌿⍨2 0⍴⍨≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P@1R24RHXYsedS4EkT37H/WuMFIweNS7Bch41Lno/3/1kqLSVCt1rjQF9YyM1NQcIMjPV1TELpCYCKbUudTTEnOKMbVB@DhMQYikpaWBaKU0pX/5BSWZ@XnF/3WLAQ)

-3 thanks to Adám!

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>56</s> 52 bytes

```
{it.chunked(2).filter{it.toHashSet().size>1}.size<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNa8MwDIbv/RVq6cGGJdAdSxdo6WA7J39AqZVZ2LOD7YxtIb/dy8dp70ESL48@kPHJsstfaIHj3Q@tpbonNGcQdQrsPmRR3by3hA5e8sipfOjBGVLiWZYd20RhMZN/w6hrSkKWkX@pOk1rvpym3A0OPpGdwDNcQ8Cfyza5kjDCDmZh2fnwig/97hR9k5p9XqoniCsJRbVyi/rZSNaJQ0MxwXHloIDj@O98sTXK6SC3FdNuyrlptGaOEWCLSnk/DG1rLRFAjH1PhGjMfp8bzXH@CDif/gA)

Thank you Khuldraeseth na'Barya for saving 4 bytes

Comment: [Save a handful](https://tio.run/##VZBNa8MwDIbv/RVq6cGGJdAdSxdo6WA7J39AqZVZ2LOD7YxtIb/dy8dp70ESL48@kPHJsstfaIHj3Q@tpbonNGcQdQrsPmRR3by3hA5e8sipfOjBGVLiWZYd20RhMZN/w6hrSkKWkX@pOk1rvpym3A0OPpGdwDNcQ8Cfyza5kjDCDmZh2fnwig/97hR9k5p9XqoniCsJRbVyi/rZSNaJQ0MxwXHloIDj@O98sTXK6SC3FdNuyrlptGaOEWCLSnk/DG1rLRFAjH1PhGjMfp8bzXH@CDif/gA). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 31 bytes

```
a:qFb,#a{b%2?x(ab+1)Qa@b?xi:1}i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0arQLUlHObE6SdXIvkIjMUnbUDMw0SHJviLTyrA28///lJT8/NLSpKScnNRUBYXi4oKC1NTExOxsRUUA)

slightly different approach with fold operator, 31 bytes

```
a:qFb,#a{I!b%2i:$Q[a@b(ab+1)]}i
```

outputs 0 if double speak, 1 otherwise

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

Returns `0` if double-speak (or empty string), truthy otherwise.

```c
f(s,i)char*s;{for(i=*s;i&(i=*s++)&&i==*s++;);s=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBboMwEEX3nGJACsI2kQrqqha3yLIb29hghdjIA@0iytU7NWTz583ozzPXyRgi12DrmZlV4iifLqbGD5l8fU4hWF374STJJA5evsiHDR7Kh@YAlSbTwvEPnOflh8GzADhEErgQx0kCgzXltmuqC37BBb9D1cJZb6EKcYMx7nqxlShd87bwTyaLLEp221OAD1m8iLqu6/uebrd59h4R4J3jGOO@a70s1gIgrqu1St3vZUlKa0Uqp9ak6M@4RU1I199/)

If the input string is assumed to always be at least 2 characters (gives incorrect result for single-character strings):

### [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
f(char*s){while(*s&&*s++==*s++);s=*s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNboMwEITvPMWClMg/RCqop1p5ixxzsY0NKI6NvJAcorx6t6a5fLMzmh17Gq0l8sxOOgvkr@c0B8cEHo8CpTyfd3KFRdWb5rjCXc@R7YfOo21h/wMhinlweFUAPmWmQEi5Rwo4LLm0PWsO@AMHvMamhf96C01MKwxpM8E1svbssyK@uarKUHbrliN8qepN1HVd3/d0uUzTPCMCfDgMKW2bMSE4B4C4LM5pfbvVNWljNOlCY0jTr/VBj0in5x8)

Comment: The second suggestion seems to treat single character strings the same as any other odd length strings?

Comment: Wouldn't putting `s=i` at the end of `for` braces (`for(i=*s;i&(i=*s++)&&i==*s++;s=i)` save you one `;`?

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski `s=i` is used to return the value: it's not part of the loop. I'm using `i` to capture the character value, so assigning it to `s` during the loop would mess up the pointer (and likely crash the program!)

Comment: @ErikF my bad, I thought `s=i` is repeated in every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 64 bytes

```java
s->{int i=s.length;for(;i>1;)i=s[--i]==s[--i]?i:i|1;return i<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBi4MwEIXv/RWDIChowKvWlmXPCws9iodUo45rY8mMQun6292opdseksf7Msx7pJWjDNvyZy46SQRfEjXcdwDX4dxhAcSSrYw9lnCxb96JDeo6y0Gamvx1FKC1S8TA2Ilq0AVjr8W3USUWktW@aKTJ8gNUkM4UHu6oGTAl0Sldc5NUvfESPESJb2EWhpinDz1ijL9RYhQPRgPuo2SakzXvWYIVMUH6qAHgyLN0gn/z5qx9dW@WuWkQiV6JRZZZSM4Kpy18KTxKs2bHWwP/WeB0I1YX0Q8srrYjV57jUgwuudoJ1uEAKrGot1yC@0/7PR/GyJvn@/6WMO2WM81/)

## Explanations

```java
s->{
 int i=s.length;
 for(;i>1;)                 // while the length is 2 or greater.
  i=s[--i]==s[--i]?i:i|1;   // check the 2 previous values. If they're identical, don't do anything. Else, make i odd so that it fails at the return.
 return i<1;                // i will be 0 only when the size is even and all characters were doubled.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{!S:g/(.)$0//}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ox2CpdX0NPU8VAX7/2f1p@kUJOZl5qsZ2dXnFBTmaJhrqCroK6pkI1F2dxYqVCmoZetEGsJlft/8SkRKBMWmJOcSpXYhIyB8gDckqKSkFsCAciU1KSkZGZWVwMky0BCQBFgELFMEUA)

Replaces all pairs of identical characters with nothing and then boolean NOTs the result to return true if is an empty string (i.e. all characters were next to an identical one), or false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>51 50</s> 38 bytes

```
echo preg_match("/^((.)\2)+$/",$argn);
```

Checks whether input matches pairs of chars where the chars in each pair are the same (using back ref).

Run like this:

```
echo 'dd00uubbllee' | php -nR 'echo preg_match("/^((.)\\2)+$/",$argn);';echo
```

- -1 byte thanks to @manatwork
- -12 bytes by using preg_match with back references.

Comment: Wouldn't `/.(.?)/` be enough to handle odd length strings?

Comment: @manatwork you're right, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 13 bytes

```
LL2%}2/:=};P#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/Hx0i11kjfyrbWOkD5////SiEhGRmZmcXFCgoQMiUlP7@0NCkpJyc1VUGhuLigIDU1MTE7W1FRCQA)

```
L              \ Push len(input)
 L2%           \ Take (len(input) + 1) % 2. This will be 1 only if the input had even length.
    }          \ Move this to the bottom of the stack for later.
     2/:  ;    \ Length of original input, divided by 2, times do:
        =      \    Pop top two characters, and check equality. (Pushes 0 or 1)
         }     \    Move this to the bottom of the stack for later.
           P   \ Push the stack's product. If the input had odd length, or any two characters
               \ did not match, then the stack will contain a 0, so the product will be 0.
               \ Else, it will be 1.
            #  \ Print the product.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 50 bytes

```
2a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e2x2v1r3x2v1e0m1o0x1x2f0m1a1o0x1f
```

Works for any input string, provided it's passed as a file terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with 0x commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                       # Set variable 1 equal to 2
1x1f1r3x1v2e                 # Function 1
                             # Read a byte and jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
            2x2v             # Otherwise, store it in variable 2
                1r3x2v1e     # Read another byte
                             # Jump back to the start of function 1 if it equals variable 2
                        0m1o # Otherwise, output 0
1x2f0m1a1o                   # Function 2
                             # Output 1
1f                           # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 8 bytes

```
J2en)J==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fyyg1T9PL1vb//8TEpKTkZAA)

```
                           [AABBCC]         [ABC]
J   #Duplicate             [AABBCC,AABBCC]  [ABC,ABC]
2en #Every other character [AABBCC,ABC]     [ABC,AC]
)J  #Duplicated            [AABBCC,AABBCC]  [ABC,AACC]
==  #Is the same           [1]              [0]
```

## Burlesque, 11 bytes

```
=[{L[2dv}al
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fNrraJ9oopaw2Mef//8SkpEQA)

```
=[   # Group consecutive like values
{
 L[  # Length of (group)
 2dv # Divisible by 2
}al  # All
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md), 84 bytes

No output for false, output one `\u0000` for true using this [standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17938/86978) rule

```
@0@1
0000
]]]]&101
eqal\\&1
@0@1..=0\/
:eqal
@0..@1
}0..}1
--..--
<1&0<1&0
{0@0{1@1
```

[interpretor](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 23 bytes

```javascript
z=>/^((.)\2)+$/.test(z)
```

Uses a regular expression that match two of the same characters one or more times

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxv8rWTj9OQ0NPM8ZIU1tFX68ktbhEo0rzv2ZCYmKCpvV/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 5 bytes

```
0?/20_?:?
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwPy8yMF8_Oj8iLCJbXCJ0dGhoaWlzc1wiXSIsMF0)

Doesn't work with the empty string; OP hasn't clarified if that's a problem.

### Explanation

```
0   transpose
?       input
/     split into groups of
2       2
0 reduce
_
?       accumulator
:     =
?       item
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP4 (45 chars)

Given *$argv[1]* as a command line argument :

```php
echo preg_match('#^((.)\2)*$#',$argv[1])?1:0;
```

The script will output `0` or `1` to answer.

### PHP7.4 (41 chars)

The **$f** arrow function will return the answer :

```php
$f=fn($s)=>preg_match('#^((.)\2)*$#',$s);
```

### C gcc (27 chars)

Function **f** today return an indication of whether or not the input is double speak :

```c
f(char*s){1[s]-*s||f(s+2);}
```

Usage :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("EXPECT %5s ... %-5s .. aba\n","NO", f("aba")?"NO":"YES");
    printf("EXPECT %5s ... %-5s .. abba\n","NO", f("abba")?"NO":"YES");
    printf("EXPECT %5s ... %-5s .. aabb\n","YES", f("aabb")?"NO":"YES");
    printf("EXPECT %5s ... %-5s .. aaabb\n","NO", f("aaabb")?"NO":"YES");
    printf("EXPECT %5s ... %-5s .. tthhiiss\n","YES", f("tthhiiss")?"NO":"YES");
    printf("EXPECT %5s ... %-5s .. ttthhhiiisss\n","NO", f("ttthhhiiisss")?"NO":"YES");
}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##nY5NC4JAEIbv/ophQ9g1FQq6ZNQhvFZQh6I62Jq5UFs4dlJ/u42G0cclnNPOu/M8vNI5SVmWEZdxkFgost4W946FeR5x7PaFV5QdpeX5Hh5hhGmorm48NgylU7gESnMBmQE0t4SiiDN/vfCnKzAHCK7rgunUDwgOwU4zm83mzAY6o52JSbUO2cZfMuH9Z/nRtPMQV3sq5CmipJWoMb0atTSlaRwrhfhZq0lbCYklmGj8aPj@8e0tygc)

**C Variants** :

```c
g(char*s){s=*s&&g(s+2)+s[1]-*s;} // 32 chars
h(char*s){return*s&&h(s+2)+s[1]-*s;} // 36 chars
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22 bytes

```
l2%?v>l?v1n;
 ;n0<^?=<
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoibDIlP3Y+bD92MW47XG4gO24wPF4/PTwiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiYWFiYmNjIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Answer (score 2):

### X86_64/Linux Machine Code, 19-Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJNa9tAED1rf8UEJ5CYyBGmhDTgQ9OEYgjpwS6ll5r9GEmLV1qhWdVyf3zU0UdsqA6jnX0z8@bNrCTCQrljnGnddXdz@FFqXxRYBlDo/AFsCk@bDRwkAWFoKpABlr@XyQJgfic4YWYwtSXC@vnly@uuj@X7aJE5r6SLdhRkHdgP2AYxeo8i4rx1T2TLDGrMLAWsCWSN8BdrP9YWkUHtois0rZjZlGnOHCJSgUbsFq6QrJihIxRR4f@46PLbrsDiBJTGpgMlyhZWK0h6s/m12dUozcg1oMae0e3z@m2C6EhaOieiVudZzykHTt0K5301inn10kDJEqGStp4SnTd0GOA3RAPBAwuqQR1hya3oHPr8KXaSykX7@K856j2EnGetjgEJChl0PoW2vlbRlcy5CemG8CcWsu83xWvwNbBg8Clo35Th1IqvcLDipNXSMGy41g4lTz@3oGygPpUl3iyGcX0EcXHjG@UwFhEAUMWMC/gecqwPlhBKX8bn1f03KmMH0pfWfvTDa1LR5X0yaTiNeEGog/UlLBSRGNb4yJeV1Hj9Kfl8D3N4uBFdt93mubVEAKM1xvumUco5RO6OqgpRyv3@4uJdp05m1MWlp2CcVf2J35JsXGBvAvhVptYhe3wOVvO/i3@623jLfayS9iEZv38)

**Usage:**

```
$> gcc -Wl,-Tbss=0x80000000 -DIDEAL_BSS -s -static -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none double-speak.S -o double-speak
$> echo -n "<input> | ./double-speak; echo $?
```

Program reads input from stdin (it is sensitive to the exact byte count of input, i.e stray spaces/new lines will change result).

**Returns 0 for double-speak, and non-zero otherwise.**

**Notes:**

- Size is measured in machine code (i.e 19 bytes of PROGBITS; .text, .data, etc...)
- The 19-byte size assumes the above compile command which sets the BSS address at an ideal value. With generic compile commands (no linker inputs), its 21-bytes.

**Program:**

```
/* Uncomment below if BSS was setup at 2^20.  */
/* #define IDEAL_BSS */
    .global _start
    .text
_start:
    /* Incoming registers are zero.  */

    decl    %edx
#ifdef IDEAL_BSS
    btsl    %edx, %esi
#else
    movl    $G_mem, %esi
#endif
    /* eax == 0 == SYS_read.  */
    /* edi == 0 == STDIN.  */
    syscall
    xchgl   %eax, %ecx
loop:
    /* Load next pair.  */
    lodsw
    /* Need to decr by 2 each loop.  */
    decl    %ecx
    /* Check that bytes match.  */
    xorb    %ah, %al
    /* Break if ne or end of count.  */
    loope   loop

    /* edi is zero (clears hi bits of eax). eax is zero if double-
       speak. Otherwise non-zero.  */
    xchgl   %eax, %edi
    /* Exit.  */
    movb    $60, %al
    syscall
    .section .bss
G_mem:  .space(4096 * 8)
```

**Example/Test:**

```
$> for x in aba abba aabb aaabb tthhiiss ttthhhiiisss; do echo -n "${x}" | ./double-speak; echo "${x} -> $?"; done
aba -> 3
abba -> 3
aabb -> 0
aaabb -> 3
tthhiiss -> 0
ttthhhiiisss -> 28
```

Answer (score 2):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s Type System, 86 bytes

```typescript
type F<S>=S extends`${infer C}${infer D}${infer R}`?C extends D?F<R>:0:S extends""?1:0
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAZQHwF4FQgD2BAdgEwGcADAEgG8BLXAMwgCcoBhAXwursYBE2raGoAJRbEA-EwzY8RKF1HxBSAFwAGJeiw4ChAEQ7RARlUAoY6EhQAKhELAVUFLDg7LlgBZvKlQoShQvPn74+AD2IQCu4QBGUQA2sRDQUD5gkBAAhukA1lkAhLk6SMYA9MV+UAB6oqbm0Na2Bg5OOulR6YUlZX5VNeB1NsAATE3wLTHtRaXlPWZ9VgMAzCPOmTEdU93Vsxb1wAAsyy2rUetdlVu187YArIfAwB4BupNnM5e7AGx39x6eT8+daYXOa7ADsh1Wp3K52MQA)

This is a generic type `F` taking a string-literal type parameter `S`, and outputting `0` for non-double-speak and `1` for double-speak.

None of the test cases offer a case where all of the pairs are equal but the whole string is of odd length, which tripped me up a bit. This is likely golfable, maybe that last `extends` clause can be dropped with something clever.

Explanation:

```typescript
type F<S> = 
  // Match S to extract the first two chars C and D and the rest R
  S extends `${infer C}${infer D}${infer R}`
  // if it matched: is C the same type as D?
  ? C extends D
    ? F<R> // if so, recurse with R
    : 0 // otherwise, it's not double-speak; return 0
  // if it didn't match, we check if the string is empty or has one character.
  : S extends "" ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 26 bytes

```javascript
f=([a,b,...c])=>a==b&&f(c)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RVCxTsMwFBRrRr7gNUNlq4nVbpWiZIONqd2AwUmeE6uuHWJHoqr6JSwd4Cf4E_gaXpoCg8_n0929J7-9W1fj-fwxBJWuP1XOHmVSJkKI6pnnhczzcj5XrOKT4fvmtnLWBzDaooccenwZdI8sVj7mokdZ32uDm4Ot2DKBmEJr0kOv94wL3xkdWPxkY55F1x5nG6Q7hwcZWrGXr4xmX9rp0TGaUYAXBm0TWk6xSLke2P8S4NS0DIdjBGAw0E5-MGPlMiMl9Ac4gmKjiWdwgkqGqiXpz7YilYxjpzMojGsuZtHJ-s7W7HfFBaw4QQxpQbC45nl0mr7m_LXZbttWa-8BJqxr54ahLI1BTFPvuw5Ryt1uNotkKemMIOkiLKMQpjQRYkSJ-6n7Bw)

Outputs via exit-code. I think this is really nice and clean but that's just my opinion. Unfortunately, this doesn't beat the tried-and-true regex.

Explanation:

- `f=([a,b,...c])=>...`

  Makes a function `f` that destructures its string argument into the first
  character `a`, the second character `b`, and rest of the string `c`.
- `a==b&&f(c)`

  Check if `a` is equal to `b`. The `&&` (AND) operator only evaluates its
  right argument if its left is true, so if it is true we recurse with `c`.

  If `a` and `b` aren't equal, then it can't be double speak, so we stop
  recursion to output with a 0 exit code.

  If they're equal, we keep checking the next two until either

  - A) recursion stops because `a` isn't equal to `b`, or
  - B) `a` and `b` are both `undefined` because we've reached the end of the string and there are no more characters left, so we recurse until the recursion depth is hit, giving an exit code of 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
{s->(0..s.length-1 step 2).fold(""){t,c->t+s[c]+s[c]}==s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVCxasMwEN3zFReTQaKRaTuG2tCQDp3jrXSQrUssrErCJ5cWo29XZXvqGx7H49173A0uGG3TtzSg6eKm1uDVoxxOwK5h1PbORX12zqC0UKWZRM0ey5JKg/YeevEEFNDDMy9vzihWFHwOx07U4YE@us@VYlVRTLfJwpfUlskTvI6j/H3Z4msOM@wgQ@aI8U12/btV@IMq63qZjrlicYKoV98Cn4VgLCsapACH1QcCDvO/G9i2yGPBt4q4iyk1Td9rTQSwsVLOTVPbGoMIQOQ9opTDsN@npteU3wLWhT8)

-1 byte thanks to Khuldraeseth na'Barya

-1 byte changing it -> s

---

Slightly lazy attempt - basically just took my answer from the doublespeak question, applied it to every second char of the input and see if the result is the input.

Comment: [Save a byte](https://tio.run/##VVCxTsMwEN37Fdeogy3qCBgrEgkEA3OzIQYnvtanGNuKHQSK8u3GqSfe8HR6evee7kYXDdn0LQ1QeHVzb/DsUY4nYOc4kb1y0b44Z1BaaNLC7uuaYm3QXqMWDxAienjk9cUZxaqKL@E4iDbcUfwYPguvTUNxTZfZwpcky@QJnqdJ/j6V/JbDAjvIkDllepODfrcKf1BlnbbpmFs2J4j25tvgsxCNZVWHIcLh5gMBh@XfEaws8rXipWLdrSl1ndZEIQAUVsq5ee57YxABQvAeUcpx3O9Tpynkv4B18Q8)

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya updated, thanks! did not know that was a thing

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -n, <s>21</s> 14+1 = 15 bytes

```ruby
p~/^((.)\2)*$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BOP05DQ08zxkhTS0X///@QkIyMzMziYgUFCJmSkp9fWpqUlJOTmqqgUFxcUJCampiYna2oyBWSkVmskFmcp17yL7@gJDM/r/i/bh4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>90</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 82 bytes

```lua
a,e=1,os.exit;(...):gsub('.',load's=...a=a~=1 and(a==s and 1 or e(1))or s')e(a==1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoRADEDRq8TKCQxC2oXpvIVYZNasCMMEjIGt9upxrf6D35wjOEuhrDbJ97iAz32h9bWb1zROY/54f1@H9mTIhX@FgPuWuBR7AAR6giRC/NdA@obyXMKImGdV91pbExmGGw)

Take input as argument, use exit code as output.

### Explanation

This is based on abusing few Lua features:

- `os.exit` could accept either number, allowing short code for exit or boolean, making last check possible (`true` meaning success, `false` meaning failure).
- `gsub` can be also used to iterate over string in callback-style, not only for doing replacement.
- `load` is shorter than `function(...) end`.
- `...` is often shorter than `arg[1]`.

Whole idea hidden behind those tricks:

1. For each character: either remember if nothing is already it or perform check: if current is different from remembered, fail. Otherwise, reset remembered value and continue.
2. When done, make sure that there's nothing pending in the buffer (`e(a==1)`). This is required to fail on strings with odd length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 17 characters

```
?$1=
?=0@end
\Z=1
```

Outputs 1 on double speak and 0 on not.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n 'TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!' | gema '?$1=;?=0@end;\Z=1'
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/317F0JbL3tbAITUvhSsmytbw//@QkIyMzMziYgUFCJmSkp9fWpqUlJOTmqqgUFxcUJCampiYna2oCAA)

### Gema, 12 characters

```
?$1=
?=@fail
```

Terminates with exit code 0 on double speak and 2 on not.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n 'TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!' | gema '?$1=;?=@fail'
bash-5.0$ echo $?
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/317F0JbL3tYhLTEz5///kJCMjMzM4mIFBQiZkpKfX1qalJSTk5qqoFBcXFCQmpqYmJ2tqAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), <strike>59</strike> <strike>55</strike> 50 bytes

```c
f(char *s){while(*s==*++s)s++;return!*--s&&s!="";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LDoIwFET3fMVtjaYPMe4rfgVLN6UtaQMW0kvjgvDtFUPiLE4mZzFj6sWYcgrRjNk6eOBiw3Tzz9Iz43UCgXz9@DA6JrBphJTIUUqV3JJTJKKu8XJB0lCqthLiAm8dIuPVCnuqH@a0657Rs4VXpNe9ta33ISACHLR2mnLuunF0DgBxnp3TehgIoZyr/9BxCXdVbeUL)

Thanks to Jo King for the 4 bytes and Unrelated String for saving 5 bytes

Can it be even shorter?

Comment: *s==*++s, how is this not UB when *s points to the end of the string?

Comment: the *s will always point to the last character of the string given in argument which is not last character because string here ends with '\0' so the *++s gets the \0

Comment: You increment s by two each time through the loop, so if there is an even number of actuall characters in the string I do not see how you can guarantee that *s never points to the '\0'

Comment: You could golf it considerably by replacing `*--s=='\0'` with the simple `!*--s`, but also  note that most challenges require submissions to be either functions or full programs, and this is neither.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping shortening it and @Taemyr play with this code [TIO](https://tio.run/##TZDBbsIwEETP5CtGqaqGpC3cU3oLR46cuBjHEKthN/I6jSrEt6eOqUos@bKjfTOz@s1rPY5PlnTb1wYf4mvL781nknyzrXFRlrJlck0Qnm6UQy6btKr2@6ra7dIyzofGtiYLwiYvClnG2TX8zlnypyzdWif@vr0FFNWQzbM@UPqay7IEViv4xkBzCDAwvXgcDVxvydToqTUi@OEeXe9hPZT8gw/rGWawvomcwzpZSFGUi8UUJMDDYjTXiqBa4QnfS4AfJyJqJo8v4iEUMc5MHmcOPoQ2hlbaGwdLEJwcX2I9zOrNy0TxlszllrmDCaUfxaeL6QY2AB@n4VNMLz7snSe7O@CPexvHXw) I don't need to care if *s gets the \0 character cause then the *++s will get the first character from the string used in printf.

Comment: Although I don't know exactly how that works(if someone could explain thanks) and I tried it with putchar too changing printf to putchar also gives the *++s some character value.

Comment: @Loki I see no printf in your code.  In the TIO you get the first char of whatever the compiler puts after the string you are looking at, so you are in UB.

Comment: https://tio.run/##XY7NDoIwEITvPMW2BtIfMZ6t9exDcMECoQlW05Z4IDx7LVoMMdm9fDOZGVV6pcJOGzWMTQtn5xv9OPSX0BHV1xaYo9Or10NLmJOSce6o41w8rTa@IzhvIFeVwXvm4lERKViJWFm6onBIYry1fo30H318P7rRo0iFbf1oDVgxhyX9XmtDaDYBQBYf0kqJEcJiQ24SV0dj6gTXyKuGE6TepYsKWJNS0VFkc3gD

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 46<s>49</s> bytes

-3 bytes thanks to `@cubic lettuce`

```
{it.chunked(2).all{it.length>1&&it[0]==it[1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsIwEEXX7VcMpZRkYbEuiy3oL7iULqbv0DjRmAoS8u2xUVcHzj3cRRkpyL9QgimBXYwWNPFdfVZKDkhQeStM3s0rLUPPDjxHKYORA01mrossE@a6b6pqQ9E458eV4IaCGOrpWcJJa3wff7c1BxtHo9IQRhAEofnK6L4FRhJLUrtJV0JqTai4S3gcudh5j9i2Xff4s@8/)

```
{it.length%2==0&&it.chunked(2).all{it[0]==it[1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLDoIwFETX8BU3BEm7kCBLYkn0F1waFuXdUG@1FhPT9NtrUVeTOXMyizJSoH9xCaYCcjFa4ET39VkpOXAE5q0wuRxwMvOuZKzIstC7ecVl6ElJcy5lMK5Fw1iIQ@OcH1eEGxdIuJ6eFZy05u/j77mmYONoVBq2EQTC5nxhdA@CkUiS1AboKkit2SzqEhpHLnbec962Xff4Z99/AA)

Comment: Save 3 bytes by `{it.chunked(2).all{it.length>1&&it[0]==it[1]}}` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL 2012, 76 bytes

Looping using the following logic.

> Finding the first match on the first character in the rest of the string.
>
> If the match is on the second position, the first 2 characters are removed.
>
> if the match is on a later position, character 0 to 1 is removed, resulting in null string.
>
> If there are no matches, characters 3-4 are removed. Repeating this will eventually result in a null string.

The final string will be an empty string or a null string.

Empty string is "double speak"(1).
Null string is not "double speak"(0).

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='ccbbddeeff'

WHILE @>''SET
@=stuff(@,-3/~charindex(left(@,1),@,2),2,'')PRINT
iif(@=0,1,0)
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CVLJT75984)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|!s.chars().enumerate().any(|(i,c)|s.chars().nth(i|1).unwrap()!=c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcpBCoMwEEDRvaeIWcgMiNBti4eZhkgCOkhmpBTj2WOgi6509@H9tImWic1CkQH3ZvZqJjOakuXZiabcyuACJQEcPG@LT6S@NvEXMsTeYf4PrAFifuCw8SfRCtiODsurWVNknbkFux@2NxN0lt5kES/oxipe2w2qhhCjyLXXoR51@T1HOQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 43 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*
*-2 bytes thanks to @JoKing*

recursive function assuming zero terminated char table

```cpp
int f(char*s){return!*s||*s==s[1]&&f(s+2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/NDoIwEAbvPEXBhLQYE/Va8EWMh7Uu0qQ/pFtOwLMjSOKB4HedyWRXte3prdR00E6Z7oWlAiIM8TZpF1nNVQOhINEHjF1waUHDUFBV0f3yyPOa0/Eq5Ph1LWjHBesTNm@N8JpnTYNojPeMWQsQI2KaZkLIjQbwnLcFzi83rPAP2/T38vvmov7M9T12lsk4fQA)

Comment: @ceilingcat cool, I didn't now you can be __that__ concise

Comment: @JoKing it works, there's just a warning because I'm using string literals to generate right kind of input - zero-terminated `char*` - which is not exactly legal in c++ but gcc allows it

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought the lack of output meant it wasn't working. [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY/NDoIwEAbvPEXBhLQYE/Va8EWMh7Uu0qQ/pFtOwLMjSOKB4HedyWRXte3prdR00E6Z7oWlAiIM8TZpF1nNVQOhINEHjF1waUHDUFBV0f3yyPOa0/Eq5Ph1LWjHBesTNm@N8JpnTYNojPeMWQsQI2KaZkLIjQbwnLcFzi83rPAP2/T38vvmov7M9T12lsk4fQA)

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

This solution is totally broken as demonstrated by the `aabbbb` test case. Thanks to @manatwork for pointing this out. Do not pass Go! Do not collect 200 dollars!

### Bash and Gnu utils, <strike>46</strike> <strike>45 bytes</strike>

```
fold -1|uniq -c|grep -qv "2 "&&echo 0||echo 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0/J0VB17CmNC@zUEE3uSa9KLVAQbewTEHJSEFJTS01OSNfwaCmBkwb/v8fEpKRkWmUWVwMAA)

-1 byte by skipping the first space in grep expression

Comment: Not sure if I can use `grep` exit codes and return output there?
Instead of this `&&echo 0||echo1`

Comment: This works fine on the question's test cases, but as I understand the challenge, it should output 1 on [Khuldraeseth na'Barya](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/khuldraeseth-nabarya)'s [suggested test case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak/189555#comment453441_189358), “aabbbb”.

Comment: @manatwork You're right. This solution is buggy in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 26 bytes

```javascript
s=>!s.replace(/(.)\1/g,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxDoMwDEDRnVMkLCRSG8QB4BSMLE5iIGDhCBeuHyp16/KHJ/0NbpBwpvx5HxyxzH2RftDiTswEAU1rnJ26dnk1jS2BD2FCR7yY2dTjuK4piSj1a4zM1@U9EaJSIjkjAuy71rW11d8M3sOXywM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 39 bytes

```rust
|s:&[u8]|s.chunks(2).all(|n|n[0]==n[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcyxDoIwEAbg3ac4Opg2MUSdjIa3YCMMrZTQUA/CtRPl2WvFvdxwy//9/@LJxR7hIw1yAesJ0lntoIcKYqDnufGPNlD5HjyOxO@ilNbygAGba1tV2NxaEX@l116dF4POYsHZurEL9FwxqSQTIhMf5Ank8wPg3DAYQ5Q3CSWVWNbV9X8L4P@7bpq8V8parQGI5llrKcexKPaVLX4B)

This is a closure that takes the input as a byte slice (`b` prefix on a string), e.g.

```rust
println!("{}", f(b"aabb"));
```

Comment: Does not work for b"aab", unless the panic is intended.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>156</strike> 145 bytes

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int f(){
    char a[2]; while(std::cin.get(a, 3)) if(a[0] != a[1]) return 0; return 1;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << f();
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDoIwGIT3PsVPXNpEDegG6FOwEYbS/sAfoTS0jYPx2WuVeMPlhrvvlLWnUakYD2TUHDRCTavzG8rlzsh4GLh4MUhSk9xAtpeugudEM3LndVkqMucRPZdHuAoBNHDZ5h1kt1QtOgEb@rAZyKt/Kir2/oEXSYYLtsN31ho81PX3MpVibJppInIOYHet1zWEvp9nxDRx1iJK@Xhk2Qc)

Comment: Welcome to the site! C++ is pretty lenient about whitespace so you can save bytes by removing a bunch of it.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 47 bytes

```
select*from t where regexp_like(x,'^((.)\2)+$')
```

It works with an assumption that input data is stored in a table t(x), e.g.

```
with t(x) as (select 'hheelllloo' from dual)
```

Returns either original string or no rows.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 109 bytes

```swift
func a(b:String){let c=Array(b),l=c.count;var d=0,i=0;while i<l-1{if c[i]==c[i+1]{d+=1};i+=2;};print(d*2==l)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxDsIgEADQX2EEqaY0TuINfoOj6UCh6CUXavBqYwjfjl3e@D4bRj63FtfkhZPT5c4Z01MVmll4uOXsfnJSHYE/@WVNbL8uiwB9h9Db7YU0C7zS0RSMwj9wBNjVZixBg6kWNQy22veesgyHAYBUbe0P)

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 190 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(string[]a){bool d=true;if(a[0].Length%(double)2>0)d=false;else for(int i=0;i<a[0].Length;i+=2){d=a[0][i]==a[0][i+1]?d:false;}System.Console.Write(d);}}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZTjv6D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 48 bytes

```clj
(fn[x](every? #(apply = %)(partition 2 2[\0]x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclBDkUwEADQvVNMiGRmJ/biIFj008ZIU02NH05ftdbte7PdtzPoiIs2YCIaN1wT6r8Odw8VKu/tDR3UhF4FYeHdQQvtMDbTRUSRCvSBnVgHaKBUP1XSx3KYNIM5FVlX5uPIRJpU6d6MDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
2/zip~=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30i/KrOgzvb//5KSjIzMzGIA)

## Explanation

````
2/      # Split input into parts of 2,            e.g. tt,ee,ss,tt
  zip   # Read the list horizontally,         yielding test, test
     ~  # Put the two strings onto the stack, yielding test,test
      = # Check whether they are equal,       yielding 1

# False case:
#  tteesst
#->tt,ee,ss,t
#->test,tes
#->0
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pF/^((.)\2)+$/`, 7 bytes

Outputs `0` for falsy and `2` for truthy.

```perl
$_=@F^1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbBLc7w///EpESuxCQQASSBBIgsKcnIyMwsLgYygCwgE8gu/pdfUJKZn1f8X7cgx00/TkNDTzPGSFNbRR8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>108</s> <s>97</s> <s>88</s> 69 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
D's 1
while D and S
let D be roll S's roll S

say D
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

```
listen to S       :Read input string into variable S
cut S             :Split into an array
D's 1             :Initialise D as 1
while D and S     :While D is truthy and S is not empty
let D be          :  Reassign to D
  roll S          :    Pop the first element from S
  's              :    Check equality with
  roll S          :    Pop the first element from S
                  :End while loop
say D             :Output D
```

Comment: I quite like the output of 'mysterious' if it's false.

Comment: Odd, @AJFaraday, could've sworn I has it outputting `0` for falsey. Must've changed something before posting without realising. Anyway, long's you're OK with that, I'll leave it as-is. Could save some more by looping forever with no output if the result is truthy but that would probably be pushing things!

Answer (score 1):

## SM83, 7 bytes

Input in `hl`. Output is in `z` flag. All other flags are off.

```
2A B7 C8 BE 23 28 F9 C9
```

```
isdbl:
 ld a,(hl+)                 // 2A       load first byte and inc
 or a                       // B7       test if zero
 ret z                      // C8       return if at end (with z on)
 xor (hl)                   // BE       test sameness
 inc hl                     // 23       inc again (does not change flags)
 jr z,isdbl                 // 28 F9    loop if same
 ret                        // C9       else return
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 69 bytes

a solution which would put myself between [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231328/64499) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189712/64499).

EDIT: you, people, are soooo clever. I love yall

```
[](string a){int c=0,d=1,k;for(int i:a)k=c++%2?d*=k==i,k:i;return d;}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat if you mean the one in the ranged for statement, I believe I cannot as the following if-else statement is not reducible to a single semicolon.

Comment: @ceilingcat thank you, that works!

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##PctBqgIxEATQfU7RKh8SVPC7NBNP4U5ctEmrTWaSMJ2sxLOPI4KbKnhU@VK2d@@nFSfft0AdZ6kj4XBUP5qB0/2omswFCQeSgp5AarCKU4UBOWnzVNhqBnTT@aK/H0Dz/Ay8222C@99Ee8uj/ggf0PBNr9f@b2@iY0u9EMwSt2yC29mRahsTBPuarPK51a5DvTydHg9mEYBvhpBza9dr3xMBiJRChBjjYrE0Vr2mNw) by using a single `return`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
q{Q.-Q{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7A6UE83sPr/f6WSkoyMzMziYqV/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)