# Is this n-speak?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

Inspired by [Is it double speak?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak/), I devised a harder challenge. Given a string, determine if the string is *n-speak*, for any \$n\geq 2\$.

N-speak is defined by repeating each letter \$n\$ times. With \$n = 4\$, the string `Hello` is transformed to `HHHHeeeelllllllloooo`. Your goal is to figure out if the input is a valid output for any n-speak transformation.

It should be noted that any sentence which is valid n-speak, for \$n = 2k\$, is also valid k-speak. Thus, the hard parts to solve will be odd values of \$n\$.

### Input

A string consisting of at least 2 characters. Input could also be a list of characters. Input is case sensitive.

### Output

`Truthy` if the string is n-speak, `falsey` otherwise.

### Examples

#### True cases

```
HHeelllloo,,  wwoorrlldd!!
TTTrrriiipppllleee   ssspppeeeaaakkk
QQQQuuuuaaaaddddrrrruuuupppplllleeee    ssssppppeeeeaaaakkkk
7777777-------ssssssspppppppeeeeeeeaaaaaaakkkkkkk
999999999
aaaabb
aaaaaaaabbbbcc
aaaaabbbbb
@@@
```

If you want to generate additional truthy cases, you can use [this MathGolf script](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18pPL9coSQjs1gBiBIVcvLz0hWKU/NKUvOSU5VyDy/L1jjcEv//v5EBAA). Place the string within the quotation marks, and the value of \$n\$ as the input.

#### False cases

```
Hello, world!
TTTrrriiipppllleee   speak
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
Ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk
aabbab
aaaabbb
a (does not need to be handled)
(empty string, does not need to be handled)
```

Of course, since this is code golf, get ready to trim some bytes!

Comment: Suggested test case: `aabbab`

Comment: Suggested test case: `aaaabbb`

Comment: I'll add them both tomorrow, good suggestions.

Comment: I am genuinely honoured and flattered that you have used and expanded my challenge :)

Comment: @AJFaraday glad that you liked it! I enjoyed both of your challenges, which gave me the idea for this one. There might be an even harder challenge coming soon.

Comment: @maxb by all means. Although I find that relatively simple challenges often get more response. Just think to yourself "If I saw this, would I automatically start thinking about how to code it". Those are the winners :)

Comment: When is someone going to post "n-speak"? ;)

Comment: _"It should be noted that any sentence which is valid n-speak, for n=2k, is also valid k-speak. Thus, the hard parts to solve will be odd values of n."_ This is an interesting claim since your examples are $n=2$ and $n=4$ which can't be reduced to odd values.

Comment: @JiK the 2nd, 4th, 5th, and 9th test cases are all odd numbered. It was mostly an observation that for every even case, a solution to the original **Is is double speak?** challenge would also would also be correct.

Answer (score 16):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Runs with `⎕io←0`

```apl
1≠∨/⍸2≠/∊0⍞0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@9TsMwEID3PIU7ZUnVwIJgRqgrUl7gHF9RZEtn2YqivgBNkYpYWBEjj8Dz@EXCnY4iGPim@/vsO4hh7fYQ6GEpz68DlceXtirzYbdclON7mT825fR5yeGmzE9tOb21C3eXuksjmh4y5pu62lXbLWJgiJrGmGkiSikE51YrbnZdl1IahiHGyDOIaIzJOXPKMQB473nsnhkZLoBj2EmSR9XEE1FMUcUVWWzRr5S1kpWooAKKV9i5PsOxdKz9DjSxtu/PBclsVd9ByH8O57OpMROl4P6/NSL4Xy///MC1W0c0jtbKrNwmy8qKMv4F)

Golfed together with [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m).

On the input (example: `"aaccccaaaaaabb"`, using `""` to denote a string (an array of chars) and `''` to denote a char)

`∊0⍞0` surround with 0s and flatten, `0 'a' 'a' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 0`

`2≠/` perform pairwise not-equal, `1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1`

`⍸` get the 0-indexed indices, `0 2 6 12 14`

`∨/` compute the GCD, `2`

`1≠` is this not equal to 1?

Answer (score 10):

## Java 10, 85 bytes

```java
s->{var r=0>1;for(int i=0;++i<s.length();)r|=s.matches("((.)\\2{"+i+"})*");return r;}
```

Regex ported from [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189782/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVJNT@MwEL33Vww@JaQNH5fVEsppteICEqI32MMkMdTEtS3baVWV/vYyjtNqU3rgHazMPM@b8ct84BInH3WzqyQ6Bw8o1GYEIJTn9g0rDo8hBCi1lhwVVMmzt0K9g0sLIrYjOpxHLyp4BAVT2LnJ3WaJFuz08u6qeNM2ITEQ08siy8StyyVX736epEVqP6cuX6Cv5twlLEny9PX1esMykbFtes7SwnLfWgW22O6K0Mi0paRGfb@lFjUsaOB@pJd/gGmc9uICZrb183UXee58wu7vOZcErcdjgNVKa2ulrOuzM9Y9ZX9vNptZa4UQxhi6zjknyjlHIX0jYtM0w4onQksgDmsCldsQm6gQJIJGEAkqQSboBKEjpV8RkwgXYSJ4BEY0EcPy33sM0@F@WX7PxXxZVtUJLhCHmue183yR69bnhqz2UtH/G@2t/ovS8fXN/16T03oMK21l/SN7Dcfm9ICHQYf0n1rrti3LoBCcDf4EV45EhiH7trPdDnVkv9ZCmdb3W3Ti1R2dsRtgmcqrGKa96nb3BQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                          // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  var r=0>1;                  //  Result-boolean, starting at false
  for(int i=0;++i<s.length();)//  Loop `i` in the range [1, input-length):
    r|=                       //   Change the result to true if:
      s.matches("((.)\\2{"+i+"})*");
                              //    The input-String matches this regex
                              // NOTE: String#matches implicitly adds a leading ^ and 
                              //       trailing $ to match the full String
  return r;}                  // After the loop, return the result-boolean
```

*Regex explanation:*

```java
^((.)\2{i})*$                 // Full regex to match, where `i` is the loop-integer
^           $                 // If the full String matches:
  (.)                         //  A character
     \2{i}                    //  Appended with that same character `i` amount of times
 (        )*                  //  And that repeated zero or more times for the entire string
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Œɠg/’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJML0vUfNcz8//9/SEhIUVFRZmZmQUFBTk5OamqqgoJCcUFqYjYA)

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
γ€g¿≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZHTWvSD@1/1Lng//@QkJCioqLMzMyCgoKcnJzU1FQFBYXigtTEbAA)

Comment: I thought my 14-byter in MathGolf was a good one, but you just crushed it. I'd love an explanation both for this and your Jelly answer.

Comment: @maxb It really just takes the lengths of the group runs, calculates their GCD and tests if it's not 1.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Derived from the regular expression used by @wastl in [*Is it double speak?*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189379/58563).

```javascript
s=>[...s].some((_,n)=>s.match(`^((.)\\2{${++n}})*$`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFBT8MgFMfvfgqWLCm4joMX46E7GbOrSW/tdFCY1rI@Aqs9LPvslSfRaGSLvxPwf@8XeLyJd@Eb19rDsgelp10x@WJVcc79hnvYa0qf854VK8/34tC80u0TpZzV9c1xflws@tOJXc@3jE0N9B6M5gZeaFaVbtCbjF39PN3RbL3W2gQA8pyQcQRwzhilZrOM/Skuy9I517attTb0aK0JId77sA1rIUTXdYm2x8AQCAVCBYLD4d5GDXpQhCZUoQtlaEvpbiPLiI/YiI6ISBdJOO6@SGTYKeWZIIZSNs25Akw/u3@lWd1XD8L45B@EH4CcjOCM@v/YrRbdhUt@XzZRc68AhkFKdOHYcW44rZQudSZFfOL0AQ)

---

## Recursive version, 55 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=n=>s[++n]&&!!s.match(`^((.)\\2{${n}})*$`)|g(n))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFBT8MgFMfvfgqaLCu4rgcvxkN3MmZXk97amUJhtRaBwGoPc5@98iQazZjxdwL@7/0Cjxf6Rl1re3NYK83FvC9mV2xwV6hi46rVSu2WyyRx@Ss9tM@4ecI4J3V9c1wc1elErhcNee@wIqRp5lYrp6XIpe5wWpV2FLuUXP083eN0uxVCerTOMoSmSWtrpeQ8SVJyVlyWpbW273tjjO8RQiCEnHN@69eU0mEYIm2PntHjCyj3eIeFvQka8IAITKACF8jAFtPdBtYBFzABEaCBIRBx3H0RyaCTsQtBCBlr20sFkH52/0rTWlUPVLroH/gf0BmatJX8/2M3gg5/XPL7spGae671ODIGLhg7zA2mFdPFzhgNT5w/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
s => (                    // s = input string
  g = n =>                // g is a recursive function taking a repetition length n
    s[++n] &&             // increment n; abort if s[n] is not defined
    !!s.match(            // otherwise, test whether s consists of groups of:
      `^((.)\\2{${n}})*$` //   some character, followed by n copies of the same character
    )                     //
    | g(n)                // or whether it works for some greater n
)``                       // initial call to g with n = [''] (zero-ish)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>73</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```python
lambda s:s in[''.join(c*n for c in s[::n])for n in range(2,len(s))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZAxT8MwEIX3/oqrOiRBgaELolI3hLoiZSsd7NihJsZnnRNF/fXhThaQAgPf5Hv37tm@eBnOGLZzt3@ZvXrXRkHaJXDhWBR3b@hC2d4E6JCgZRHScbcLp0rqIDWp8GrLbe1tKFNVneZNQ@NwvqwiuTBAVxaHg7WeQaxrgGlCJPLemPW6qL5dTdMQkXMuxshmay0ApJS45LNSqu/7pf@ZGRnuKMPwMEkd87wESIJESIaESIrEXOXcZ24zKRMzNqMyfWY5/PDJUhSv1j@VrGrdtr86Ios/y6vNk/LJLhfI68MaJiRv/rGzaFX/1@1fr1g2Hw3iOGot07Is@bR89SqgqOYP)

<sub>-4 bytes, thanks to Jitse</sub>

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by replacing `set(...)` with `{...}`

Comment: Also, you can remove the space in `...1 in[...`

Answer (score 5):

## [QuadS](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
1≠∨/⍵
(.)\1*
⊃⍵L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn@/9/wUeeCRx0r9B/1buXS0NOMMdTietTVDOT5/P@fmJgMBIlgkJQEAA)

`1≠` is 1 different from

`∨/` the GCD

`⍵` of the result of

`(.)\1*` PCRE Searching for any character followed by 0 or more repetitions thereof

`⊃⍵L` and returning the first of the match lengths (i.e. the length of the match)

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╢b}▄;
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b6627ddc3b&i=%22HHeelllloo,,++wwoorrlldd%21%21%22%0A%22TTTrrriiipppllleee+++ssspppeeeaaakkk%22%0A%22QQQQuuuuaaaaddddrrrruuuupppplllleeee++++ssssppppeeeeaaaakkkk%22%0A%227777777-------ssssssspppppppeeeeeeeaaaaaaakkkkkkk%22%0A%22999999999%22%0A%22aaaabb%22%0A%22aaaaaaaabbbbcc%22%0A%22aaaaabbbbb%22%0A%22Hello,+world%21%22%0A%22TTTrrriiipppllleee+++speak%22%0A%22aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab%22%0A%22Ddoouubbllee++ssppeeaakk%22%0A%22a%22&a=1&m=2)

Procedure:

- Calculate run-lengths.
- GCD of array
- Is > 1?

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL 2008 query, 193 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='bbbbbbccc';

WITH C as(SELECT number+2n,@ t
FROM spt_values
WHERE'P'=type
UNION ALL 
SELECT n,stuff(t,1,n,'')FROM C
WHERE left(t,n)collate Thai_Bin=replicate(left(t,1),n))SELECT 1+1/~count(*)FROM C
WHERE''=t
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/NST24626)**

Comment: Is "collate Thai_Bin" really necessary?

Comment: @DrYWit it depends, the database could be set up as case sensitive. But case sensitive databases are not a popular choice. This could be handled better differently using HASHBYTES or maybe VARBINARY, but  that is more costly in bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda s:any(s=="".join(i*k for i in s[::k])for k in range(2,len(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZCxTsMwEIb3e4prJweFDjAgImVj6IqUrXSw6ys1NrZlOwp9@uDDwIDEN0T35/cXnROv5RL8/VrGwxGWi3GEU5ppACzpWp9YdjJG8loYH@ciug6QPk4UC5cqkbRwHl9WJ9@VlpgH6a8ij@N2u3sLxgtzY/EcEho0HvNhGOyx42w5J@lfSdz1jrzIXdet3GRuvr4ek/FFnLla93siVwmh7xGXJYSUnNN6s4FpmlJKxpgYYz1BRIiYc66xzlJKay08V@ZKjVJXqpE4xyaxxRp7LLLJKrsWHhq3jdyIDWrIhm3A4w/Ab5WC776OSp1O8Dsr2Nd7hR6XkJz@7zKRf7P8g4InHcI8K8XneHXehncA@Qk)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>76</del> 75 bytes

```php
while(($x=strspn($argn,$argn[$n+=$x],$n))>1&&($m=max($m,$x))%$x<1);echo!$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHBTsMwDD0vX@FNYWtFp4kTQt3gMqFxQULsBjukq0ertkmUpKwI8e3DabYBF96h9Xv2sxNHF/owv9OFZow7tM7CAl7YYDYDZ1pXfLDBZLVCrAlKJQnAfq@UMXWd58PhJKH0er02xpRlqbWmKkQEAGstUYqFEFVV9YVPhJZAksgJ5DKe62D0Tm/1Xm/2bm/3/tDgOmAaYAN0AAaIgCqgd92c0DOfzbJzGGiWbbc/kud9BS1hJ2qLH2ffyZhlIoQr2oxKYK9Mnf@3Do2i@jP0PLxXl7lSbZtlvt4vwN/H34KSm5QxRiexZdPWwiHQW8H0Hp7Xy4dHKKVuHdspg2JbRHB8QmGBC/MmIYZPBoDbQgUhgdGrHKWHfVHWGEW8W1hnrJZRyPbfFy4vF7zbJFzG8e3VeBzxZtGIjn4J7@L4gnfzqzj1TYe8Sw/H/n1jGkZHNWjRAcr30ijZoHQkt5I0GhinP6T5TSSRr8M3)

First attempt, a somewhat naïve iterative approach.

*Ungolfed:*

```php
// get the length of the next span of the same char
while( $s = strspn( $argn, $argn[ $n ], $n ) ) {

    // if span is less than 2 chars long, input is not n-speak
    if ( $s < 2 ) {
        break;
    }

    // k is GCD
    $k = max( $k, $s );

    // if span length does not divide evenly into GCD, input is not n-speak
    if( ( $k % $s ) != 0 ) {
        break;
    }

    // increment current input string index
    $n += $s;

}
```

***-1 byte***, thx to @Night2!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>30</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```perl6
{1-[gcd] m:g/(.)$0*/>>.to}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BasMwDIbvegoVythKmnaXlQ7aXXbIdZDb6MGO1RLsTsZeCGXs2TMJb7ntO0m2PvErUgpP0/WGd2c8TF@P6/dL5054fb5s7uuH5Xa1OR7rT/6esrnhSy1TZ04Y@g/KU9MQBYG5qhDHkTmlEJxbLKBt25RS3/cxRpkgIkTMOUsrtTHGew9vwiBIa5wgRtI@Fkkt1dRTUU1V1fWwK6wLuRALVDAFX4D9H6Cv1sLvv5TWdh3MtYVG7uIKR07B/XdMJOPnFfMqeHXMw2Ctzml0TaMZwPwA)

Also uses the GCD trick, but uses the index of the end position of each run matched by the regex. Returns a negative number (truthy) if n-speak, zero (falsey) otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f=(>1).foldr(gcd.length)0.group
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZCxboMwEEDn8BUXJpAoaqeqQyKGDAztUImtqqpzbIhlgy0bxOdTny5p06VvujvfO599wWiUtdumR@/CDCecsX7Vcc76Q3F8KuveWRmK4Sxrq6ZhvpSP9RDc4rcR9QQHGNG/fUHhg55mqKEvs90H5G2r0lRrnasqgHV1LgRrpdzv82xXQd51XQhBa@29T21KKQCIMaY0xYhojOHO98SSSDWUiaQFyj2bpJJLMtmkk08DrhOemQcmMp5RDDKGYe3lBqd0LsRvzLkQ5/NdjQrXnqZpOGjTR7gKVhes/Pf1XqH5O//nHi6fpHPLIgQZ9GBan5a@SUKguF@Wks9s@wY)

Straightforward; uses the GCD trick.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 80 bytes

```
func[s][repeat n length? s[if parse/case s[any[copy t skip n t]][return on]]off]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZIxb4QwDIX3@xU@pqtE1bFqly4dbm3FhjIkxNwhuDhKghC/ntqNiqJT1X4Ttt97JIaAdvtE26pD/wpbP7uujaoN6FEncDChu6TrG8R26MHrEPGp0xG51m5tO/IrJIjj4FmblBjTHByQU4r6Xm0@DC5BD9X5jDgxRHUNsCxEIUyTtcdjddhFTdOEEIZh8N6zFhEBIMbIJT9rrcdxLOQfzMzwQFuGvUFqn@3ilwBJkAjJkBBJKWOeM4@ZmPEZzOjMmCm8Lz8UPVEac9fITWO67n4g3V1dfZ@hkJx5a1TDQmGy/6@Kv9r4y4v3AxSzd0s0z8aIV1Ykd5UblnY4WcIIjvhXQLSQCAzCVTs7oX0olCe8@bRCTNy41PCna/sC)

### More idiomatic [Red](http://www.red-lang.org):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 81 bytes

```
func[s][any collect[repeat n length? s[keep parse/case s[any[copy t skip n t]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZG9T8MwEMX3/hXXTkUKYkSwsDB0BXWLOvjj2kZ2fZbtKMpfH@6wiKwKwW@K37334o@EdvlE258251dYzmMwfT71KsxgyHs0pU8YURUI4DFcyvUNcu8QI0SVMj4ZlZEVDvSG4gwFshsiu8tJWGIaQoEz7A4HRM8QdR3ANBGl5L212@1us5qOx2NKaRiGGCN7EREAcs685G@llHOusX8wI8MDZRnOJlnHGpe8FEiDVEiHlEhLW/NceazkSqxgRVVcpcm@/NBo4tT6Tqii1sbcD0Rd3bvvPTSWA98adTBR8vb/q@Kncr/8eN1AM3u3ROOotWTliuSscsI2DntLmCEQvz@ihUKgEa4qWI/2oXHu8RbLDLmwcOngz9TyBQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-¡`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 bytes

```
ò¦ mÊrÕÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LaE&code=8qYgbcpy1ck&input=IkhIZWVsbGxsb28sLCAgd3dvb3JybGxkZCEhIg)

```
ò¦ mÊrÕÉ     :Implicit input of string
ò            :Partition by
 ¦           :  Inequality
   m         :Map
    Ê        :  Length
     r       :Reduce by
      Õ      :  GCD
       É     :Subtract 1
             :Implicit output of boolean negation
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ġz₂=Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xSgNBEIZfZbP1JYVNSKE2FtcK14nF7u2qxy3MMuuxxBAIJ4Sk8xWstLSx0NoXuX2Rc4ZNIAh@1cz8//y/RlU/LB3cn42rKMX0Qsh4uUrbj9Q/p92bfMTOzuQs7d7lnXKB5vXwvV8Pny/jz@tT6vvz4WszjjeyLK11BEBRCBEjAKJzxkwmspAlSVCICOgM71VVIWLTNN57@rHWCiFCCLTSrJRq2/Zfm7eKxWuiI8itDEFO5N1nM7vZzrGcy8GczNH8rv6g6TbPTDMh4zM2c3C3Gfq5MgBdpzUXchk7WSdpcYTrDpWae07qNVHXxwNvWt7@Ag)

Takes input through the input variable and outputs through success or failure.

At first I thought this would actually be *shorter* than [my solution to Is it double speak?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189406/85334), but then I realized that `ġ` can and will try a group length of 1.

```
ġ        It is possible to split the input into chunks of similar length
 z₂      such that they have strictly equal length, and zipped together
    Ṁ    there are multiple results
   =     which are all equal.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 78 bytes

```
{s->(2..s.length/2).any{i->s.chunked(i).all{z->z.length==i&&z.all{z[0]==it}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZIxa8MwEIV3/4qrCcEG2y1ZSgv2UDpkK6XZSgc5lhNhVXIkOSEx/u3pXZRQ4uSbdPfu3sFDjXZSqGNrxJY5DlsmYfMafTkj1CpOizetJWcKcjj2Ni2iWZbZTHK1cuvHWZwxte9FWthsue5Uw6tIYE/K/pAWh/NYnovp9OC7308/WLoBubrouHUWbzBj2P6jjgJAnOk4OA3hfM65RLROEoDdTmtjpKyqh4cwuZ5cLBbGGCFE27a4wDlH1VqLJb4ZY03TjHc@kQ5BlVUIGhiqW@9BJuRCNuRDRuREVjdez57UYz2th3uYp/GMDV4ujAXaKct7Xa@U5XJ5VyWJ9k5SzaQ9Z4qJ6gR22sjqEuO/ej/HlrPmZpSNKG8m3iutu64syYdipCgogDCIg6DuFPwyoaIYer@nDUQOhPKf4tIm8McoJ1UUTvpN5DLLl1pV8QB5DpPeZbUw1g1hfJofgiE4/gE)

### Explanation

```
{s->                      Take a string as input
  (2..s.length/2)         The each string needs two parts at least, prevents the case "aaa" is 3-speak
    .any{i->              If there is any n (in this case i) that is n-speak return true
      s.chunked(i)        Split into length i substrings
      .all{z->            All substrings z
        z.length==i       Should be completely full, ie. "aaa"->["aa","a"]
        &&                And
        z.all{            All chars (it)
          z[0]==it        Should be the same as the first char
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps the description is unclear, but "aaa" is valid 3-speak. The input string should have at least two characters, but they do not need to be different.

Comment: @maxb, ok cool. That should be -2 bytes. Thanks for the update. I'll fix that tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 80 bytes

```scala
s=>"(.)\\1*".r.findAllIn(s).map(_.size).reduce((x,y)=>(BigInt(x) gcd y).toInt)>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBS8MwFMfv@xRZT4nUwk6i0LIND9tR3HEgSfM6a2MTktRtip@95hEmmk3wd8p7L@@X8Hc1V3zU4gVqT2oCBw@9dGRhDPmYTN64Is3do7dtvyurpdYKeF@OrqwyWrDtdnaVFbZo2l4ulFr31LHilRv6VLj2HVhhQQ41UHrIj6ys6LLdrXtPD4zsakmOrPA61KyajSY84FVPM28H/3zM2OTUaWi2WgGogNZ5Tsh@r7W1Skk5nWbs18XNZmOtbdvWGBPuAwAhxDkXynDmnHddl6w8BIZAGHIZCPsWaxMV6EAJWlCDHhShKVXdRK4jLmIiEOGRLpLs355I@rghxIVmHAhR15eGOEm35vP5z07WcOUgTTtkrXOy11bJ/wVsgHd/fO/7m8n8Xmo9DEKgA8PFhDCXM40QXFzM46yb1Fh@juMX)

PS. Original solution was based on `split` function but it's longer (83 bytes).

```scala
s=>(s+s).split("(.)(?!\\1)").map(_.size+1).reduce((x,y)=>(BigInt(x) gcd y).toInt)>1
```

Comment: This returns `true` for input `aab`, unfortunately.

Comment: @maxb, thanks for checking. `s.` replaced with `(s+s).` to handle that.

Comment: Good job! Though now I noticed that it fails for `aaaabb` and `aabbbb`.

Comment: @maxb, apologies, now I tested on all your test cases from starting post.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 34 bytes

```
GCD@@Length/@Split@Characters@#>1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@9/d2cXBwSc1L70kQ98huCAns8TBOSOxKDG5JLWo2EHZzlDtf0BRZl5JtLKCrp2CW7RybKyagr7DoQXVSh4eqak5QJCfr6OjoFBenp9fVJSTk5KiqKiko6DkAZTL11Eozy/KSVFUqv0PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>83</s> <s>79</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```perl
$_=s,(.)\1+,$t=length$&;$t/=2while$t%2-1;$r+=$t==($g||=$t);'',ge==$r&&/^$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xasMwEEB3fYUDqhMTO04CoTRG0KGDh3YouFtokWzhCItISDJe8u1171DrrW/R3enecWel06d5pl/M55tddjlscxqYlrc@XGla0VCy43RVWtLwcCwOFXVbBg1sQ/v7HaKsWq/zXjJGXZqWn7Scq2fONllFW0Z7qLJ9Nde1lBowJs@TZJqMcU7rrlutSNM0zjmllLUWOqSUSZJ47yGFmHM@DAN5B0YAUt4BYDjMbZTQQg09FNFEFd2BPEaKiI/YiIzwyBAhT38QrApBfv8hFKJtyRILUsNdJk8m43T33zFW8mEZsYwiL50x4ygE9uHquA3u8G1sUObm5@LttNsf9vC@Kh/O54@gNONaz4XVPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 96 bytes

```
{<>({}())<>({}[({})]){{}<>({}<>){{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}<>([{}()]({}<>)<>)}(<>)<>}{}}<>{}({}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsAgDAS/4tEc/IH4Cm/iIQULohTRY8jb02gLCbub2VwT6@Pujk2EfLDEFuBo0oUMRHyiD2rtvgEdqswHJt447bf8tXTYHv2gor8uEmOcc9Zaxxi991KKMWatpVE9IrbWxOEL)

Uses the same GCD trick that many other submissions use.  Output is 0 if the input is not n-speak, and a positive integer otherwise.

```
# For each character in the input
{

  # Add 1 to current run length
  <>({}())<>

  # If current and next characters differ:
  ({}[({})]){

    # Clean up unneeded difference
    {}<>

    # Move current run length to left stack, exposing current GCD on right stack
    ({}<>)

    # GCD routine: repeat until L=0
    {

      # Compute L mod R
      {(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}<>

      # Move R to left stack; finish computing L mod R and push to right stack
      ([{}()]({}<>)<>)

    }

    # Push 0 for new run length
    (<>)<>

  }{}

}

# Output GCD-1
<>{}({}[()])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL, 182 bytes

```
select+1-sign(min(length(x)-(select sum(length(regexp_substr(x,'(.)\1{'||i||'}',1,level)))from t connect by level<length(x))))from(select x,level i from t connect by level<length(x))
```

It works with an assumption that input data is stored in a table t(x), e.g.

```
with t(x) as (select 'HHeelllloo,,  wwoorrlldd!!' from dual)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>29</s> 23 bytes

```
{~|/(&/s@&1<s)!s:#'=:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrquRl9DTb/YQc3QplhTsdhKWd3WqqL2f5pSSEhIUVFRZmZmQUFBTk5OamqqgoJCcXExkAtkJyYmZmdnK/0HAA)

edit: removed some unnecessary colons (i know when a monadic is required but it's not always clear to me if there's ambiguity so i default to including the colon) and changed the mod `x-y*x%y` to ngn/k's `y!x`, which meant i could remove a variable assignment

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>24</s> 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⊂∊1↓⍳∘≢{⍵/⍨(≢⍵)⍴⍺↑⍺}¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDPSsNAEMbvPsX0lBZSpHgQvSrSnkSbF9jtTjVkzS67CaWIF4VSCymKCJ499eZBvXjso@yLxNksVnrpBwnzzXy//ce07Iopk@qqrt3i3s0XPTd7cdWnm7@5x/dbV/3su@qbvlWbPJUdV31R182ee3frFTH12M2eXLV0y9fBuVs8rD8OaEhueHlC/6Q/GNZRYkqEEbNoj6O9MUT9PqIkKRXHAJOJUsZIKUSr1YyTJDHGpGmqtaYUIgKAtZYs1YyxLMua4AWpJFGLCRJRxnsdQE961LMe9rTHPR8WOAzqBtkgHYRBLCgLaqijPzXOTznflMFyPhr9t7ynRHTGpN1@CHoGFcNEGSl23V0jy7Z22OzUdE@FUmXJuc/72/rD@yMHBNpCoYVcFZAjCigUcIRrlguJotNk2nijiynYwqT5VQw7878)

`⊂` enclose the string to treat map using the entire string
 e.g. `"aaabbb"`

`⍳∘≢{`…`}¨` for each of the `⍳` **ɩ**ndices 1 through the tally of characters in the string:
 e.g. `3`

`⍺↑⍺` take the current number of elements from the current number, padding with 0s
 e.g. `[3,0,0]`

`(≢⍵)⍴` cyclically **r**eshape into the shape of the tally of characters in the string
  e.g. `[3,0,0,3,0,0]`

`⍵/⍨` use that to replicate the string's characters
  `"aaabbb"`

`1↓` drop the first one (*n* = 1)

`⊂∊` is the the entire string a member of that list?

Comment: Are you dividing the input string into n-sized chunks, and checking that all characters are equal within each chunk? I haven't gotten into APL, but it's definitely the most readable "golfing" language.

Comment: @maxb I'm in the process of writing an explanation. I'm filtering with all possible masks `[1,0,0,1,0,0…]` etc. I'll be happy to teach you APL (it doesn't take long to learn). Just pop unto [the APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard).

Comment: Here's [`{1<∨/≢¨⍵⊆⍨≢∘∪¨,\⍵}`](https://tio.run/##fZC/S8QwFMd3/4rclKWHHA6iuClyN4leR5ekyUlpICGhFBEnodSDHjoIzk7FxUX/gf4p7x/pvdfgyS1@hjbfl/fJL@HMVN0LY@@G4WF2Bk13CM8ffQftD6xraDtM0LxD89l3yS1WH4cV1C/QbmDztriC9VP/dQT1K6blzTl@0/liOfDUl5plIuhwyg9WjM/nWhvE2iRhrKqs9d4YpSaTcTpNU@99nufOOezSWjPGQggYcSyEKIpibLxGSgRLQiFoecouimSSSi7JZJNOflzgODKNhIiL6IiIFJHROvllTDQr5W4Yo5RZ9leijB38Upiw/xD4DDZhlfVG/Xd3p0Wxt8Nup7F6oawtSympn25Lh6cj02TCBf1m0H5zvgU) for 18

Comment: @Cowsquack Clever, and different, so why don't you post `{1<∨/≢¨⍵⊆⍨≢¨∪\⍵}`?

Comment: Unfortunately it fails for `aacccaaaaabb`

Comment: @Cowsquack `1<∨/≢¨0⊂⍨1,2≠/⍞` then

Comment: @Cowsquack `1<∨/2-/⍸2≠/∊0⍞0` works too.

Comment: I suppose at this point you can just post the answer :P

Comment: ---That (`1<∨/2-/⍸2≠/∊0⍞0`) is a nice answer btw--- Actually wait it fails for `999999999` but that can be fixed by changing the `1<` to `1≠`

Comment: Here's `1≠∨/⍸2≠/∊0⍞0` with `⎕io←0`

Comment: @Cowsquack OK, you post then (I don't need rep) and we'll call it a collaborative effort :-) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBSsQwEIbvfYrsqZcuW72InkXWkwh9gUkTpCQwQ0IpvoBWYcWLV/HoI/g8eZE6YzCrKOx3mvkz/z9kgPza3ILHmyU9vVxepbvntkrzPS1H6eEtze@btPs45nKT5sc27V7bhV@XugujVT1EG8/qSn1B1XZrrWcQm0apaUIMwXtjVqsy0nVdCGEYBiLiSWstyzFGbrkGAOdcGb5mRoZlMAw7g/SUzeIWu/glQBIkQjL2ISeZdSZmKGMzkHGZ4jz9pigAWgP8aDOa6fvfsmi6qi/Ax38OxWfCRk0YvDl0G7Lg/mwsm8vLuUEcR63FJxeRz8mX9tZSqU8 "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 bytes

```
ÊÆóXÃ¤d_äe e
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=ysbzWMOkZF/kZSBl&input=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)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
M!`(.)\1*
.
.
^(..+)(\1|¶)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BCsIwDEDv@YoOFLo5CzuJd8FdPAg7Dlm79jBabOkcu/hdfoA/NhOqu/l6SdK8kETzGO5y2fJzt1yyjou8rQoQ@G5ciF3O2@r5fuXFZlnq2hiHeF@WjM2z9zE6p3WWQdM0McZhGEII2GGMYYyN44gpxlJKay1ckQnBVGoEjUh5SBJZpJFHIpmkkmvhkNgnxkRImIRM2AQcfwBVlYLvP4ZK9T2ssYIa7/Ilm310@t8xwUi7jlhHwUl7P01KUR@tTtvQDiDhAw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
M!`(.)\1*
```

Split the text into runs of identical characters.

```
.
.
```

Replace them all with the same character.

```
^(..+)(\1|¶)*$
```

Check whether the GCD of the lengths of the runs is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 14 bytes

```
£─╞möl╠mÅ▀£╙╓┴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY87DsIwDEB3ThGmLmVG7AxdkXqBhASokspRStW1CyeAIrEgJK6AOADcJBcJtgyIhTf59yy7ltvNGtwqpcc1Hvo4nOvn3cXhUj938dhjcTjFYR8Pt5SyojDGIQB5LkTXAYTgnNbjcTbKyrIMIVRV5b3HGWOMEKJpGkwxllJaa3FsgbQIFqRG0AmUe9bII5FMUsklmWzSp8yEaRjPGEYylkFn9gFj6ij1DjhRarn8FCijboF/Qi46CE7/f84baX9WfVdiba4B2lYpmqVn6Dq6KUsv)

### Explanation

Checks all possible divisions of the input string into equal length chunks, and checks if there is a partition in which all chunks have just one unique character.

```
£                length of string with pop
 ─               get divisors
  ╞              discard from left of string/array (removes 1)
   mö            explicit map using 7 operators
     l           push input
      ╠          divide input into chunks of size k
       mÅ        explicit map using 2 operators
         ▀£      number of unique elements of list
           ╙     get maximum number of unique characters per chunk
                 loop ends here
            ╓    get the minimum of all maximums
             ┴   check if equal to 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 10 bytes

```
ẋl¦d¦&⊢⌉1>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@Gu7pxDy1IOLVN71LXoUU@nod3//4mJSUAAAA)

Same "GCD of run-lengths > 1" as many other submissions use.

There is a bug in `ė` (run-length encoding) that drops the last unique element of the list, otherwise we could have the following 9 byte solution: `ė(¦d¦&⊢1>`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

Outputs **0** for falsy inputs or a positive integer otherwise.

```
tiFhCr8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8xDsIwDEV3nyLdCyswg1BXpF4gaSI1SpAjp1UFlw@2DN14k534Wd/ltczt2ZZ4n690bsYf320YQsgMYt8bs22IRDl733UwjiMRxRhLKTwRQjDG1Fq55dpam1KCB7My3FrPsEHSF5XEEk08EcUUVdwEJ@WgVKUoQbFKUuDyA@TVOfj@c@ncNMFeOxj4LuzNhpT9v2NKsGlfsa@Cm0dcV@dkTqJLGsnwAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
<1iFhMr8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38Yw0y3Dt8ji/38lcwjQhYBiCCiAgFQISISAbAhQAgA)

```
<1iFhMr8Q   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
            Trailing Q inferred
      r8Q   Run length encode Q into [count, character]
    hM      Take first element of each
  iF        Reduce by GCD
<1          Is 1 less than the above? Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 38 bytes

```perl
for$i(1..y///c){print/^((.)\2{$i})*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY89a8MwEEB3/QoleLCLY9FCCd07eC14DAXJUkFI@MQpxpSQv171rmq99U339Y675DA@l/IB2Pj2cRg@lVJzd0vol6t6b9uhuzzdGn/vHhp1Lz/l42U5lnF0LhIAfS/ltgEgxmjt4SCmaUJE731KiSacc1LKnDOlFGutQwjijVgJSrUlyEDOU5XYYo09Ftlkld0gzpVTJVdSxVV0JVTEyx@Cq8aI3z6Fxsyz2GMjRvoLerkBRvvfM8npsK/YV4lXC7CuxvAcn87X8A1fkK4ellxOyzc)

The `print"\n"` in the footer is needed to separate the outputs.

Straightforward loop through all possible `n`s. Outputs nothing for "1-speak", anything else for n-speak where n > 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 76 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Where((_,n)=>s.Count%(n+=2)<1&!s.Where((c,i)=>c!=s[i/n*n]).Any()).Any()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc9NC4JAEAbgu79iFYrdMqOufkAEQeAx8CAS67DiQszCrpYR/XZbwwQ7vfMw72EGzAaM7E8tQnROpWkiqLlO/FKpW1LFvYkTE2S10ILSq49s4FG12CworuM9i3ZLdyqAL20B3NjkcosrLFhwwCdlY/Sh41RKCw41vXNNOiKRoHjkxcshxOPc879Z/hLGgZclTLOF1YzzLcB/eSaLN7POtGxEKlHQinbBRQ3P21NZ2H8A)

Generate all `n` from 2, 3, 4, ... and do the following:

- Check if the length of input is divisible by n
- Compare each character of input to the corresponding character of an `n-speak` string

If both checks pass, the input string is `n-speak`.

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org) , 126 bytes

```
bool f(string s){import std.algorithm;auto a=s.group.minElement!(a=>a[1])[1];foreach(g;s.group)if(g[1]%a)return 0;return a>1;}
```

First code golf I've done in D.

Does not handle empty input strings (causes an assertion failure in the standard library).

Ungolfed version:

```
bool f(string s) {
    import std.algorithm; // for group and minElement

    // splits the string into a groups of the same character
    // eg. "HHHiii".group returns
    // [Tuple!(char, uint)('H', 3), Tuple!(char, uint)('i', 3)]
    auto groups = s.group;

    // gets the smallest group length
    auto min_length = groups.minElement!(a => a[1])[1];

    foreach(g; groups) // for each group
        if(g[1] % min_length) // if it's length is not divisible by smallest length
            return 0; // return false

    return min_length > 1; // return true if smallest length was above 1
}
```