# Lucas and Fibonacci are in pair

Tags: string, code-challenge, decision-problem, restricted-source, self-validating

Influenced by [Non-discriminating Programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156967/non-discriminating-programming), I made up an idea of a similar challenge.

Here, we say a string is a Lucas string if the number of appearances of each character is a Lucas number (2, 1, 3, 4, 7, ...), and a string is a Fibonacci string if the number of appearances of each character is a Fibonacci number (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...).

Here are some concrete examples:

```
"Programming Puzzles"
Appearance Count:   P a e g i l m n o r s u z
                  1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2
```

All counts are both Lucas numbers and Fibonacci numbers, so this is both a Lucas string and a Fibonacci String

```
"Sandbox for Proposed Challenges"
Appearance Count:   C P S a b d e f g h l n o p r s x
                  3 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 4 1 2 2 1
```

All counts are Lucas numbers, so this is a Lucas string. However the count of `o` is not a Fibonacci number, so this is not a Fibonacci string.

```
"Here are some concrete examples: "
Appearance Count:   : H a c e l m n o p r s t x
                  5 1 1 2 2 8 1 2 1 2 1 3 2 1 1
```

All counts are Fibonacci, so this is a Fibonacci string. However the counts of  and `e` are not Lucas numbers, so this is not a Lucas string.

```
"Non-discriminating Programming"
Appearance Count:   - N P a c d g i m n o r s t
                  1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 5 3 4 2 3 1 1
```

Since count of `i` is not Lucas number, and count of `n` is not Fibonacci number, so this is neither a Lucas string nor a Fibonacci String.

### Challenge

Write 2 programs, one Lucas program and one Fibonacci program, both accepting a string as input, that:

- The Lucas program checks whether the input is Fibonacci; and
- The Fibonacci program checks whether the input is Lucas,

where the definitions of "Lucas" and "Fibonacci" are as above.

### Rules

- Your programs **can choose to receive input either from STDIN or as function/program argument**.
- Your programs **must output or return one of the 2(TWO) distinct values** at your choice, one for the truthy value and one for the falsy value, and the choice **must be consistent across the programs**, i.e. you cannot have one program returning `0/1` while the other one returning `true/false`.
- Your programs **must output or return a truthy value if the source of each other is inputted**, i.e. your Lucas program must return a truthy value if the source of your Fibonacci program is inputted, and vice versa.
- **It is allowed to have program being both Lucas and Fibonacci.**
- Characters not used are apparently not counted, in case you doubt because 0 is not in the Lucas sequence.
- Number of distinct characters in each program are not restricted to either Lucas or Fibonacci numbers.
- Only full programs or functions allowed. Snippets are not accepted.
- Standard loopholes are apparently forbidden.

### Scoring

The score will be calculated as follows:

- For each program, multiply `the number of distinct characters used` by `the maximum number of appearances of the characters in the source`.
- Add the two values calculated in the previous step up. This is your score.

Example:

```
Lucas code :    20 distinct characters, MAX(appearance of each character)=7
Fibonacci code: 30 distinct characters, MAX(appearance of each character)=5
Score: 20*7 + 30*5 = 140 + 150 = 290
```

### Test cases

```
Input                                   | Output of ...    
                                        | Lucas Program      | Fibonacci Program
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
<Your Lucas program>                    | True if all appe-  | True
(Lucas string by rules)                 | arance counts are  |
                                        | exactly 1, 2 or 3; |
                                        | False otherwise    |
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
<Your Fibonacci program>                | True               | True if all appe-
(Fibonacci string by rules)             |                    | arance counts are
                                        |                    | exactly 1, 2 or 3;
                                        |                    | False otherwise
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Programming Puzzles"                   | True               | True
(Both Lucas and Fibonacci)              |                    |     
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Sandbox for Proposed Challenges"       | False              | True
(Lucas but not Fibonacci)               |                    |     
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Here are some concrete examples: "     | True               | False
(Fibonacci but not Lucas)               |                    |
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Non-discriminating Programming"        | False              | False
(Neither Lucas nor Fibonacci)           |                    |
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Hello world!"                          | True               | True
(Both Lucas and Fibonacci)              |                    |     
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"18446744073709551616"                  | False              | True
(Lucas but not Fibonacci)               |                    |     
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Lucas and Fibonacci are IN pair"       | True               | False
(Fibonacci but not Lucas)               |                    |
----------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------
"Lucas and Fibonacci are in pair"       | False              | False
(Neither Lucas nor Fibonacci)           |                    |
```

### Winning Criteria

The submission with the lowest score in each language wins.

Comment: "_Lucas and Fibonacci are IN pair (Fibonacci but not Lucas)_" You've swapped the True and False in your table.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I don't see anything stating that. Two programs where each characters is used once should be fine I think. But I'll let OP verify/deny that.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Besides, in the Truthy/Falsey table the Lucas program as input in the Lucas program states: "_True if all appearance counts are exactly 1, 2 or 3; False otherwise_", and similar in the Fibonacci program and input columns.

Comment: I see, but I think this should be clarified in the *Rules* section. I thought they ought to be mutually exclusively either Fib or Lucas.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I can definitely understand your confusion. I've re-read the challenge a few times myself to make sure. Still waiting for OP to verify and edit however..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Since the Lucas program checks whether the input is Fibonacci, so there is no problem in that row I think.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I have edited to clarify that it is allowed to have program being both Lucas and Fibonacci. As long as the two programs do different jobs accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score: 10 + 8 = 18

This could be a comment on Kevin's post, but I've developed it independently and the technique is slightly different. Therefore I am posting it myself.

#### Fibonacci program that checks Lucas (10 bytes)

```
€¢Dā0šÅgÃQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaQ4tcjjQaHF14uDX9cHPg///BiXkpSfkVCmn5RQoBRfkF@cWpKQrOGYk5Oal56anFAA)

```
€¢Dā0šÅgÃQ -> Full program
€¢         -> Count the occurrences of each character in the string. Call this list C.
  Dā       -> Duplicate and yield the range [1 ... len string].
    0š     -> Prepend 0. [0 ... len string].
      Åg   -> Nth Lucas number (for each).
        Ã  -> Intersection with C.
         Q -> Check equality with C.
```

---

#### Lucas program that checks Fibonacci (8 bytes)

```
€¢DāÅfÃQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaQ4tcjjQebk073Bz4/7@SR2pRqkIiEBfn56YqJOfnJRellqQqpFYk5hbkpBZbKSgBAA)

```
€¢DāÅfÃQ -> Full program
€¢       -> Count the occurrences of each character in the string. Call this list C.
  Dā     -> Duplicate and yield the range [1 ... len string].
    Åf   -> Nth Fibonacci number (for each). We don't need the 0th this time!
      Ã  -> Intersection with C.
       Q -> Check equality with C.
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I'm afraid the Lucas program fail for single-char inputs because the list starts with `[2,1,...]`. So the `Dā<Åg` would be `[2]` with the count `[1]`, returning in a falsey result. The Fibonacci program is perfect, though. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fixed. AHHH, Lucas sequence, why do you have to be non-increasing?!

Comment: I know the feeling.. Screwed up my initial program as well. Too bad the `∞` is `[1,INF]` instead of `[0,INF]`, otherwise I would have used that instead of `Z>`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: <s>19</s> 17 (9x1 + 8x1)

-2 score thanks to *@Emigna*.

#### Lucas (<s>10</s> 9 bytes):

```
€¢Z>ÅGKg_
```

[Try it online (with the Fibonacci program as input).](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaQ4ui7A63ununx8O4h1vdgDwA)
[Verify all test cases.](https://tio.run/##dY@xagJBEIb7e4rRWsHD8y5axEK4RBJESGcjc3uTy8LezrGrKIKNoA@QR7ALBLu8wNr7EL7IuZgiVYqpPv7v/4ctZpLqfjp2X8MmXA@f0By6U335cSfrjtvZ43n/9FLM61Y9NVwYLEupC5guNxtFNnhDnWe8hnc24HnFlnIYfaBSpAvPn8kQoD/LJYFgLQwtCGiNZeXzAwgmrNu5tMJIL8bFXf5X5AVKMazYqLwRhA9RFCdR1Em6Saff64VxGAevS4EW/A5IZcYahZD3xvEEKpTmXy71L7/uvt1xdt6n/ssb)

#### Fibonacci (<s>9</s> 8 bytes):

```
€¢ZÅFKg_
```

[Try it online (with the Lucas program as input).](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaQ4uiDre6eafHw3h2h1vdgVwA)
[Verify all test cases.](https://tio.run/##dY@xagJBEIb7e4rRWsHD8y5axEK4RBJESGcjc3uTy8LezrGrKIKNoA@QR7ALBLu8wNr7EL7IuZgiVYqpPv7v/4ctZpLqfjp2X8MmXA@f0By6U335cSfrjtvZeZ@@FPO6VU8NFwbLUuoCpsvNRpEN3lDnGa/hnQ14XrGlHEYfqBTpwvNnMgToz3JJIFgLQwsCWmNZ@fwAggnrdi6tMNKLcXGX/xV5gVIMKzYqbwThQxTFSRR1km7S6fd6YRzGwetSoAW/A1KZsUYh5L1xPIEKpfmXS/3Lr7tvd5w9nvdP/s0b)

Outputs `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey results.

**Explanation:**

```python
€¢          # Count each of the characters in the input
            #  i.e. "Programming Puzzles" → [2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1]
  Z         # Get the max, without popping the list
            #  i.e. [2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1] → 2
   >ÅG      # Calculate the Lucas numbers up to and including this max+1
            # (Note: the +1 is because `1ÅG` returns `[]` instead of `[1]`)
            #  i.e. 2 → [2,1]
   ÅF       # Calculate the Fibonacci numbers up to and including this max
            #  i.e. 2 → [0,1,1,2]
     K      # Remove all these Fibonacci numbers from the count list
            #  i.e. [2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1] and [2,1] → []
            #  i.e. [2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1] and [0,1,1,2] → []
      g_    # Check if the list is not empty
            #  i.e. [] → 0
```

Comment: The test cases in TIO should be swapped, aren't they? Both programs are both Lucas and Fibonacci tho ;)

Comment: @user71546 Should be fixed now. Also added an explanation and test suite.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen How about the *Both programs are both Lucas and Fibonacci tho* point?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I had the Fibonacci program as input in the Fibonacci TIO, and Lucas program in the Lucas TIO. Hence _user71546_ stated the test cases should be swapped. The "_Both programs are both Lucas and Fibonacci tho ;)_" part I read as: "_Not that it matters that they are swapped, since both programs are both a Lucas and Fibonacci program anyway. ;)_" As mentioned in my other comment, I don't see anything indicating the programs can't be both a Lucas AND Fibonacci program, similar as the test case "Programming Puzzles".. Will delete and/or fix if this is not allowed.

Comment: Do you really need the `ê`s?

Comment: @Emigna Thanks for -2 score! Not sure why I had that now that I think about it. Hmm.. time to update my Java answer as well it seems. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32*2 + 33*2 = <s>171</s> 130

*-41 points thanks to nwellnhof!*

#### Lucas Program:

```perl6
{min([values .ords⊎e]».&{$_∈(1,1,*+*…0)[0…$_]})}
```

#### Fibonacci Program:

```perl6
{min([values .ords⊎e]».&{$_∈(2,1,*+*…0)[0…$_]})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZHPSsNAEMbP5inG0D9JTUOiaastBVEQC1IKHttStpttXdjsxt1E28aCx@LBx/AlvPkofZG6aQ5eRKSHYdjhN9/3MRsTyZq7XbSECoOukUWUW8MnxFKiwBUyVNu3dzL@@nQrWWmy3Wws3/Gd2klt@/rh2UNPt9JkvLbXRq4w@5fC6e8KeYZLLEK91oXqwUGqTvXgCNWOYcyEhJcih2MOpJhLFGm9OQzS1YoRZTpg3iMeTsUCclYjsVAkhOsHxBjh8wK5JZIA0qVERAALjiVJCJAFimKt0oYc6gteD6nCkmoHlOxdfhxNR6swJuBZSBYe66d/HgTNVhB4rbOWd9Fo@E2/mevcpRgp0KHghk4FRxjTvXevDzGi8i@E8gKBzDiKJeXJzDLL9cBTo6RcFNfrpYkDzCpNbAdmebM7xtowFFrqW2AhSXuUaKq4mhuh2MpcLKKpm3L6mBK3x5NaMbhCc7f4GI0t1rar0mj3DQ)

Anonymous code blocks that take a string and return a Junction (which can be coerced to truthy/falsey values). Both use the same structure rearranged to get the correct amount of characters.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{min([values .ords⊎e]».&{$_∈(1,1,*+*…0)[0…$_]})}

{  # Anonymous code block
  min(  # Find the minimum of:
      [values .ords⊎e]  # Coerces the string to a list of the number of occurrences
                      ».&{ # Map each value to:
                          $_∈  # Whether the value is an element of:
                             (1,1,*+*…0)   # The sequence
                                        [0…$_]  # Truncated to prevent it evaluating infinitely
                         }
     )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19</s>  8×1+9×1=17

<sup>[code-page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)</sup>

Lucas Program:

```
ĠẈfƑJÆḞ$
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//xKDhuohmxpFKw4bhuJ4k////IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMi)** Or see [all-tests](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoe7OtKOTfQ63PZwxzyV/0f3HG5/1LQmC4gfNczR1bVTeNQwN/L//2glNJVKOlwKCLGjuw@3Hdl/rAssGlCUn16UmJubmZeuEFBaVZWTWgwWD07MS0nKr1BIyy9SAKopyC9OTVFwzkjMyUnNS4eq8UgtSlVIBOLi/NxUheT8vOSi1JJUhdSKxNwCoDlWCmBVfvl5uimZxclFmUBLEkvAFiEshRqUk5OvUJ5flJOiCBYwtDAxMTM3MTEwNzY3sDQ1NTQzNANL@JQmJxYrAN2m4JaZlJ@XmJycCXaBp59CQWJmEV41mXkQNbEA).

Fibonacci Program:

```
ĠẈfƑJŻÆĿƊ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoe7OtKOTfQ6uvtw25H9x7r@//@vBBc83PZwxzwVJQA)** Or see [all-tests](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoe7OtKOTfQ6uvtw25H9x7r@H91zuP1R05osIH7UMEdX107hUcPcyP//o5Xgag@3PdwxT0VJh0tBCUM/WDSgKD@9KDE3NzMvXSGgtKoqJ7UYLB6cmJeSlF@hkJZfpABUU5BfnJqi4JyRmJOTmpcOVeORWpSqkAjExfm5qQrJ@XnJRaklqQqpFYm5BUBzrBTAqvzy83RTMouTizKBliSWgC1CWAo1KCcnX6E8vygnRREsYGhhYmJmbmJiYG5sbmBpampoZmgGlvApTU4sVgC6TcEtMyk/LzE5ORPsAk8/hYLEzCK8ajLzIGpiAQ).

#### How?

Both work in very similar fashions -- `ÆḞ` gets the n<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number while `ÆĿ` gets the n<sup>th</sup> lucas number. `Ż` adds a zero to the front of the list of n's to use with `ÆĿ` to cater for the fact that the 0<sup>th</sup> Lucas number is 2, which  we need to test for while 0 is the 0<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number, which we do not need to test for. `Ɗ` is a quick to chain the last three links together as a monad, while `$` chains the last two links together as a monad...

Lucas Program:

```
ĠẈfƑJÆḞ$ - Link: list of characters, s
Ġ        - group indices by value
 Ẉ       - length of each
       $ - last two links as a monad (f(s))
    J    -   range of length of s
     ÆḞ  -   nth Fibonacci number (vectorises)
   Ƒ     - is left argument is equal to the result of?:
  f      -   filter - remove items from left that are not in right
         -            i.e. groupLengths without those Fibonacci numbers
```

Fibonacci Program:

```
ĠẈfƑJŻÆĿƊ - Link: list of characters, s
Ġ         - group indices by value
 Ẉ        - length of each
        Ɗ - last three links as a monad (f(s))
    J     -   range of length of s
     Ż    -   prepend a zero
      ÆĿ  -   nth Lucas number (vectorises)
   Ƒ      - is left argument is equal to the result of?:
  f       -   filter - remove items from left that are not in right
         -            i.e. groupLengths without those Lucas numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, score <s>1238</s> 1137 (35x18 + 39x13)

#### Lucas:

```java
c->c.chars().map(a->c.length()-c.replace(""+(char)a,"").length()).allMatch(a->{int n=2,s=1,m=3;for(;a>m;n=s,s=m)m=n+s;return a>0&a<4|a==m;})//",-..mmnrr
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVPbbhMxEH3vVwz7gOwku2loLqWL84KEQEqrSuGN8jBxnKyLL4vtLb3llQ/gE/mR4N1caFoJYWltzcyZ8Tmr42u8wfR6/m3NFXoP5yjNwxGANEG4BXIBkzoEmFmrBBpQZBqcNEvwNI@F1VHcfMAgOUxAAYM1T8c84wU6T2imsSRYJ5Qwy1AQmvLMiVLFySRJ2qTGUewkCd0jaIZKnWPgRd35EJmAYW86nvU6mp3kC@tIjmOdG@ZjUlPNTNvnToTKGcDx8Wt8139ExnS@ot1u0kmzTGvj3DqvuZbVTEWuW8o3Vs5BR81bVV@@AtKN4CB8IMmls0uHWteKL6v7eyV80gjfAaZo5jN7C5EWRHBpvZjD@yJKiHKegz8KJwDj560WwK3hkbYAcYu6jJPP4BB@YU06l547Ge@PfGsOf/k8H62UhR/Wqfmrw0rvtN8fjvr949HJ6PjtYNAb9oaHiEnF0UMUAh/kzBrkXDYsP11AidL9H1iaA3CzdbvwOTaBXEAoxJOGRWV4kNaA9BBcFYq75geGIsabC3aIsydX@3TsD5wl6sTeWX7vrKvkauct0amDf7pLMRIPGpNF5r@7QJANWtjCdp9ubUVUSzGGj@QlNGWnlDZV2vgtjXbLWAwRjSL1ovVKXryWxnqNru2DkqaswtZ80zsfhM5sFbIyFoMypCm3E/j98xckbZWpTYZuB6/WfwA)

#### Fibonacci:

```java
s->s.chars().map(e->s.length()-s.replace(""+(char)e,"").length()).allMatch(a->{int l=(int)Math.sqrt(a=5*a*a+4);return(l*l==a|(l=(int)Math.sqrt(a-=8))*l==a);})//--...===aaanl((((()))))
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVPLbtswELznK7Y6FGRsyXbjPBqVvhQwWqAJAri3poc1RUVM@VBJKs3z2g/oJ/ZHXEqWkzgFihIQhd0dLmcWw0u8wvSy@LbiCr2HE5TmbgdAmiBciVzAvA0BltYqgQZKsghOmgvwNI@Fh524@YBBcphDCQxWPp35jFfoPKGZxpqINqGEuQgVoanPnKhV7EySZEBaHBXDJKGPCJqhUicYeEUwnd1FJqAYiT8ak1Xmv7tAkO3v4i4OpjR3IjTOELWrGMN78jc0ZUeUdlWaP9DRKE2zLGMxRDSKtIu2a5W3UupmqaKUXtGVlQXoOJJe9JevgHQ9jyB8IMmZsxcOtW4Hctbc3irhk24uG8ACTbG011BaBxFcWy8KeF9FhVHtS/AH4QRg/LzVArg1PIoTIK5R17HzMWzDT61JC@m5k/H@yLfl8MTnZWulLPywThWvtiuTo@n04HA6HR/uHY7f7u9PDiYH24hPDUcPUQjM5dIa5Fx2LD@eQo3S/R9Ymi1wt41G8DkeAllCqASsj5aN4UFaA9JDcE2obrrhhSrGTy03qONnV/N0xreMh23i0Xj80XjnyfnGejhsg3@az7A3Q88mQ8328siE5DjTuWE@JjXVzAx870HA2fg1vpveI2O6s9p5Moxm09q4Xvjz59KZq2Pevyhp6ib09lrc@CB0ZpuQ1bEYlCFdeZDA75@/IBmUWbnO0L7xw@oP)

**Explanation (base) Lucas:**

```java
s->                     // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  s.chars()             //  Loop over the characters as integer-stream
   .map(c->             //  Map each of them to:
     s.length()-s.replace(""+(char)c,"").length())
                        //   The occurrence-count of this character in the input
   .allMatch(n->{       //  Check if all these occurrence-counters are true for:
      int a=2,b=1,c=3;  //    Integer `a`,`b`,`c` starting at 2,1,3 (start of Lucas sequence)
      for(;n>c;         //    Loop as long as the current occurrence-counter is larger than `c`
          ;             //      After every iteration:
           a=b,         //       Replace `a` with `b`
           b=c)         //       Replace `b` with `c`
        c=a+b;          //     Replace `c` with `a` + `b`
      return            //    Return whether the occurrence-counter is one of:
             n>0&n<4    //     1,2,3,
             |n==c;})   //     or `c`
```

**Explanation (base) Fibonacci:**

```java
s->                     // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  s.chars()             //  Loop over the characters as integer-stream
   .map(c->             //  Map each of them to:
      s.length()-s.replace(""+(char)c,"").length())
                        //   The occurrence-count of this character in the input
   .allMatch(n->{       //  Check if all these occurrence-counters are true for:
      int r=(int)Math.sqrt(n=5*n*n+4); 
                        //   Integer `r`, the square of `5*n*n+4` floored
      return r*r==k     //  Return whether `5*n*n+4` is a perfect square,
             |(r=(int)Math.sqrt(n-=8))*r==n;})
                        //  and/or if `5*n*n-4` is a perfect square
```

A number \$n\$ is a Fibonacci number, if either or both of \$5n^2+4\$ or \$5n^2-4\$ is a perfect square [<sup>(source)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers)

**Explanation modifications:**

After these base programs explained above, I've made the following changes:

- Changed the names of variables to only use letters we've already used to reduce amount of distinct characters; and also so the least amount of characters have to be added at the comment to make the occurrence-counts Lucas/Fibonacci numbers;
- Added parenthesis around the return-statement (to get rid of the space as well);
- Put any remaining character we need to increase for it to become a Lucas/Fibonacci number after the trailing comment `//`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11*1+12*1=23 bytes

Both return 0 as truthy, 1 as falsy

Fibonacci test:

```
ĐỤ⇹ɔ2ᴇřḞ\Ł±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHu5c8at95corRwy3tR2c@3DEv5mjjoY3//xengkAuAA)

Lucas test:

```
ĐỤ⇹ɔ02ᴇŘĿ\Ł±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHu5c8at95coqB0cMt7UdnHNkfc7Tx0Mb//4tTQSAXAA)

Explanation:

```
                    Implicit input
Đ                   Duplicate the input
 Ụ                  Get list of unique characters
  ⇹                 Swap the top two elements on the stack
   ɔ                Count the number of occurrences of each character in the input
    2ᴇř             Push [1,...,100] (should be more than enough)
       Ḟ            Get the first 100 Fibonacci numbers
        \           Get all character counts that aren't Fibonacci numbers
         Ł          Get the number of such counts
          ±         Output the sign of the number of such counts
                    Implicit output
```

```
                    Implicit input
ĐỤ⇹ɔ                get count of occurrences of each character
    02ᴇŘ            Push [0,1,...,100] (should be more than enough)
        Ŀ           Get the first 101 Lucas numbers
         \          Get all character counts that aren't Lucas numbers
          Ł         Get the number of such counts
           ±        Output the sign of the number of such counts
                    Implicit output
```